# What happens when you plug a UPS into itself?

Tags: discussion, community

UPSey daisy; so we had a little ... incident ...

[image: UPS-CEPTION!]

*Pretty sure* that has power.

We're past that now, and things are returning to normal. It's only appropriate that we take a moment to think about the folks that got pulled out of bed and worked their knuckles to the bone to get things back up and running. In the spirit of that, we're going to have a little contest.

#### Lets's make some free-hand thank-you cards for the folks that kept things going!

Yeah, it's their job and all, but they went above and beyond today. Plus, who doesn't like some cool free hand cards chocked full 'o love to hang on their wall? And it's Friday, so it's not like you have anything better to do. Plus, it's been a while since we've done one of these.

**Rules:**

- Must say "Never Forget" with today's date, somewhere in the picture (May 16, 2014 in any format you desire)
- Must not mention or depict any entity, person or company in a derogatory manner
- Must be as funny as you can possibly make it
- Must be at or under our size limit for image uploads
- If large, make sure the small version links to the large version
- Must be *mostly* hand-drawn (mouse, pen, etc)
- Must (of course) be your original work

**The top 10 artists, as chosen by votes, will receive a goody box containing:**

- One Stack Exchange T-shirt (or your choice of other site's shirts we have in stock)
- Your choice of a Stack Exchange coffee mug, or Stack Exchange [Nalgene](http://nalgene.com/) water bottle
- An assortment of pens, stickers and retractable sharpies
- A Stack Overflow padfolio, with branded aluminium pen

**Mechanics**

- Multiple entries allowed, but only one prize pack per winner
- Winning entries determined by net count of up-votes (down-voting the competition isn't going to help you)
- Open to employees, but c'mon, y'all can just ask me for this stuff, so make it *good*.
- Contest closes at 20:00:00 UTC Monday May 19 2014
- Allow 6 to 8 weeks for prize delivery (no, I'm not kidd.. ugh, I give up)

***Now get those crayons in your toes and show these unsung heroes some well deserved love!***

---

*Just about 7.5 hours left folks, get any last minute votes in before then! This will remain open past the contest end time, however votes must be logged on or before 20:00:00 UTC in order to count. Good luck to everyone, we've received some awesome stuff so far!*

#### The Winners

Because there were some late entries, a weekend involved and a whole lot of awesomeness on display here, I'm declaring everyone that contributed a positively scored entry as a winner, you'll all receive an email from me in the next few days to collect your size, prize preference and shipping information.

That means if you entered, and didn't delete your submission, you're going to get something.

Thank you to all that participated, we hope you enjoyed making these as much as our team has enjoyed laughing while viewing them.

Comment: I'm in; working on this during school :-D

Comment: Wait, crayons in our toes? But that would disqualify my entry, since it'd be free-foot, wouldn't it? :P

Comment: Your title almost initiated my meta-off-topic close reflex.

Comment: @Undo Why? I wasn't trying to do it with an Android app .

Comment: Wait... @TimPost can I get a nalgene bottle?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Can you make any comment I post using my phone sparkle?

Comment: @TimPost Yes, but only if you also let me make every 1 in 10 notifications's alert sound be Jarrod swearing.

Comment: Tim, I have to ask, when the site goes down, who do you go to for help? I mean, there's no [so], [sf], or [su] to ask.... like: *"I plugged my UPS in to my UPS, and now the command prompt is not showing up... what type of Coffee should I buy?"*

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi DEAL. That flim-and-flam is good for the whole family.

Comment: Tag it as featured

Comment: I have a feeling FGITW applies *greatly* here. :O

Comment: SE Unplugged, LP record, released May 16, 2014

Comment: What did I miss? What happened? (yeah, too lazy to go read the tavern transcript ;))

Comment: *`the folks that got pulled out of bed`* but it was 10 o'clock when it happened :D.

Comment: @user2284570 10am UTC which means 6am NY

Comment: @user2284570 em... What?

Comment: @ratchetfreak : I knew this, :) this was just for joking. I didn't used UTC, but [CEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time#Central_European_Summer_Time) which make 4am in NYC.

Comment: @user2284570 actually the [time line](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/85902805739/stack-exchange-primary-data-center-offline-may-16th) says 6:45 am UTC when power failed so 2 am NY time

Comment: @TimPost : Is it possible to get a picture of the real UPS power which caused the failure. Also I can't imagine a server room rely on a single UPS. Also is it Ok to dowvnote the drawings we don't like?

Comment: Hmm. Both of my submissions are over the threshold, so will they both occupy space in the top 10? I don't want to push #11 off the list because I submitted two entries.

Comment: @Doorknob You'll count for one slot, just like if you had one submission in the top 5 and one negatively scored with very few up-goats.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @rolfl That is easily solvable by offline copies of the  network!

Answer (score 56):

[image: yeah..]

Mobius power strip.  Just keep following it, I'm sure there's utility power somewhere along the cable..

Comment: +1, enough [Web 0.1](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Web_0_0x2e_1.aspx)

Comment: Yay, a moebiUPS trip!

Comment: (skip me on the goody box, I'll raid NYC for some swag when I'm out there next month)

Answer (score 52):

[image: Hamster wheel UPS]

Comment: ... to feed your rat!

Comment: Clearly its a hamster. Though, I suppose larger deployments might use capybara

Answer (score 45):

[image]

Comment: LOL LOL more LOL

Comment: **This.** Seriously, imagine the impact if it happens to Facebook. Or Twitter. Or both.

Comment: It's funny 'cuz in 9 months there will be a slew of questions on [parenting.SE] from folks with lots of rep on other sites!

Answer (score 36):

[image]

([Nick Craver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGCYr.jpg?s=256&g=1))

[image]

([George Beech](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1171131459/George.JPG))

[image]

([Geoff Dalgas](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-967UjmgW0po/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAApo/Ogr05LuvCyo/photo.jpg))

Comment: really funny! +1

Comment: The likeness here is quite good!

Comment: +1, even though creepy dentist Dalgas is going to give me *serious* nightmares.

Answer (score 30):

Here's a different angle on the matter: what happened shortly before Nick decided to spring into action and singlehandedly defeat the 0-pronged UPS power cable from hell?

[image]

Comment: Warning: contains trace amounts of copy paste

Comment: SOMEBODY SET US UP THE PLUG

Comment: This is epic.  Epic, I say.

Answer (score 25):

<sup>*Sincere apologies to Webmasters.SE, Mathematica.SE, Photography.SE, Money.SE, Cooking.SE, Scifi.SE, Judaism.SE, Security.SE, DBA.SE, and pretty much every SE site for doing a terrible job on your logos. :(*</sup>

My mouse hates me for this. I hope it's worth it.

[image]

Comment: Just looking at this makes my hand hurt. :-/ Nonetheless, excellent work!

Comment: Note to self: random drawings get more upvotes than [planned out storylines.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231768/180276) O_o

Comment: -1 I don't see dba.se :-(

Comment: @jcolebrand It's in the very top left corner. :-P

Comment: It's ok, I didn't really -1 :p http://i.imgur.com/aA1Upoz.png

Comment: @Doorknob [OBJECTION!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231769/13992)

Answer (score 22):

Click this to make it big and beautiful-like!

[image]

I went through https://stackexchange.com/about/team looking for devs, sorry if I missed anyone!

Comment: I didn't get listed... guess I'm really not a dev any more :(

Comment: @DavidFullerton You're the UPS.

Comment: I didn't get listed as well =( *sobbing*

Comment: my name is sklivvz not sklivzz =( /heartbroken

Comment: Aw crap. @Sklivvz sorry, I should have looked it up before guessing at which alphabet-ending letter was repeated twice.

Comment: Actually, the new unicode standards say that `zz` is code for `vz`, so we're fine.

Comment: I'm just pulling your leg. People misspell me all the time and that's pretty much the point of my nick

Comment: That's awesome :)

Comment: @Sklivvz Wait, it's not Skliwz?

Comment: Nice - I enjoyed this and would enjoy again :)

Answer (score 18):

[image]

Answer (score 18):

[image: balpha time]

Answer (score 17):

Wow, this was hard to fit onto a normal 8.5x11 piece of paper.

Also, this was done during school, if that's worth anything. :P

Apologies for lack of color / freehand red drawings; I would have messed up *way* too much if I did that. Click for a high-res version.

Features include:

- a haiku
- science
- a waffle
- a potato (dropped)
- a STAPPIT Bolt™

Start in the top right corner (after the big thank you) and work your way along. :P

[image]

Comment: Note to self: [random drawings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231784/180276) get more upvotes than planned out storylines. O_o

Answer (score 16):

[image: Don't forget!]

[image: Avec Couleur]

Comment: +1 for font. But if you made it red, it would be +2

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[image: NEVER FORGET the day unicorns ate the wire, 2014-05-16.]

Answer (score 12):

Just to get the ball rolling*...

[image: NEVER FORGET]

<sub>*I suppose technically I should freehand the text for the hand-drawn requirement, but for now I'll just go to lunch</sub>

Comment: Got some _very_ strange looks when I connected the dots by tracing my finger on my screen with the "CONNECT THE DOTS .. LA LA LA LA" Pee-Wee Herman voice. And here I thought people knew me.

Comment: Problem is they also know Paul Reubens...

Comment: I MISS POLLYANNA ... :-(

Answer (score 11):

[image: it's lonely when the lights go off]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Comment: @blunders Stack Exchange has status pages?

Comment: @strugee: Yes, **click this link** ([Read-only mode status message, Request to add links to official status pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231126/read-only-mode-status-message-request-to-add-links-to-official-status-pages)), **upvote the question**, and **follow the links I've listed in my question to the Twitter-for-SE-Status & Blog-for-SE-Status.**

Answer (score 9):

[image]

I ain't got time for freehand, foo.

Answer (score 8):

[image: New one]

Comment: for reference that is the hand pushing the plug into the devide. it's a "freehand" drawing even

Comment: I just wanted to say ir is funny. +1

Answer (score 8):

> [image: Never!]

<sup>Figure traced freehand from [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqRFK.gif), and embellished somewhat, obviously. I assume everyone knows [Blanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanka)'s tragic story of being mutated by electric eels, but some may not know that [his electrical attack](http://youtu.be/KiDM7laL6ms) often starts with a scratch (since you have to mash <kbd>jab</kbd>). Usually he's not just scratching himself, but desperate times call for desperate measures. I also imagine that this is what our SE street fighters looked like when they got called in to work. More power to 'em!</sup>

## ☆ *[MS PAINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_(software)) 4EVA* ☆

Comment: "this GIF" link is broken.

Comment: Fixed, sort of. The version linked now is the one I downloaded and enlarged in Paint, so it doesn't have the butt-scratching animation anymore, sadly.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### [image]

### Gimpshopping on Atom netbook

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ohhh... I thought this was a bug with the iOS app... anyway, SE might *want* you to forget this whole incident so they don't stay embarrased, but okay... remember the
[image: UPS plugged into itself]

It took me more time to scan this then to make it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]