# Give MSE a way to feature things on MSE itself rather than network-wide

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, meta, community-bulletin

MSE should have it's own Community Bulletin like the rest of the SE sites do. It would basically just be hot questions of the main MSE site, instead of the meta (which doesn't exist here, obviously)... but it would also allow us to pin things like this: [What happens when you plug a UPS into itself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself) as a pinned event.

Comment: I was considering asking for this very thing myself. It seems strange that topics that can end up affecting the entirity of the SE network don't get much visibility outside of MSE.

Comment: While we agree that this is a good idea - and think it's something that the Meta mods could make use of to help support community participation in MSE-specific discussions, it's unlikely we'll get to this in the near future but we will keep it in mind to improve this.

Comment: @Catija which is almost the same as what Tim said 8.5 years ago, lol. He should have put that status already back then. :)

Answer (score 13):

We're working on this. MSE *does* have a community bulletin, however *featured* posts here are going to circulate to child-meta sites under *their* respective community bulletins, so we have to be sort of selective in what we feature here (implementation on this is not fully complete, but that's what we're doing).

While it would be nice for that post to get more *immediate* exposure (so more folks can join in the fun) - it's not something that I'd want to feature, and syndicate to child meta sites across the network, out of fear that people would train themselves to ignore things we syndicate in the future.

We do have the ability to manually put things in *this* bulletin, but again - that isn't something I'd use the ability to do. Tweeting it later should have the desired effect, and I've linked to it in chat - when folks get back from lunch I'm certain you'll see some more activity on it.

It is Fry Day, after all :)

---

An aside -

Thinking about this more, I'd like to think about this more.

Comment: Well, while I'd like to see that post get more attention (obviously), I was more generally talking about future similar posts that (IMO) we clearly want to give featured prominence to users who are on MSE only, but not to all users on all sites. But glad to see this is [tag:status-planned]

Comment: I think we might be missing a better way to handle this, actually, going to give it a think. What I need is like [featured] with some kind of featured-override, without the meta tag. Finking.

Comment: PLZPLZPLZPLZ I want it

Comment: @nicael that immediately worries me.

Comment: :D Lol. I wanted it to be added

Comment: What about things like the new profile makeover?  It's weird that it's "featured on meta" on other sites but doesn't show up in the community bulletin here.

Comment: @Troyen When something is featured network-wide, it gets a lot of answers and repeatedly bumps on top of this site's front page. That's enough visibility already. Besides, everyone participating here is presumably active on at least one regular SE site, and will see the post in community bulletin there.