# Why doesn't this Featured post show up on the sidebar of MSE?

Tags: discussion, meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

This doesn't *really* feel like a bug, so it's probably just behavior I haven't noticed in the past. But shouldn't this [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) post be showing up under the bar on the right?

[image]

Since it's on MSE, it does show up on every other site's "Featured on Meta" list. But does that not exist here? The post is also eight hours old (or so), so I don't think it's a caching issue.

If it doesn't, it seems like it should. I've spent most of my day on MSE, and I'm just noticing that post now.

Comment: I'm really not sure whether this is a [tag:discussion] or [tag:bug], so I'll gladly change that to be appropriate if anyone can shed some light there.

Comment: This is by design, [feature request asking to change it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/mse-itself-should-have-a-community-bulletin) is under review.

Comment: It actually appears in the "Frequently Asked" section.... I don't know why, yet, since featured aren't normally FAQ's

Answer (score 2):

In the Community Bulletin of MSE only blogs are shown, this is by design now.

FAQ sidebar is filled by employees and it is not required for those posts to have the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.