# There should be a way to feature a question only on MSE, without it appearing in the community bulletin network-wide

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Meta Stack Exchange should have an option to feature a question which isn't visible to other SE communities.

For example, consider this question:
[Do we want accepted answers unpinned on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370716/1052107)

This question should be featured because it is important and decides the future of Meta Stack Exchange. Other sites also have featured their "Do you want the accepted answer to be unpinned on this site" Meta question, and ideally we should too, since this is a very important question and can change the future of the site. However, the problem is that if we use the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, it would appear in the community bulletin box across the Stack Exchange network - but this question is not useful/relevant to other communities, only for Meta Stack Exchange.

So I would like to propose a feature for moderators or staff members that would allow them to feature a question only in MSE, and not have it appear in the "community bulletin" box outside of MSE.

Maybe a way for moderators to set a Meta SE site banner or another way to advertise matters of importance.

Comment: So, besides the discussion regarding the pinning of the accepted answer, are there any other examples you could think of that would deserve being featured, but not for the entire network?

Comment: @Luuklag definitely there might not be but maybe proposal for site like Do you want triage on Meta SE such question might come on future- maybe 1 in 1 year? Sites like Anime SE rarely have question featured but do. We can let the staff take decision over this topic whether they consider this feature or not

Comment: Ah, so it's a solution in search of a problem then. Honestly, one other question (written by you) isn't the best impression or base for a feature request like this. If you feel your own question is not getting enough attention, that's what bounties are for.

Comment: draw-attention bounty would work about like you want, wouldn't it?

Comment: [Give MSE a way to feature things on MSE itself rather than network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/give-mse-a-way-to-feature-things-on-mse-itself-rather-than-network-wide) has an official response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not necessarily opposed to this idea, the only problem I see is terminology confusion (the caption of the sidebar widget is "Featured on Meta" - that would mean something different here than on other sites). We'd get used to that eventually.

But in practice, important discussions on Meta Stack Exchange (e.g. various Code of Conduct changes topics which weren't featured network-wide already) tend to generate *a lot* of activity in the form of new answers, edits and/or bounties. Those bump the question regularly, keeping it visible at all times. Right now, the bottommost post on the homepage (if you have it listing 50 questions) was active October 8th (four days ago); I can't imagine a post I would feature on Meta being inactive that long.

Comment: Yup so maybe we can use a widget "Important Meta Discussion" or something like that. Take language from one of SE communities - the English one for a good widget name

Comment: @JitendraSingh If you're already on Meta, you're here to check meta posts. And the would-be-featured post is amongst the top 10 or so posts, then what exactly is the problem? I almost never look at the bulletin while I'm on Meta.SE; I do check it while I'm on other sites though.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think all of this is necessary for just the one post *you've written*.

> This question should be featured because it is important and decides the future of Meta Stack Exchange.

You're making it sound like this discussion will have some life-changing, earth-shattering consequences. That's not true though, the decision can always be revisited if it turns out it doesn't work out. (This was also pointed out to you [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9035808#9035808), credit where credit is due).

> Other sites have also featured their "Do you want the accepted answer to be unpinned on this site" Meta question, and ideally we should too,

I don't think this is needed. I can't speak for all other sites, but usually *I* feature meta posts because activity on meta is low. Activity on Meta SE isn't low, the specific post in question had plenty of interaction.

> Maybe a way for mods to set a Meta SE site banner or other way to advertise matters of importance

There already is a system in place for questions that you feel deserve more attention: You (or any community member) can always put a bounty on it. And given that there are always a few posts bountied on MSE, I would say that that system is working fine.

As an added benefit, the existing system of reputation and bounties sidesteps the potential for a conflict of interest that your 'featuring' feature comes with, namely the potential reputation gain for featuring a post on this meta. Everyone is going to want to have their post featured and posting meta-Meta posts will hold the potential to become some kind of reputation-hunting festival.

There is no such conflict on child meta's since those are free of reputational gain, but here on MSE there is a reputation system, and there are bounties, so just use them.