# 2022: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2022 (and where did January go, right?) and dive head first into 2023, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Meta Stack Exchange over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 3 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 1,377 | 972 |
| Answers flagged | 212 | 2,139 |
| Comment flags handled | 3,536 | 2,586 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 5,846 | 5,038 |
| Comments flagged | 1,246 | 4,876 |
| Comments undeleted | 123 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 20 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 37 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 2,849 | 3,484 |
| Posts locked | 38 | 1,406 |
| Posts undeleted | 48 | 138 |
| Posts unlocked | 14 | 20 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 3,369 | 6,912 |
| Questions closed | 2,466 | 2,120 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 661 | 9,665 |
| Questions merged | 3 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 58 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 4 | 87 |
| Questions reopened | 51 | 80 |
| Questions unprotected | 2 | 2 |
| Revisions redacted | 20 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 134 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 152 | 0 |
| Tags merged | 43 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 225 | 3,795 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 96 | 593 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 25 | 514 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 68 | 1,445 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 6 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 149 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 10 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 4,130 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 115 | 386 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes). Community can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2021: a year in moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375072/2021-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2023! ^_^

Comment: These posts should be [featured].

Comment: I defer to mods on each site on that decision, @ElementsinSpace ;)

Comment: Featuring it here features it network wide - which I don't think is the intention?

Comment: Related to the above comments: [There should be a way to feature a question only on MSE, without it appearing in the community bulletin network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370781/986753)

Comment: Footnote 1 makes the Community figures useless you need to separate the -1 user from the rest of us