# Official diagrams for Stack Exchange data center setup?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

From time to time I've found various diagrams for the datacenter setup of the StackExchange setup in NYC. Are these kept anywhere in an official capacity? Are there more up to date versions than the ones in the blog articles? I'm asking because I'm curious as to the setup and would like to understand how the various pieces go together and work.

Articles with datacenter info:

- [Stack Overflow’s New York Data Center](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/10/29/1432571770/)
- [HSRP is not for WANs](http://blog.serverfault.com/2010/07/18/828122846/)
- [The Stack Exchange Architecture – 2011 Edition, Episode 1](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/09/30/the-stack-exchange-architecture-2011-edition-episode-1/)
- [How Stack Exchange gets the most out of HAProxy](http://brokenhaze.com/blog/2014/03/25/how-stack-exchange-gets-the-most-out-of-haproxy/)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself <--- should tell you everything you need to know

Comment: @Oded - taking that to mean no then?

Comment: We don't really have anything publicly consumable at this point. May have something in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Oded - OK. Are the diagrams that have been produced up to this point still reliable IYO or have things changed dramatically and should basically be ignored? I'm genuinely interested in learning from SE's approaches to things.

Comment: I doubt anything changed "dramatically". Things may have moved a bit and numbers would not be so accurate anymore, but things from the last couple of years should be broadly applicable.

Comment: @Oded - OK, thanks for getting back to me on this, it's appreciated!