# Was the Stack Exchange UPS plugged into itself a joke, or real?

Tags: discussion, downtime

Power issues caused the May 16, 2014 downtime, as stated in [Stack Exchange Primary Data Center Offline - May 16th, 2014](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/85902805739/stack-exchange-primary-data-center-offline-may-16th)

[What happens when you plug a UPS into itself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself) , a post for a picture contest, talks about it being caused by a UPS being plugged into itself.

I know that the photo in the post itself is a joke. But was the failure being caused by a UPS being plugged into itself also a joke, or real?

Yes, plugging a UPS into itself sounds like a pretty stupid mistake to make, but I assume it's possible when you've got a large and complex system.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/467240946372202496

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/467253860323840001

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Nick [tweeted](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/467240946372202496): (NSFW language warning)

> Turns out our "independent" power feeds which we built full redundancy behind all went to the same (now failing) UPS. One. Fucking. Job.

So as far as I can tell, it was due to  connecting all feeds to a single UPS which failed, then when the power went down, all servers went down as well.

Comment: Yeah, though this isn't _quite_ plugging a UPS to itself, that's close enough to have made a good joke. The DC power architecture we have was only done with redundancy in mind as we believed we were getting two redundant power supplies - that both came from one UPS was an unwelcome surprise.

Comment: @Oded thanks, and hope you (well, not you personally ;)) hired a good lawyer for a lawsuit against those who dared lying! :-)

Comment: Oded doesn't sue. Oded visits.

Comment: Only as last resort, @Bart. :)

Comment: Small nitpick, the verb is "tweet", not "twit". Twit has a [whole different meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twit) altogether.

Comment: @Cupcake totally right, what a shame! ;)