# App thinks I am Community, but I'm not - really!

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app

I was editing [a post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232041/152859) this morning via the app. All good, except this:

[>[image]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232041/152859)

No, I am *not* Community. I am Shadow Wizard. And if going that way, why no diamond as well? :)

Anyway, guess that when edited by the author it should just say "Edited", same way like in the desktop site.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this

Comment: @Arie were you able to reproduce? Found anything? :)

Comment: yes, able to repro, have a fix but this also involves a possible backend issue.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to see it deployed. :)

Comment: Do you have a link to the post you edited?

Comment: @Undo I've added it to the post, but don't think it's relevant - same bug happened today to somebody else on iPad. (this is what made me find this old report of mine :-))

Comment: @Bart why the bounty?

Comment: @Cai http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5648901#5648901

Comment: @Sha lol ok... yeh it is kinda pointless though, this certainly isn't an issue anymore

Comment: @Cai really?? lol, didn't check it. So you can post an answer saying that, and get a nice bounty. :)

Comment: @Arie any idea if it was ever deployed? Or fixed somehow in other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288048/307988), the editor was previously not fetched for answers (not sure if this was the case at that time), and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285758/307988) says that previously any user that returned `nil` would be erroneously attributed to "Community". So I assume the post was incorrectly trying to attribute the editor and failing.

Both of those situations have now changed (editors are always shown with the [new style attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287985/307988), and users can now return `nil`), so this is no longer an issue.

> [image]

Comment: And that's why you add a bounty. So you don't have to do the work yourself. :p

Comment: @Bart touché :)