# Editors aren't attributed on answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, attribution

The new post attribution works similar to the website with OP attributed first and the most recent editor attributed adjacent to that. This works as expected on questions but answers are missing any attribution for editors and simply have the "Edited..." text.

The following question and answer were both edited by me, for example...

[Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/81102/52050), with proper editor attribution:

> [image]

[Answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/81112/52050), with no editor attribution:

> [image]

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.1
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1373/

Comment: Editors are not supposed to edit content, only presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.2.5.

The last editor was never displayed before so we didn't bother fetching it.

Note that for community wikis and edits by the post author, the editor still won't appear.  This matches the web behavior.

Comment: Last editors name was displayed before wasn't it?

Comment: Probably as some point in the past.  I think questions could say "Edited by {name}" but we haven't been reading the editor on answers for at least a year.  Usually to get the editor name you would have to tap on "Edited" to get the list or revisions.

Comment: Fair enough, I must be misremembering.