# Did all sites just graduate?

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, beta-sites

Seems like **all** beta sites just lost the "Beta" status and have [increased](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) [privilege requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

I assume this is a bug, what happened here? [Did a unicorn ate the wires again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself/231786#231786)

Even though we at Code Review would love to be graduating, I bet a site like Puzzling are going to have a hard time, [as they only have one person with closing privileges](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).

Comment: I guess that optimization was a bad idea.

Comment: ROFLMAO, @MarcGravell, that is a good thing!

Comment: I think we've chased the problem away; normal function should be resumed

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Indeed you are correct. A unicorn did indeed eat the wires, becoming a unicord. It wasn't an unobserved side-effect of my performance refactorings *in any way*, so the current build I'm frantically pushing out will probably have no effect except for coincidence.

Ahem.

Comment: What? UNICORN is evolving!

Comment: @Stijn yup, at least one: [we managed to get a picture uploaded just before the data center melted](http://images.khinsider.com/Kingdom%20Hearts%20Dream%20Drop%20Distance/Renders/Spirits/Electricorn.png)

Comment: Someone have a Ditto over here? Unicords for everyone!

Comment: Those darn unicorns! A [booby](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Blue-footed_Booby_(Sula_nebouxii)_-displaying.jpg) would never eat the wires!!

Comment: @bluefeet he'd probably trip over his blue feet and impale the servers instead. Guess what kind of problems we had then!

Comment: Of course it wasn't an *unobserved* side effect. Seems it was very clearly observed.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I meant "unobserved prior to live deployment"

Comment: @MarcGravell Of course you did. Here, have some candy. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell, what do you mean live deployment? I thought that StackExchange was filled with professionals that don't need to test their code?

Comment: Google also suggests that Unicord is a company.  They're trying to get into our economy!