# Why is there only one person working on site designs?

Tags: discussion, design, beta-sites, graduating-sites

Directly related to [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september)

So I ask

> Why is there only one person working on site designs?

in response to

> We have one designer working on site designs these days at any given time.

[Ana's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september#comment858789_263905)

---

Could you (Stack Exchange) take designs from users and implement them on the sites to speed up the process of full graduation?

Could you (Stack Exchange) hire users on a part time basis to design a specific site, with or without the possibility of long(er) term employment?

I am sure this could play out in many different ways.

---

There are professionals willing to create site designs, why are we waiting on site designs for elevated privilege reputation levels?

Comment: Because no one is applying for https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/24481/senior-product-designer-stack-exchange

Comment: They just have to hire someone, right @random?

Comment: No, they have to interview them first to see if they have any skills

Comment: that posting has been up for over a month, at least.

Comment: There's a huge gap between creating a logo mockup and creating a website brand identity

Comment: To be fair, letting users just create the design really wouldn't speed up the process all that much. Creating the design is the fun and easy part. Cutting it apart and integrating it into all the aspects of the site and making sure it doesn't break everything is the long and intense part that holds everything up. This is also why our designers have been working hard at standardizing things more across the sites - to make it much easier to complete this design integration process in the future.

Comment: To be completely fair, Code Review has been waiting almost an entire year.  I am sure other sites have been waiting longer.

Comment: @Malachi To be fair, I'm sure Code Review can survive 6-8 more "weeks" without a design.

Comment: @animuson, seems like some sites get preference over others --> [CR Meta Tracking Graduation](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2538/18427)  seems Biology and Network Engineering were able to be fast tracked past us in the waiting line.  why is that?  their announcement came after ours and yet they are full graduated now, and Code Review isn't.

Comment: @Malachi Life is unfair and life will always be unfair.

Comment: I thought SE had at least three designers now? Are the other two just working on other projects?

Comment: it's not so much the design we are anxious for, it's more the privilege levels.

Comment: @Malachi It seems like some sites have gotten preference because it's partially true. I'm not familiar with all of the factors that go into determining the order of site designs, but there have been a few times I remember where CMs have asked for individual sites to get priority. That was back when elections didn't happen until designs rolled out, and certain sites in the graduation queue found themselves in need of new mods. Rather than appoint new pro tems, it seemed better to provide elections. Resolving that weirdness is actually one reason we're trying design-independent graduation now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Stack Exchange employs a team of 6 designers, and as others have noted, [we're looking to hire more](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/24481/senior-product-designer-stack-exchange). 6 is a tiny number of designers for a company like ours. One reason it's so small is that we don't just hire visual designers who create illustrations and designs in Photoshop and let others convert them for the web. As designer Donna Choi noted in [her recent blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/08/why-stack-overflow-is-a-good-workplace-for-women/):

> Every designer executes on a wide range of problems - from designing application flows to illustrating unicorns to building out front-end experiences.

We have an incredibly well-rounded design team, each member of which is vital to the projects they're working on, right from the kickoff. They own huge projects, they design interactions, and they drive key feature development. *And* they create illustrations and custom skins for SE sites.

All of this is to say that our design positions are not just design positions. They're equal parts graphic design, product management, HCI, and front-end development. This kind of hybrid role is really hard to hire for, so that's one reason we still have a very small design team.

That's the first piece.

@animuson [summed up the second piece](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263909/why-is-there-only-one-person-working-on-site-designs#comment858824_263909) nicely:

> To be fair, letting users just create the design really wouldn't speed up the process all that much. Creating the design is the fun and easy part. Cutting it apart and integrating it into all the aspects of the site and making sure it doesn't break everything is the long and intense part that holds everything up. This is also why our designers have been working hard at standardizing things more across the sites - to make it much easier to complete this design integration process in the future.

Custom site designs weren't designed to be future-proof. We're encountering scale problems that weren't anticipated when the system was implemented. For example, we recently rolled out [a redesign of the user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/165581). It was a nightmare to roll it out across the network because each graduated site had just enough customization to require the profile conversion to be done by hand. Instead of doing that, the design team decided that the smarter choice would be to standardize site designs, so that this and future new features can be more efficiently rolled out across the network.

It's taking a long time, because we have a lot of sites. They're 73% done with this project, and it's slow going, because each designer also has about a thousand other projects on their desk. Site designs are in the same situation. There's a backlog, and the backlog is being worked on, but just throwing more people at the problem - whether by hiring them or by soliciting help from users - probably isn't going to make the backlog go away any faster.

We do hire freelancers and outsource projects to other design firms occasionally, but that sort of thing is usually one-off projects and straight-up graphic design projects. Things like site designs that are so tightly integrated with what it means to be a Stack Exchange community are kept in-house.

Comment: I think it has been already said before, but why not advertise your open design position [here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1340/19174)?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - Not sure... first I've heard of it. Will shop the idea around.

Answer (score 11):

> Why is there only one person working on site designs?

First, because they hired just one person to do this. Feel free to [apply to become the second](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/24481/senior-product-designer-stack-exchange).

> Could you (Stack Exchange) take designs from users and implement them on the sites to speed up the process of full graduation?

Possibly they can, but that doesn't help much. How long would it take for a community to come to a consensus on this? It will take months to create and pick the designs. And then they should be implemented... This is mostly the job of one person in the end.

All of this is not something a community should do since it also involves the identity of the Stack Exchange company. Every site will be added to the corporate identity. That means there isn't just a single designer involved in all this, but also a lot of decision makers. That just isn't the responsibility of the community.

Comment: some communities would have decided on a design already. like Code Review.  some of the users there have been working on a design since before they announced our "Graduation" almost a year ago. I find your argument lacking in that regard.

Comment: That is true, but is that the identity SE thinks it should be?

Comment: They don't seem like they are taking ideas?  each site is supposed to be community not SE. so ask us, tell us, hear us.

Comment: It is a business!

Comment: @Malachi They do listen and engage in discussions and feature-requests a *great* deal. Think about how little other sites care about what their end users want, and then reconsider how much Stack Exchange *actually does* based on feature-requests and discussions in Metas. As Patrick said, it is a business, and they're responsible for the business side and if the company turns a profit and works, not the community . Community has a say but that does not mean Stack have to implement. Every user has an equal opinion here, but imagine if *all* feature-requests were implemented. *shudder*