# How does the Constable badge work in the new graduation model?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, moderators, pro-tem-moderators

Recall the description of the Constable badge:

> Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

Now that "site graduation" isn't a single discrete thing, until what point do you have to be a mod to earn a Constable badge?

The reason I'm asking: Anime.SE has not graduated, but it has had [elections](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/1). I was [appointed as a moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/new-moderator-pro-tem-announcement) in April of this year, and ceased to be a moderator when elections concluded in August (on account of not winning the election). I wasn't pro-tem for a full year, nor was I pro-tem through site graduation, but I *was* pro-tem until the point when we no longer had pro-tem moderators. Should I get a Constable badge?

Comment: Certainly. I'm a little surprised you didn't.

Comment: I think the spirit of the badge is: “Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least a year and wasn’t fired or burnt out within a year.”

Comment: @Wrzlprmft not that I defend anyone, but I think it's a bit unfair since moderator slots are limited, and I don't think *fired* (this gives negative perception) is certainly the case here.

Comment: @AndrewT.: I did not want to suggest that – on the contrary: I think that Senshin getting the badge would very well be within its spirit, as he neither resigned nor was fired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We ... hit a number of snags when implementing [design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september), but there's an end in sight there. Once we're done, DI graduation will behave pretty much the same as our previous version of graduation, minus the design and a privilege level change.

What this means for you is this: Anime *has* graduated. <s>Once we're done unbreaking the backend side of things (ETA about a week?), badge queries will run and you should end up with your badge.</s> We fixed our design-independent graduation process, so badges should be awarded as they would be in any previous graduation going forward.

Comment: You seem to have unbroken your stuff; I was indeed awarded [the badge](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/constable?userid=1908) just now.

Comment: @senshin I was just heading over to let you know that you should see it soon. :)

Answer (score 8):

Besides "one year", I think the only logical endpoint is specifically the end of the first election. This is usually, though not necessarily always, the first measurable milestone of a graduating site. But the key feature is that, once the election is over, we know for sure a pro tem didn't just wash out or give up. They (you) went the distance.

From what I can tell, though, from other sites, the badge actually is awarded a year after appointment to candidates that served through election, even if they aren't elected. E.g. on GIS, the [badges](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/badges/127/constable) were awarded months after [the first election](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election) to four pro-tem mods (none of whom were elected) and a little over a year after the site started. This is deeply strange, but take heart: you may yet get your badge next April.