# Able to create non-existent site tags by mentioning them in chat message

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, chat

You know how it takes 1500 rep to create a tag? Well, I did it with 402.

1. Go to chat
2. Post the tag in chat (type [testy-doodles](/questions/tagged/testy-doodles))
3. Make a question.

Example:

[image: chat message]

Note: I had to write some random stuff to get past the automated question quality detection.

[image: somebody typed into a box]
[image: here is a pencil]
[image: pedometer is broken]

[Link to profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41088/uo%C9%A5%CA%87%CA%8Ep%CA%8Ez%C9%90%C9%B9c): [https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41088/uoɥʇʎpʎzɐɹc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41088/uo%C9%A5%CA%87%CA%8Ep%CA%8Ez%C9%90%C9%B9c)

Comment: Well, it's poor coincidence you thought that creating the tag got anything to  do with posting in chat. It's totally not relevant.

Answer (score 9):

No, you didn't. On Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, which used to be a beta site, but is now in [Phase 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) of its graduation, the minimum amount of reputation to create a tag is [150](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), not 300 (which is the standard) or 1500 (which is for Stack Overflow).

Comment: It's out of beta already; they just don't have a theme yet -.-

Comment: @CrazyPython you're right - I corrected this now. Until the theme is live, sites tend to keep the beta-levels for privileges.

Comment: And it certainly won't be 1500 even after site graduates, 300 max.

Comment: Why is that? The look of the site should not affect its mechanics.

Comment: @nicael thanks, I got confused because OP mentioned 1500.

Comment: @CrazyPython see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) - Code Golf is still in Phase 1.

Answer (score 6):

It's not 1500 everywhere, but only on Stack Overflow.

> [image]