# How long until graduated sites get a new site design and increased privileges threshold?

Tags: support, privileges, election, graduating-sites, full-sites

The August 2015 announcement [Design-Independent Graduation is on for early September!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) says that there are 2 phases after a site has graduated:

> ### Phase 1
>
> *The Community Team announces that a site is cleared for graduation. Without delay...*
>
> - the beta label is removed
> - elections are held
> - migration paths are set up
> - community ads are run
>
> ### Phase 2
>
> *Then, as it becomes available:*
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

In further updates from staff in later years, it's been made clear that [a custom design and increased privilege thresholds are no longer tied together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/377214), so Phase 2 has been essentially split into two, and also that [mod elections and formal graduation are no longer tied together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727/278659), so Phase 1 has also been essentially split.

**How long do subsequent phases occur after the site has graduated?** In other words, how long does it take for a site to get its own unique design, increased privileges threshold, and mod elections, after it has launched?

Is there a post that lists the timing between the phases for past graduated sites?

Comment: [How long is a piece of string?](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how_long_is_a_piece_of_string)

Comment: Well, since sites staying in beta can be arbitrarily longer or shorter than what you might expect (see the [recent mass graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096)), I would not expect anything regarding the timing of phase 2.

Comment: Very related: [When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368463/335251)

Comment: Also relevant: [With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/335251) (We've now [posted an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/335251).)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sources used for this answer:

- **Graduation dates:** [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) or [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#page=1&pagesize=10000&filter=!)QnKmPBxB(NhUB5jfSr)730d&run=true).
- **Design dates and increased privilege dates:** the site's meta for announcements of new designs.
- **Full mod election dates:** the list of elections found at `/election` on every site, plus some digging to understand if they're pro-tem or full elections.

### Increased privilege thresholds

These are **no longer applied** for newly graduating sites, unless a site specifically asks for it. This was confirmed on [27 February 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387045/278659), and only two sites ([Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Golf and Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), both in 2019) were given increased privilege thresholds since 2016. The full list of recently (since 2015) graduating sites with increased privilege thresholds is as follows. All of them got both a design and increased privilege thresholds on the same day.

| Site | Graduation | Design and increased privileges | Duration | Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blender | 2015-06-16 | 2016-01-28 | 7 months | [Link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/new-site-design-is-live) |
| Network Engineering | 2015-06-23 | 2015-06-23 | same day | [Link](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/site-graduated-new-design-launched) |
| Cryptography | 2015-06-30 | 2015-12-21 | 6 months | [Link](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/643) |
| Code Review | 2015-07-14 | 2015-11-25 | 4 months | [Link](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6186) |
| Computer Science | 2015-08-18 | 2016-02-01 | 5 months | [Link](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1211) |
| Anime & Manga | 2015-08-25 | 2019-04-30 | 44 months | [Link](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/anime-manga-site-design) |
| Magento | 2015-09-01 | 2016-02-26 | 6 months | [Link](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/835) |
| English Language Learners | 2015-09-08 | 2016-02-25 | 6 months | [Link](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2945/44986) |
| Music: Practice & Theory | 2015-09-09 | 2016-03-30 | 7 months | [Link](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2433) |
| Software Recommendations | 2015-09-09 | 2016-04-22 | 7 months | [Link](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519) |
| Japanese Language | 2015-09-09 | 2016-06-08 | 9 months | [Link](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1583) |
| Worldbuilding | 2015-11-16 | 2016-05-17 | 6 months | [Link](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3551/2235) |
| Emacs | 2015-11-16 | 2016-05-24 | 6 months | [Link](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/408) |
| Aviation | 2015-11-16 | 2016-07-01 | 7 months | [Link](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3008) |
| Signal Processing | 2015-11-16 | 2016-10-05 | 11 months | [Link](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1421) |
| Raspberry Pi | 2015-11-17 | 2015-11-17 | same day | [Link](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597) |
| Code Golf & Coding Challenges | 2016-02-23 | 2019-06-11 | same day | [Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live) |
| Puzzling | 2016-05-04 | 2016-05-04 | same day | [Link](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4720/5373) |

---

### Site design and full moderator elections

This is an **incomplete** list, made community wiki in case anyone wishes to add to it. The sites are sorted by graduation date, then by design date (if applicable), then by name in alphabetical order.

The duration confirms that "it varies". The sites with '?' are still waiting for their design or full moderator elections. The date in the election column is the *start* date (so "-2 weeks" indicates an election whose end coincided with the graduation date) of the first *attempted* full election (regardless of whether or not it had enough candidates to actually run as an election - seven sites, [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election) and [Bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/election) and [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election) and [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election) and [Stellar](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/election) and [Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/election) and [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/election), haven't had successful full elections yet, but attempts were made so those dates are included in the table). The last column is a link to the announcement of the design.

Prior to [24 May 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/377214), site design and increased privileges always occurred on the same day, as they were considered part of the same phase of site graduation, unless the site had a design to begin with (due to a site sponsorship). Prior to [30 April 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/278659), all moderator elections were full mod elections, as pro-tem elections for not-yet-graduated sites started for the first time in 2018.

| Site | Graduation | Design | Duration | Election began | Duration | Link(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blender | 2015-06-16 | 2016-01-28 | 7 months | 2016-06-01 | 12 months | [Link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/new-site-design-is-live) |
| Network Engineering | 2015-06-23 | 2015-06-23 | same day | 2015-06-01 | -3 weeks | [Link](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/site-graduated-new-design-launched) |
| Cryptography | 2015-06-30 | 2015-12-21 | 6 months | 2015-06-15 | -2 weeks |  |
| Code Review | 2015-07-14 | 2015-11-25 | 4 months | 2015-06-29 | -2 weeks |  |
| Computer Science | 2015-08-18 | 2016-02-01 | 5 months | 2016-08-03 | 12 months |  |
| Anime & Manga | 2015-08-25 | 2019-04-30 | 44 months | 2015-08-10 | -2 weeks | [Link](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/anime-manga-site-design) |
| Magento | 2015-09-01 | 2016-02-26 | 6 months | 2015-08-17 | -2 weeks |  |
| English Language Learners | 2015-09-08 | 2016-02-25 | 6 months | 2015-08-24 | -2 weeks |  |
| Music: Practice & Theory | 2015-09-09 | 2016-03-30 | 7 months | 2015-11-09 | 2 months |  |
| Software Recommendations | 2015-09-09 | 2016-04-22 | 7 months | 2015-11-30 | 2 months |  |
| Japanese Language | 2015-09-09 | 2016-06-08 | 9 months | 2015-11-02 | 2 months |  |
| Worldbuilding | 2015-11-16 | 2016-05-17 | 6 months | 2016-02-01 | 3 months |  |
| Emacs | 2015-11-16 | 2016-05-24 | 6 months | 2016-02-08 | 3 months |  |
| Aviation | 2015-11-16 | 2016-07-01 | 7 months | 2016-03-14 | 4 months |  |
| Signal Processing | 2015-11-16 | 2016-10-05 | 11 months | 2016-03-07 | 4 months |  |
| Raspberry Pi | 2015-11-17 | 2015-11-17 | same day | 2015-12-07 | <1 month |  |
| Code Golf & Coding Challenges | 2016-02-23 | 2019-06-11 | 39 months | 2016-03-21 | 1 month | [Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live) |
| Puzzling | 2016-05-04 | 2016-05-04 | same day | 2016-07-11 | 2 months |  |
| Law | 2016-07-06 | ? |  | 2016-07-18 | <1 month |  |
| Philosophy | 2016-07-06 | 2022-09-16 | 74 months | 2016-07-25 | <1 month | [Link](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair | 2016-09-13 | 2022-08-10 | 71 months | 2016-10-10 | 1 month | [Link](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/new-design-launched) |
| Quantitative Finance | 2016-12-12 | 2023-03-30 | 75 months | 2017-02-06 | 2 months | [Link](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Ethereum | 2017-06-26 | 2022-07-14 | 61 months | 2017-07-03 | <1 month | [Link](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/719/new-site-design-launched) |
| Data Science | 2017-07-10 | 2022-08-10 | 61 months | 2017-07-31 | <1 month | [Link](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/new-design-launched) |
| Arduino | 2017-07-17 | 2022-07-12 | 60 months | 2017-08-14 | 1 month | [Link](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/new-site-design-launched) |
| Bitcoin | 2017-10-09 | 2022-09-16 | 59 months | 2017-10-16 | <1 month | [Link](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Spanish Language | 2019-08-01 | 2022-09-22 | 37 months | 2020-10-05 | 14 months | [Link](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/new-design-launched) |
| French Language | 2019-08-01 | 2022-09-30 | 37 months | 2020-05-25 | 9 months | [Link](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/new-site-design-launched) |
| German Language | 2019-08-01 | 2022-09-30 | 37 months | 2020-11-16 | 15 months | [Link](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/new-site-design-launched) |
| Sound Design | 2019-08-01 | 2022-12-14 | 40 months |  |  | [Link](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497) |
| Chess | 2019-08-01 | 2023-04-14 | 44 months |  |  | [Link](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Gardening and Landscaping | 2019-08-01 | 2023-04-13 | 44 months | 2021-09-13 | 25 months | [Link](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Writing | 2019-08-01 | 2023-04-13 | 44 months | 2021-11-01 | 27 months | [Link](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Islam | 2019-08-01 | 2023-08-23 | 48 months | 2021-06-28 | 22 months | [Link](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/your-new-site-design-is-live) |
| Biblical Hermeneutics | 2019-08-01 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Board & Card Games | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-10-18 | 26 months |  |
| Bricks | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-09-27 | 25 months |  |
| Computational Science | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-11-01 | 27 months |  |
| Chinese Language | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2020-06-29 | 10 months |  |
| History | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2020-10-19 | 14 months |  |
| Homebrewing | 2019-08-01 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Linguistics | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-08-23 | 24 months |  |
| Martial Arts | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-10-04 | 26 months |  |
| Parenting | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2020-05-25 | 9 months |  |
| Physical Fitness | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-08-09 | 24 months |  |
| Poker | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-09-27 | 25 months |  |
| Project Management | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-08-02 | 24 months |  |
| Psychology and Neuroscience | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-09-20 | 25 months |  |
| Russian Language | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-11-01 | 27 months |  |
| Software Testing & Quality Assurance | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-09-20 | 25 months |  |
| Sports | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2020-06-01 | 10 months |  |
| The Great Outdoors | 2019-08-01 | ? |  | 2021-06-28 | 22 months |  |
| Video Production | 2019-08-01 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Русский язык | 2019-08-01 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Quantum Computing | 2021-12-16 | 2018-03-12 | -45 months |  |  | [Link](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1) |
| Artificial Intelligence | 2021-12-16 | 2018-09-05 | -39 months |  |  | [Link](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1404) |
| 3D Printing | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Amateur Radio | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Arts and Crafts | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-03-07 | 3 months |  |
| Astronomy | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Beer, Wine, and Spirits | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Bioinformatics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-09-19 | 9 months |  |
| Buddhism | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| CiviCRM | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Coffee | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-10-24 | 10 months |  |
| Computer Graphics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Computer Science Educators | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| DevOps | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Drones and Model Aircraft | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Earth Science | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Ebooks | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Economics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Engineering | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-09-19 | 9 months |  |
| EOS.IO | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Esperanto Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Expatriates | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Freelancing | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Genealogy & Family History | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Hinduism | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| History of Science and Mathematics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Iota | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Internet of Things | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Italian Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Joomla | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2023-02-21 | 14 months |  |
| Korean Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Language Learning | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Latin Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-08-15 | 8 months |  |
| Lifehacks | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-07-25 | 7 months |  |
| Literature | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2023-03-28 | 15 months |  |
| Mathematics Educators | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-10-22 | 10 months |  |
| Matter Modeling | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Monero | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Mythology and Folklore | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Open Source | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Operations Research | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-03-14 | 3 months |  |
| Pets | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-08-08 | 8 months |  |
| Politics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-09-26 | 9 months |  |
| Portuguese Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Retrocomputing | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Reverse Engineering | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Robotics | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2023-05-09 | 17 months |  |
| Sitecore | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-08-22 | 8 months |  |
| Space Exploration | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-03-28 | 3 months |  |
| Stellar | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2023-02-28 | 14 months |  |
| Sustainable Living | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-05-16 | 5 months |  |
| Tezos | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-07-18 | 7 months |  |
| Tor | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2022-05-23 | 5 months |  |
| Tridion | 2021-12-16 | ? |  | 2023-03-07 | 15 months |  |
| Ukrainian Language | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Vi and Vim | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Woodworking | 2021-12-16 | ? |  |  |  |  |
| Cardano | 2022-02-03 | ? |  | 2022-09-19 | 7 months |  |

Comment: A relevant post by one of our designers from earlier today: [Custom German Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697/8844) :)

Comment: The comments on this MSE question include links to several similar posts on other sites that have been waiting a while for a design: [With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/335251)

Comment: Possibly helpful (on Code Review Meta): [Tracking Graduation Progress](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2538)

Comment: @Peilonrayz That's in need of some updates since 2019.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not really. "This question is really about tracking Code Review's 'probable' spot in line". "Code Review  2015-07-14  2015-11-25  4 months"

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm of mind to roll back your edits, because: 1. unclear cases, such as the ones you pointed out at the bottom, as well as cases where the team opted to start an election as a "full" election but treat it as a "pro tem" election and simply appoint the candidates as pro tem mods if there weren't enough nominees to make them competitive (meaning when this happens, a cell that was initially added has to be removed), and 2. the question didn't ask about elections, only about site designs and increased privileges, so your added info is extraneous and doesn't address the question.

Comment: Also, can you please explain why you edited the date formats? As far as I can tell, date formats fall under the rule that language (e.g., American English vs. British English) should not be edited, so can you please explain why you changed them?

Comment: @Sonic It's a CW post which I've just put a huge amount of time and effort into improving, so you'd better not roll back my edits. I'm open to using a different metric for "first election", such as the first *successful* full election rather than the first *attempt* (arguably even attempting shows that the site is somehow *seen* as having reached the stage to be ready for that, but a successful election is perhaps a better indicator of *actually* having reached that stage), but don't remove useful and relevant information from this post.

Comment: Yes, arguably some parts of this answer don't directly address the original question, but that's been true for a long time. It's turned into a useful FAQ-style post, so the more information the better. I've also pinged the OP in case they want to edit a mention of mod elections into their question to make the Q&A fit more snugly together. Re date formatting, I added some dates in a natural format and then tried to make sure everything was consistent. (The table has Y-M-D and the text has D-M-Y, but at least consistent within the table and consistent within the text.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sorry if the first part of my comment came across as insensitive to your work. I figured that out, which is why I reached out in the comments instead of going straight for the button. Personally, I think the info about elections makes this super convoluted and it belongs in a separate post. Keep in mind that at the time this was asked, it was only asking about one thing, which is how long it takes from sites leaving beta to them getting a design, which was together with increased privileges at the time. The reason I separated those out later is due to the 2023 announcement.

Comment: @Sonic Ah, I now see that it was you who edited the OP after the two parts of Phase 2 were separated from each other, as originally it simply asked for the gap between (graduation+election) and (design+privileges). So if I do the same regarding Phase 1, everything will be solved. The situations are analogous, as you changed the OP and this answer when design and privileges were no longer connected, so we can also change it to show that graduation and elections are no longer connected.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The edit was based off of the title of the post, which has not changed at all since it was originally asked. Increased privileges were mentioned in the original post, even if they were later disconnected from site designs. On the other hand, the original post never made any mention of elections. In hindsight, I should have kept the original post as it was, editing that quote into the answer instead, but my prior comments that raise concerns over this post becoming convoluted due to the introduction of elections, and adding confusion due to the unclear cases mentioned, still stand.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Also, it is still true that "elections are held" once a site leaves beta. The reason you noticed a delay between elections for the 59 sites that left beta in late 2021 was because of the community team's bandwidth (they could only run a couple elections at a time). The post you linked to re. it being split is simply a *proposal*, not an announcement - the author didn't work for SE yet at the time she posted that. If you go through those 59 sites' metas and find their graduation announcements, you'll see that they mention "shortly" having elections. It's not so that they were split