# How to distinguish beta sites from non-beta sites in a cross-site SEDE query?

Tags: support, data-explorer, beta-sites

The question [Mod team updates and site status](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9250/69714) on Code Review Meta contains a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199310/site-badge-rankings) by @rolfl to compare sites on how many of a certain badge they have. My eyes fell on the following comment

> Note that 'Caucus' is listed in the results. This is a special badge that is
>   not used to rank the sites. The `Caucus` badge is awarded when there's an
>   election, so Caucus is only used to identify graduated, and non-graduated
>   sites.

which was a neat trick, but it doesn't work anymore since we now have [elections on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/295232), which award Caucus badges as well.

What other options do we have to distinguish beta sites from graduated sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- Check for Caucus badges awarded before [May 15th, 2018](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/1), but this will produce false results for sites which graduated after that date. (FWIW, there have been none so far, but they could be 'hard-coded' in the query.)
- Check for [Sheriff badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/208/sheriff) - these are only awarded on graduated sites, but it takes about a year after graduation for them to be awarded, so those exceptions have to be hard-coded as well.
- Check for users' reputation and the actions they take. E.g. if all recent edits (to non-Community wiki posts) are made by the authors *or* by people with 2000 or more reputation, you know it's a graduated site. The trouble here is that users can go under the threshold after posting bounties (suspended users are rather easy to filter out by reputation).