# List of moderators on stackexchange.com doesn't know about some elections

Tags: bug, moderators, election, stackexchange.com

There's a [list of all ♦ moderators in the network](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users) on stackexchange.com, with details about when a moderator was elected. However, it doesn't seem to know about [pro-tempore elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/295232), which can be seen e.g. on my own entry:

[image]

I would expect a link to https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1 there. Also, other (older?) elections are missing, e.g. in the case of @RoryAlsop/@DoktorMayhem on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/1) and [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/1):

[image]

Comment: Technically, pro-tem moderators are, and always have been, manually appointed by SE. SE simply uses the elections to know who to appoint. So the page is technically correct. But yeah, I'd agree to put a link to the election page there so that it's clear to others, especially if the election is competitive.