# Year of being elected as moderator missing in stackexchange.com/about/moderators

Tags: discussion, bug, stackexchange.com

There are 10 [moderators for Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) as of writing this post.

[image: Moderators]

In https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators, the year of being elected as moderator is missing for one of the moderators ([Marco Ceppi♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/41/marco-ceppi)).

[image: List of Moderators of Ask Ubuntu in Stack Exchange website]

Why is the year of being elected as moderator missing only for one of the moderators?

Answer (score 10):

Marco Ceppi was already a ♦ moderator during the beta-phase of Ask Ubuntu, at least if I read the [comments under his nomination](https://askubuntu.com/election/1#post-24492) correctly. Currently, that page only knows about elections on graduated sites, see my recent bug report: [List of moderators on stackexchange.com doesn't know about pro-tem elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354459/295232), but this is a similar problem I guess.

Comment: So, is my post a duplicate of yours?

Comment: No, because Marco was elected in a normal election.

Comment: Ok! But, will SE look into this issue? I've kinda lost hope due to no response from SE staff on my previous bug post. I also had a bounty on the previous post, asking for an authoritative reference,  but got no response..

Comment: I understand, but this is a rather low-priority bug if you ask me. There are thousands of open bugs right now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?tab=Unanswered

Comment: I've heard from people that SE employees are short handed. Why can't they hire more people?

Comment: @technastic_tc [they are](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here)

Comment: @technastic_tc hiring staff also costs money. And even with an abundance of staff some bugs are still not urgent or need fixing.