# Why do some StackExchange sites have a nice logo and others a simple speech bubble with 2 letters?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, beta-sites, logo, graduating-sites

From my Stack Exchange sites:

**Nice logos**
[image: Nice logos]

**Simple boring logos**
[image: Simple logos]

Why is that?

1. Not enough questions or people joined to the site
2. Nobody did design a cool logo
3. Other reason

Answer (score 12):

Beta sites all have the default logo of the bubble containing the site initials.

[image]

Once a site graduates, it gets its own custom site logo to differentiate it from the sites still in beta. These vary immensely depending on the site.

Comment: Ok, so next question is what a graduation is... yes... I know... It is already here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites  ;-)

Comment: Note that... since [design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905), even [sites that have graduated for a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/241919) can still stuck with the "beta" theme. /cc @nephewtom

Comment: Sorry, did not get that... Are there graduated sites that do have boring logos?

Comment: @nephewtom yes, [anime.se] is one of the sites that has graduated (since 2015) but not yet received any site design.