# When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding?

Tags: support, design, logo, graduating-sites

I'm hesitating to ask this question because we have been asked for years to be patient. And I think we have been. But for the last one/two years I can no longer find any updates on that matter. It's been six years since the [design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) was introduced, stating:

> ## Phase 2
>
> *Then, as it becomes available:*
>
> - the site gets their custom design.
> - privilege thresholds are increased to graduated site levels

But when will it come available? Ethereum StackExchange [graduated](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/congratulations-ethereum-is-graduating) **four** years ago. It graduated with a blasting 35 questions/day, 10000 users, and an incredible 30000 visits per day.

Today, it still holds up, and even though I lost track of the actual activity numbers, I would guess this site must generate some real traffic. According to [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), Ethereum StackExchange is the most active network site without a custom theme or logo.

When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding? In 2017, it pretty much looked as if designs [take between 6 and 9 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290359/how-long-until-graduated-sites-get-a-new-site-design-and-increased-privileges-th) to be rolled out. But that process seemingly stalled. Is it due to the [rollout of responsive designs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post)? But that post hasn't been updated for two years either.

What's the latest on site designs and when will my site get [some attention](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/can-we-get-a-logo-and-a-header)?

Comment: actual activity numbers [can be found here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest)

Comment: They stopped making designs as at that time they lacked the designers. Now another point is that it is too hard to integrate with darkmode and a responsive design for the most part.

Comment: And adding a logo would be hard? What's the best way to reach CMs and Staff nowadays?

Comment: @Afr what you are doing is the correct way to ask. (Though ranting about it on Twitter [might help you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/318341#318341))

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica too soon man... Too soon

Comment: Relevant: [With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/335251) (We've now [posted an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/335251).)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Luuklag mentioned there has been a long pause on this due to a lack of design resources and the challenges of integrating with darkmode, etc. Unfortunately site themes are not going to be coming in 2021.

However, some good news that we can share is we're starting to discuss ways we can work on site design in the future. I don't have a timeline yet, but we do have have an idea that we would love your feedback on.

Customization in the past was very complex. One idea we're interested in exploring is what if in the future, moderators had tools to enable making some design changes on a site once it left beta. This would be things like the site logo, banner, and color. We may have limitations on color choices to guarantee legibility.

I'm sorry that we don't have a timeline to share with you right now. You're right that you've all been patiently waiting for this. Again what we're presenting here is just an idea at this point, but we'd love your feedback.

Comment: Rosie, you might be better off making this a separate post and referring to this (and there are probably many more similar) question(s). That would increase visibility drastically and would result in more feedback on the topic.

Comment: Involving the communities to make their site their own would be great! The mods could run contests to get ideas about headline images and logos from their users.

Comment: @Luuklag We will have a post when we know the timeline.  I understand that people will be excited about this sort of announcement, but since we're so unsure about when it will actually happen, we're trying to avoid making a huge deal about this. I’m looking forward to being able to share more in the future though. I’m excited for this too!

Comment: Thank you. What's the best way to stay updated on that matter? I had difficulties finding any information.

Comment: @Afr We'll be posting when we know the timeline for this and I'll feature it at that time so it's easy for people to find and follow.

Comment: @Rosie Thank you for your answer. Are there any updates on this topic? I was thinking of making a `feature-request` based on this question: [Can communities come up with their own site design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374415/578690), but wanted to check with you first.

Comment: @TimurShtatland you can read the update here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378888/with-new-designs-planned-for-some-sites-are-there-plans-to-tackle-the-backlog/378976#378976 The design team has been working through the backlog of sites that need a redesign but we will outreach to communities when their site is slated for redesign.