# Can communities come up with their own site design?

Tags: discussion, design, community, beta-sites

What if a formerly beta site itself (on the site meta) comes up with a temporary design and provides all the needed images in the required formats and resolutions? Would Stack Exchange consider such a community-provided, community-approved design for use or reuse in the foreseeable future? Asking for Politics SE and Parenting SE, although the comments below might list a few additional sites that could be interested.

**References:**

Many. For example:

> We know the sites that lost their “Beta” label in 2019 are still waiting for a redesign, too. We hope that some sort of design love (or perhaps theme customization) will come in the future, but we don't have concrete details of what this will look like or a timeline of when this will happen.

[Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/578690)

---

> It’s become clear to me that the Stack Exchange Network has higher priority work for their design team than making beautiful site designs for our many “graduated” sites… and that’s OK. It doesn’t mean that they will never design another site (hopefully) but it does mean that we should probably work towards letting them off the hook further by allowing them do the designs in their own time rather than tying some part of the “graduation” process to their work.

[Let's break up with "Graduation" and remove a bunch of "Beta" labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727/578690)

---

> However, some good news that we can share is we're starting to discuss ways we can work on site design in the future.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369555/578690

Comment: The software currently ties getting a design to increasing the site's reputation levels to those of large sites, and I believe it would require quite a bit of dev work to untie them. (They made an exception for Quantum Computing because there was a sponsor involved at the time its beta started.)

Comment: It's a great idea that has been suggested before, but last I heard they're not going to do it. It's considered too much work and hassle to make it possible.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the software does nothing of the sort. The two are tied together for no reason other than us saying they're tied together.

Comment: How is this a feature request? What feature are you asking to add? The retagging is unclear.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard I would like to change the site design. I plan to suggest the design on the site's meta, vote, then make the change happen. So the feature request is to enable to make the change happen, once the community approves it. Maybe this needs to be a separate question, and the current question should continue to be tagged `discussion`?

Comment: As I understand, in some cases it makes sense to change  [meta-tag:discussion] to [meta-tag:feature-request] but when doing so it should also be changed the title and the body accordingly. Ideally all should be done in a single edit and the explanation should be included in the Edit summary. In practice, it depends on each case. In this specific case I think that this might require more work to meet the requirements of a feature request (see the corresponding tag wiki)

Comment: @Rubén Thanks! I will make a new post, then. And revert this one back to `discussion` tag.

Comment: What if you first ask Rosie for a comment / update about her [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369555/578690)?