# A Not-So-Long Time Ago In a StackExchange A Mouse-Click Away... Lady Stackicorn vs Evil Twinicorn!

Tags: discussion, unicorns, fun

So I'm sure a lot of you are aware of Aarthi's [Roaming Unicorn project](http://theroamingunicorn.tumblr.com/). (If not: we have a super-cool SE unicorn plushie named Lady Stackicorn, and she's been roaming the globe and having super cool adventures with her SE pals for the past few years).

This is a picture of the lovely Lady Stackicorn, adorned with mementos of her travels:

[image]

I now present to you the latest installment of awesome in Lady's journey: her encounter with her evil nemesis, EVIL TWINICORN!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

P.P.S. The next person to get her should give her a bath!

P.P.P.S. Am I the best at fight sequences? No. Is it flipping *awesome* that I discovered an evil twin unicorn at the same time as Lady was visiting? Hell yes!

P.P.P.P.S. I almost had her attack by [parsing HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454), but I decided that would probably blow up SE anyway with too much combined awesome, so I changed tactics.

May Lady Stackicorn continue her journey forever!!

Comment: The Roaming Unicorn lives! \o/

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Very much so! And on her way to her next destination post-haste! (Literally!)

Comment: You should totally add this [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking) and link back when you do :D