# Questionable query produced by "Go get it" Peer Pressure badge

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress, peer-pressure-badge

If you are tracking the "Peer Pressure" badge progress and you click "Go get it" here:

[image]

It would produce the following query:

```
user:me score:-100..-3
```

Is there a particular reason for the `-100` lower bound? The following also works:

```
user:me score:..-3
```

And is probably, strictly speaking, matching the description better:

> Delete own post with score of -3 or lower

Comment: I'm pretty sure you understand how critical is it, a lot of people are tracking peer pressure badge progress nowadays.

Comment: Eh... I mean, I guess. Technically the latter is better. But practically, if you have a post below -100 score threshold... that's almost a point of pride and I wouldn't want it to be deleted. ;)

Comment: There's always the chance, slight as it may be, that the developer adding this feature simply was not aware it's possible to omit the lower bound.

Comment: Peer pressure goes to a certain point. After that it's just bullying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue why would anyone do that except that either:

- You cannot get the badge if you delete a post with a score less than -100 (don't you think the post might be already be deleted?)
- The developer's brain was in la la land and not thinking clearly/unaware of the lowerbound

Really, the search option (on the right of the screen says:

> user {insert user # here}
>     score -100 - -3

I really don't have a clue what `score` would mean in the first place, I mean what more chaotic could it get after deleting a few characters? But after deleting the `-100`, we get a more clear result:

> user {insert user # here}
>     score<= -3

We have a clear idea what the score should be and there should be no confusion what so ever!

Now after this, I narrow the possibilities to:

- The developer was Jon Skeet's robot so blame [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) (Chance: Very unlikely)
- It was Evil Twinicorn's fault: [A Not-So-Long Time Ago In a StackExchange A Mouse-Click Away... Lady Stackicorn vs Evil Twinicorn!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271817/a-not-so-long-time-ago-in-a-stackexchange-a-mouse-click-away-lady-stackicorn) (Chance: Very unlikely)
- The developer was out of his/her mind and clueless of what happened (Chance: Certain)