# What happened to that contest swag I was promised?

Tags: discussion, swag

We've run a couple of large-scale swag-yielding events around these parts lately. So far we haven't had a good way of keeping track of each one's status, short of long comment chains on the individual contest posts (or random other meta posts). This question will serve to aggregate all of that information in one spot.

Please leave specific "where's my order?" questions on the related answer below as a comment. If there isn't an answer for your issue or event, you can leave it in a comment on the question. Comments will be deleted once the issue is resolved (or moved to email) to keep things tidy around here.

This thread will be updated as news comes in and as we run more swag-yielding events.

Comment: Does this question cover moderator elections, too?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Nope, those should be handled on the respective site's meta, or via email where applicable.

Comment: @abbyhairboat - I think I remember you were supposed to send me Lady Stackicorn so that she could finally find a final destination, on my shelf near the Fluttershy one... ^_^

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I've got no idea who ended up with the traveling unicorn, sorry :\

Comment: Isn't Lady Stackicorn still travelling?

Comment: Does Stack Exchange still hand out swag for reaching certain reputation levels? Is there a question about that here?

Answer (score 75):

### [10 Million Questions - Share Your Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303045/865899) (August 2015)

**Status**: Completed! ✧*｡٩(ˊᗜˋ*)و✧*｡
**Contact**: [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat)

These have not gone out yet. [Tim had some technical difficulties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016?#comment292088_314186). They're going out shortly; this post will be updated when there's news.

---

**Update 21 Jan 2016:** Still in the queue, and I've got the screenshot to prove it. Swag orders are processed in a FIFO queue, and [here's the current position of this request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkZco.png). (It's not quite as bad as it looks, because the top ones that are way older are waiting for items to be re-stocked in the warehouse. So all the other stuff isn't actually waiting for those to go out.)

---

**Update 11 Feb 2016:** [Here's a new shot of the queue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Rqp.png) JNat buckled down and churned through that whole queue today. You may notice that the only item we care about here - the 10M Swag sheets item - is still Open instead of Pending, but that won't be the case for long. There was another data entry issue (about half of the records were missing a Real Name, which is important for shipping), but he got that sorted out today and should be able to get the orders off to the warehouse for processing tomorrow. (He is GMT, so his day is over now.)

---

**Update 19 Feb 2016:** [The queue is now empty!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS2u2.png) That means *our* part in this is done with. However, as Abby mentioned above, there was some trouble in the collection of the entries, which means the spreadsheets are not uniformly formatted, which in turns means *our vendor* is having to spend a *bit* more time than what was expected inputting each one of your names! I had hoped for this all to be shipped by today, but I don't think that is likely — I'm *seriously* hoping it won't get past next week, though!

---

**Update 25 Feb 2016:**

These packages have left the warehouse, and should be going your way. If, after a reasonable period of time has gone by, for some reason you still haven't received your package, please shoot me an e-mail (jnat@).

---

**Update 4 Mar 2016:**

So... apparently I wasn't aware of the whole rules of this... (⌒_⌒;)
Users who posted on Meta should already have their stuff, or at least have it on the way, but... the authors of the answers they mentioned are still missing — I'm terribly sorry about this! orz
I'll gather shipping information on these during the next week (I'll have to do it manually, which means **I have no idea who's eligible or not off the top of my head, nor do I have all the names indexed yet**, so please don't populate the comment section with "am I eligible?" queries), and will get to shipping it as soon as I can!

---

**Update 14 Mar 2016:**

Just sent the posters of the original answers mentioned in the Meta post an e-mail. **Will allow for two weeks to collect everyone's addresses, and then get to shipping everything your way!** This odyssey is almost at an end!

---

**Update 29 Mar 2016:**

I've just closed the form for collecting the original answerers' shipping info. More updates to come <strike>tomorrow</strike> this week! (sorry, minor delay)

---

**Update 1 Apr 2016:**

As was explained to the people who were e-mailed about getting swag because their answers were mentioned in the meta post, an unexpected number of people (over 200!) participated in this contest: as such, we won't be able to get all of those users signed copies of "Smart and Gets Things Done", as the original post on Meta.SO mentioned. Instead, 35 of the users who filled the form I sent them were picked at random, and are listed below:

[Patrick Hofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman), [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), [Dave Zych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630665/dave-zych), [Cesare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135714/cesare), [stephen.vakil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426450/stephen-vakil), [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david), [GlenH7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345223/glenh7), [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd), [Willem Renzema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797579/willem-renzema), [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry), [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w), [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), [Irvin Dominin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975520/irvin-dominin), [AmeliaBR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128209/ameliabr), [haraldK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428606/haraldk), [KyleMit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit), [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg), [Ivan Rodriguez Torres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2127296/ivan-rodriguez-torres), [Benjol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11410/benjol), [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry), [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), [Michael Borgwardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16883/michael-borgwardt), [milez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5110359/milez), [Ilija Dimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690848/ilija-dimov), [Florian Margaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851498/florian-margaine), [scheien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307748/scheien), [Nero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564895/nero), [Massimo Polimeni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582941/massimo-polimeni), [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque), [nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp), [Mat's Mug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug), [Aracem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628447/aracem), [e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis), [Am_I_Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3482140/am-i-helpful), and [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh).

The other 90 or so of you that filled the form will get, in addition to the t-shirt and ruled notebook mentioned in the original Meta post, some extra stickers as a consolation prize.

Next week the shipments will go out, with a few caveats:

- The 35 winners of the books will just be getting their shirt and notebook for now (unless they are...);
- Users who still had some other outstanding swag (either because they reached 100k or 250k reputation anywhere on our network, or because one of their previous shipments was returned for some reason) that was supposed to be sent their way, I'll get that bundled in with this one.

I'll update this post again next week, once I have confirmation that these shipments have gone out. I'll also update on the status of the signed copies then — right now we're working on getting them signed.

---

**Update 18 Apr 2016:**

The shipments have left the warehouse last week (on Wednesday and Thursday, the 13th and the 14th). I expect most of you to get them by the end of this week. As with before, please reach out to me via e-mail if they haven't arrived after a reasonable period of time (a month, let's say).

Still working on getting the signed copies of the book, though. More updates on that to come.

---

**Update 26 Jul 2016:**

**We have finally been able to restock on the books!** \o/
Now we just need to get them shipped from the warehouse to the office, get them signed, and then sent your way! Please hang on just a bit more (thanks for being so patient), and I hope we can get these shipped within the next few weeks.

---

**Update 18 Aug 2016:**

**It's been almost a year, but the books have *finally* been shipped.** Which concludes the last piece of this contest!
I'd like to, once again, apologize for all the time this took us, and to thank everyone involved for their patience. Hopefully everyone'll have their books by the end of the month! Enjoy your swag, people!

Comment: I remember animuson commenting on MSO that these would be shipped through FedEx- Is that correct? (So I'm checking the right account to see when my stuff's on its way.)

Comment: @Kendra Yes, we normally ship trough FedEx unless it's going to a PO Box inside the US (which FedEx can't deliver to).

Comment: @Mehrdad In certain countries, FedEx will let you register on their site with your address and will automatically add new packages which are going to your name and address, for tracking purposes. We will not be providing tracking numbers to users for this contest, because we won't receive those numbers ourselves.

Comment: Stuff's been shipped: hopefully everyone will get their stuff within the next week or so, I hope. Enjoy your swag, everyone, and thanks for participating. Also, sorry for how long it took to finally ship these :\

Comment: @JNat: no problem. Thanks for your effort. What do you consider "a reasonable period of time"? What are the 'normal' delivery terms?

Comment: Since we don't have tracking information for these, I'd give it 'till the end of March, tops, @PatrickHofman. It shouldn't take more than 2 weeks, I hope... but sometimes it does.

Comment: I got a package yesterday, in the Netherlands :D. Aside from the awesome swag, it contained a whopping ___4___ hand-signed shipping forms. I can't help but feel sorry for the person that had to go through all of that ;-) Thank you!

Comment: Got both the packages. Thanks to everyone who made this possible. Loved the swag.

Comment: Wohoo finally I got my package, thank you guys sooo much!

Comment: Obligatory _"Stickers instead of a book?! I want my money back!"_ comment ;-)

Comment: The package from the 2nd shipment has just arrived! 3 Stickers, a t-shirt and the notebook were included!

Comment: I dig get the t-shirt and notebook :) Thank you!

Comment: What is the books status?

Comment: Still waiting on them, @IvanRodriguezTorres. We had to get the books reprinted :\

Comment: Hi @JNat I received t-shirt and the notebook, but no stickers :-( ; any news about the books?

Comment: No news on the books yet, @IrvinDominin. I'll dig for updates this week.

Comment: Hi @JNat, just reaching out to see if you have any updates on the books.

Comment: Still no news, @SouravGhosh, no. You can rest assured that I'll update this post as soon as I have updates.

Comment: Is he still writing that book? ;)

Comment: He is not, no :P There seem to have been some problems with the publisher, but I'm actively trying to get everyone their books, @PatrickHofman :)

Comment: Lol. No problem JNat, we know you are all working hard to get things done. Thanks.

Comment: @JNat Any small-scale update on the status of the shipment? :)

Comment: The books were signed last Friday, and we'll work getting them shipped (hopefully) this week, @SouravGhosh ;)

Comment: @JNat good to hear that. Looking forward to receive that. :)

Comment: I received mine today. Thanks

Comment: I received my (signed!) copy of Joel Spolsky's "Smart and Gets Things Done" book. Thank you :)

Comment: @JNat [Finally received the book](https://twitter.com/techiesourav/status/780790045326258179), thanks much. :)

Answer (score 36):

> **If, by the end of March, for some reason you still haven't received your package, please shoot me an e-mail (jnat@)**.

---

### [How Did Stack Overflow Help You?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303988/865899) (September 2015)

**Status**: Completed!
**Contact**: [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat)

These are also still in progress; they were in [the same boat as the Share your Story orders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/165581), mired in technical difficulties. <strike>**Follow that post for details.**</strike>

---

**Update 25 Feb 2016:**

These will, hopefully, be shipped tomorrow — if not, next week, most certainly. [The post the last update told you to follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/165581) still has the context for why this took so long to handle, in case you missed it in the past.

---

**Update 29 Feb 2016:**

These have been shipped on the 26th of February!

Comment: Shipped... and **delivered**! I've provided a [description of the contents along with a photo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317712/4151918) in my original answer.

Comment: How can I track my swag (I'm in Italy)?

Comment: We don't offer tracking numbers with these, @IrvinDominin. But you can try [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised/272624#comment894145_272623).

Comment: I'm in Canada and I Just got mine! Thanks SO :D

Comment: Got this (the second package) too. Thanks #SO! @JNat

Answer (score 29):

### [Choose your own swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271359/165581) (December 2015)

**Status**: Completed
**Contact**: [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

Everyone who replied to the email and isn't waiting for something to be back in stock should now have tracking information for their package. If you don't, please get into contact with me.

Answer (score 29):

### [Stack Overflow Annual User Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314186/865899) (January 2016)

**Status**: Completed

**Contact**: [samthebrand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/896802/samthebrand)

37 users guessed the correct number of pennies in the piggy bank. 155 users will be receiving swag. [See details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315438/896802).

Comment: I'm dying to know how many pennies there were in that piggy bank.. When will you tell us :-?

Comment: @JonasCz [now!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315438/896802)

Comment: Is there an estimated shipping date @samthebrand - save me checking here daily until nearer the time?

Comment: @Ian The swagmasta has your shipping info, but as far as I know it's not yet shipped. I'll let you know when I know by updating this post.

Comment: "has been shipped" means it's completed? Or is there still something to be done? (All other answers got "Completed" as the status)

Comment: @ShadowWizard indeed! Edited.

Comment: @samthebrand I am new here and can i know where i can find those chances to get a SOtshirt.Is there any specific thread.I would love to have a one -_- at least one day ;(

Answer (score 29):

### [Moose Contest about Hats or Something](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help) (December 2017)

**Status:** Completed
**Contact:** [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson)

Just posting this here as a reference point for everyone. The form was closed on February 12ᵗʰ to allow a few others who didn't receive the initial email. We're still in the process of formatting the spreadsheet so it can be sent to the warehouse.

**Update History**:

- **April 18, 2018:** The final batch has been submitted and should (probably) ship out by the end of the week.
- **March 23, 2018:** All but 15 of these were submitted and should have shipped by now. I ended up unexpectedly being out for a few weeks and will submit the last 15 when I am back.
- **March 2, 2018:** About half of the requests have been submitted to the warehouse, and some have started shipping out already.
- **Feb 27, 2018:** Some information has been submitted for processing, but nothing has shipped out yet. They should start shipping out within the next few days. Will update again once everything has been submitted to the warehouse.

Comment: If I send you my hat, will I get my stuff sooner?

Comment: Any way for individual people from outside USA to get more details about their shipment? (I told my children the prize will arrive during March, but being international shipment can't be sure)

Comment: Got mine today, thanks!

Comment: @rogerdeuce, images please? Wanna know what we are about to get.

Comment: I got mine today, @Haris here's a pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYsip.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, looks good.. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm in the UK and mine just arrived!

Comment: Thank you guys, I received my [goodies](https://imgur.com/UlPFDv3.jpg), kiddo is so happy and excited. She says "Thank you uncle"!

Comment: @animuson can i get black SO t-shirt (instead for SE)? Plzzzz :)

Comment: Thank you very much - ours just arrived in Scotland!

Comment: Got it today in India. But the Package was unsealed. May be done by customs.

Comment: @TheDictator, was anything missing? Where are you staying in India?

Comment: @Haris nothing is Missing. It's just customs.

Comment: I am from India ,I got my package today and it was opened too . Sharpie was missing and pen was completely broken .Still happy that I got my package

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, same here. :(

Comment: Nothing received yet. Am I one of the final 15?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just looked, yes you're on the list to still be processed. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @animuson, can you check If I am there too, and most importantly, do we have an ETA for the last 15? :}

Comment: @animuson Thanks! Got my swag (after finding out my neighbour was sitting on it for the past 3 weeks without telling me about it). Already looking forward to the next event… Yes, I’m a swag-lover. ;)

Comment: The delay somehow takes the excitement away. sob sob :(

Comment: Finally.. I had started checking almost twice a day now.. Hopefully my name is present in the last batch.. Fingers crossed.. Final wait..

Comment: Got the package yesterday, thanks :) Any idea why the shipping note also lists a SO shirt, in addition to the SE shirt?

Comment: @Stijn Hrm, no idea. We didn't send SO shirts with any of the packages. They don't usually even include shipping notes in the packages.

Comment: @animuson any chance to check if my package has been sent? (I didn't get it yet, so assume it's in the "final batch".)

Comment: Has anyone received their packages which was sent in the last (April 18th) batch?

Comment: I got my package yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: Just checking if my package has been shipped or not.. Its been a month since the last update, and i have no news of the package. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @animuson. Can I get an update about the packages.. I haven't heard/got anything yet.

Comment: @Haris Will you email me (animuson@) so I remember to look into it for you? Thanks. :)

Comment: Since it's been more than 8 weeks since I e-mailed you and I haven't seen a reply, this is another ping to say that I still haven't received anything.

Answer (score 24):

### #SOReadytoHelp twitter/profile campaign (August 2015)

**Status**: Completed
**Contact**: [abby hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat)

The orders have left the warehouse and many people have reported receiving their shirts. If yours is still missing, get in touch with Abby via email (abby@).

Comment: Hi abby, Just wanted to know if I qualify for this one ? Because I had tweeted [here](https://twitter.com/TheLittleNaruto/status/634403206152323072)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The winners are announced here [Who are the winners in the #SOreadytohelp t-shirt drawing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303721)

Comment: Thank you :) @BhargavRao