# I'm entitled to a cheese board? Really?

Tags: discussion, swag, 10th-anniversary

I'm sure you know about all the cheesy [happenings here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese?). I understood that only the top 25 answers would receive a cheese board. Mine did not come close to the top 25.

Yesterday I received an email from JNat saying

> Hello there!
>
> You're receiving this because your answer on this Meta post entitled you to receive a cheese board! \o/

I thought that maybe everyone would receive one in the end (as the SE people are very generous :) ), but the update to the question gives a very different impression:

> UPDATE: JNat will be sending out emails to collect addresses from the lucky users getting a cheese board — be on the lookout for those! :)

**So the question is: *was my email an error?***

Please don't say yes!

Comment: My guess is according to Tim's post [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7371873#7371873) they have spares and/or some people opted for other swag instead of the cheese boards so they're not just sitting on those extras but sending them out to other contestants.

Comment: I wondered too, have meager 10 upvotes, but was too lazy to actually count, and didn't want to risk getting a "You're right! No swag for you!" reply. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you got an email, then it wasn't in error, no. We originally said we'd award the top 25 answers, but then we decided, as you guessed, we'd be a bit more generous than that! :)

Hope you enjoy it, when it gets to you ;)

Comment: So maybe edit the question? Or you want it to be a pleasant surprise? :)

Comment: Just a question: for us extra lucky ones who get one due to your generosity, is there an option to go for other swag, or was that just for the winners? I just ___love___ cheese, but my space is rather limited.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ maybe you can trade with other people? I'm serious, I'd trade something and these days shipment doesn't cost too much.

Comment: Reply to the email you got from me, and I'll walk you through the option, @Jǝssǝ ;)

Comment: I'm ok with keeping it as a pleasant surprise, @Shadow :)

Comment: Thanks so much! @Shadow, thanks for the offer, but I'm flat broke at the moment (and a weak home currency makes shipping very pricey for me)

Comment: @Jǝssǝ maybe some will go as far as taking the cost on themselves... still think that it's worth a shot, come over to Tavern and feel free to ask about it. :)

Comment: @Shadow: You could start a new community; _Swag Exchange_!

Comment: @JNat: Is it time for an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272621/366373)?

Comment: Hey, @JNat, I dont seem to have received the email, perhaps it went to my spam folder. Could you confirm if you sent it?

Comment: I did send it to your hotmail address, @Ander.

Comment: @JNat I have forwarding set up to my Gmail address and I generally get everything from SO, but I did not receive it in Gmail and can not find it in Hotmail. Possibly it went to spam and got autodeleted. Would it be possible for you to resend it to Gmail, if its mot much of an inconvenience ?

Comment: @JNat Pinging you again, in case you got busy with Christmas :).

Comment: Sorry, @Ander, I was indeed buried in stuff from the holidays — I'll send the email in a bit.