# Thank you for my cheese overflow board!

Tags: discussion, fun, swag, thanks, 10th-anniversary

I was one of the ones who did not come in the top 25 in the [who cut the cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316515/278094) contest, and was [very surprised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318672/278094) to find an email from JNat about the cheese board.

Fast forward to just three days before Christmas and my swag box arrived.  A very nice Christmas present indeed.

Comment: This beautiful story gives me hope, as someone with only 6 votes on my Time for Swag [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320454/7586) at the deadline. Anyway, what are your plans for the Stack Overflow cheese set? I guess now you have to entertain more.

Comment: @kobi don't hope for too much...they did say only the top 25 after all.

Comment: My parcel is still waiting, it was supposed to to be delivered today. @David you  are supposed to have a pun in the title like "I'm swaggering around with a cheesy grin" : )

Comment: @kobi: Your hope was not disappointed. Yet again they have given _everyone_ the prize! \o/

Comment: @hat - these people are all right. I probably worked too much on that one though...

Comment: @Kobi: Perhaps overly generous would be a better description! : )

Answer (score 20):

Here in glorious 256 color animated gif form is a stop motion of me unboxing my cheese board.

Enjoy:
[image]

I quite like the engraved inscription "Cheese Overflow 2018"
[image: cheese board]

#### Thank you SE!

Comment: Why'd anyone downvote this? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 13):

#### I got mine today, and I would to say thank you to SE for going through the bother of providing alternative swag.

Now in case you think I don't like cheese, I would inform you that I just ***love*** cheese. While this is true, I don't have extra space for a cheese board, especially as I don't get to prepare cheese nearly as much as I would like. I chose alternative swag.

In the end I chose

- A Raspberry Pi T-shirt
- An SO T-shirt
- A mug
- A water bottle

In JNat's email the mug option was a Stack Exchange mug. I knew I wanted a mug, but I had wanted an SO mug ever since I saw [Is my SO Coffee Mug defective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277806/is-my-so-coffee-mug-defective)

I asked for an SO mug if they were available (a little cheeky perhaps) and Lo and Behold, to my huge delight:

[image] [image]

Just where it likes to be!

## Thank you so much for going the extra mile!!

Comment: I need to get that mug :) maybe SO will start selling merch and use the funds to support the site! Or for charity!

Comment: They actually had an online store for a short while  @Eleeza, but it soon became apparent that it was unsustainable.

Answer (score 10):

Not a GIF, but still the awesomeness!! Thanks and <strike>Cheers</strike> *Cheese* !!!

[image: Cheese Board 1]

[image: Cheese board 2]

Comment: Thanks and cheers? Thanks and _cheese_.

Answer (score 5):

I just got mine, thank you very much! :)
[image]
[image]