# Why is Code Golf & Programming Puzzles still in beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, beta-sites

Checking [Code Golf & Programming Puzzles Area51 profile page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles) you can see that the page fulfills the requirements to graduate.

Why is it still in beta?

[image]

Comment: Agreed especially with all the amazing questions that come out of that site

Comment: We at PPCG have been [wondering as well](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8030/26997). (We've even been [planning for graduation](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7897/26997).)

Comment: There's... something peculiar going behind the scenes here. Code Golf *should've* flipped some switches but it hasn't, so I'll go look into why that's the case.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271974/308256)

Comment: @CloseVoters We did [effectively ask this on our site a month ago](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8030/hey-stack-exchange-how-are-we-doing), and didn't get much of a response.

Comment: Answer: The powers that be are in denial about our status....

Comment: @GraceNote I don't want to be anoying but any news?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu Give it time. Graduating isn't necessarily a quick thing :)

Comment: I meant "loose ends in the bounty comment"

Comment: Note that your screenshot shows fewer than 10 questions per day, but we've now exceeded that and all of our stats are rated "Excellent." ;)

Comment: @GraceNote Are you there? It's us, PPCG.

Comment: Using Q&A measurements to determine whether or not a site that is [not a Q&A site](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/were-not-a-qa-site-but-what-should-be-done-about-it) should graduate seems kinda weird.

Comment: Mark this as [status-complete]!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of today, PPCG's graduation has been [officially announced](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8538/congratulations-youre-graduating)! Thanks Grace Note for working with us, and all the hard work put in by PPCG users in making the site ready to graduate!

Answer (score 29):

Just in case you might miss it.
[Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126) in a [comment to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274340/why-code-golf-programming-puzzles-is-still-in-beta#comment891571_274343):

> Music and Japanese were in the loop before we set the new criteria.
>   Aviation hit "eligibility" on October 19th. All 3 had delayed
>   graduations, the former because of the whole design thing and the
>   latter due to the pileup of graduations from implementing design
>   independent. **We just ran Code Golf through the eligibility check
>   though, and it passed, and probably should've passed a while ago. So
>   we're looking into why it hasn't been flagged yet.**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 9):

I suspect, as per [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), that it is the questions/day that are delaying graduation:

> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll
>   consider it for graduation.

Comment: That's nice in theory.  However, [Japanese Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) has fewer/day for questions. Fewer avid users. And fewer views/day.  Or you could look at [Music](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance) or [Avaiation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation). Those are sites moving through the graduation process with more shaky number fundamentals than PCG.

Comment: I wonder when the wheels to graduation for those sites were set in motion.  Perhaps it was prior to the new policy.  If not, I think you have a very good case to ask your moderators to seek clarification from SE.

Comment: Probably also worth noting that Christianity.SE (the site I moderate) has *fewer* questions per day on average than PPCG. It's been graduated for a few years.

Comment: The Japanese one says it was "Launched" 5 months ago.  Music was also launched 5 months ago.  Aviation was only launched 2 months ago.  The post you mentioned was posted 8 months ago.  That's half a year for Aviation to move to 'launched' while PCG has sat in Beta. Aviation has only been around for 2 years, while PCG has been able to sustain its questions/day for *five* years.

Comment: @MichaelT Music and Japanese were in the loop before we set the new criteria. Aviation hit "eligibility" on October 19th. All 3 had delayed graduations, the former because of the whole design thing and the latter due to the pileup of graduations from implementing design independent. We just ran Code Golf through the eligibility check though, and it passed, and probably should've passed a while ago. So we're looking into why it hasn't been flagged yet.

Comment: Statistically the longer it passes the harder is to get over 10 questions/day.  8.9 question/day on a total 1830 days is pretty good and stable

Comment: Don't worry, as pro-tem on a site where 2 questions/day is a purple patch, I think to get anywhere near 10 is great going. Congratulations!

Comment: @GraceNote Could you please update PPCG with any updates asap? [Our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) just got [quite excited](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27433131#27433131) after your comment.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu that isn't true, because the average is a running average over 2 weeks.

Comment: @NathanMerrill My bad, I kept seeing that score and I thought is general do you know what is the overall score visits/day

Comment: Also note that since in PPCG questions are actually code challenges, you can't expect to have a gazillion challenges every day, because those take some preparation to create (for them to be good) and people can't solve 10+ challenges a day.

Comment: @GraceNote Try to schedule PPCG's graduation for [November 1st](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5834/34718).