# Is my SO Coffee Mug defective?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, swag

I received a really nice SO mug as swag for the [choose your own swag contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking) this year. Everything was working fine until this morning. Was there a patch or update or something?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
if (owner.isCoding() && mug.isEmpty())
{
    mug.fill('coffee');
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: Empty SO mug with code on a monitor in the background]

As I've highlighted with an orange arrow, I am coding recursive fractals using Logo. You can see also that my cup is empty. I believe this satisfies both conditions specified in the code snippet I posted above, and yet my cup remains empty.

I checked the console and there are no errors. What gives?

Comment: -1, orange arrows are soulless

Comment: I see the problem. You assumed using Logo was coding.

Comment: Oh no! Your password is showing!

Comment: @Oded Oops! I'll upload a new screenshot.

Comment: Oh, also, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but we just switched to Agile methodology, so I'm pair programming.

Comment: It's because that if statement should be while loop, otherwise it will not fill up more than once. I really have no idea why it worked until yesterday...

Comment: Oh, I see that you're still on Windows XP, maybe that's why it's not working ? Try formatting your hard drive and installing SoCoffeMugLinux™ 16, maybe that fixes it :-)

Comment: I suspect `owner.isCoding()` is returning `false`. Please add a `alert(owner.isCoding())` to check it's result.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and turning it back on again?

Comment: I suspect you have a bug in the mug. Have you used a debugger?

Comment: I also suspect that 1) Here `owner.isCoding()`, you aren't the owner. Someone else is (The guy who made/designed the mug) 2) `mug.isEmpty()` will always return false as the mug is never empty, it is filled with air.

Comment: You aren't coding, you are holding the mug. `owner.isCoding()` returns `false` so no wonder it isn't filling.

Comment: The password is still in the edit history. Is it possible to remove that, maybe for diamond mods?

Comment: @Fabian Thanks for your concern. It's actually a fake. It was intended for humorous effect.

Comment: Phew, just saved myself from getting whooshed!

Comment: wheredidyougetthatmugfrom

Comment: Also, what if you want tea in the cup? Or hot chocolate? Would you just switch "coffee" in the code for another beverage?

Comment: @EleezatheCharacterWizard He has the link in the question. It is a competition, which is over now.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You forgot to hook up dependency injection correctly.

You need one of these:

[image]

Comment: What framework should we use? I have the same problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Clearly the problem is not enough jQuery.

Comment: OK, I tried this, but now I'm getting `Reference not set to an instance of an object`?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - assuming you are using java-beans, did you roast and grind them as the standard requires?

Comment: @Oded I did and appended them to the `filter` object. Maybe I'm invoking the `brew` method incorrectly.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - you may need to post your grounds on http://MayYourCupOverfloweth.com to get an answer on that.

Comment: Is the proposed dependency [RFC 2324](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324) compliant?

Answer (score 49):

Classic beginner mistake. The code hasn't been run. So, hold the mug and run ... perhaps to the pantry, where the coffee is.

Comment: Ah, bad UX on the design then eh? :)

Comment: Run, but don't execute the code, those things are kinda hard to ship.

Comment: Tim, since [mug] isn't instantiated, which one would fill if you had two of these next to each other?

Comment: Mug is very much instantiated, OP has it in their hand. And mine even reviews code.

Comment: Yep, in your case `isCoding()` is false @Mat'sMug

Answer (score 48):

Your computer checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_the_glass_half_empty_or_half_full%3F) and [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/) and discovered that "half full" and "half empty" mean the same thing. Now if

```
0.5*full = 0.5*empty
```

then

```
full = empty
```

So your code made the cup empty, on the assumption that that was the same as making it full.

Comment: It's not my code! How do I get it fixed?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Find out who wrote it and ply them with coffee until they fix it.

Comment: Just not from this mug.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming your coffee mug isn't playing an April Fools joke on you . . .

This appears to count as undefined behavior. [An official source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318448) states that (boldface mine)

> While no incidents have been reported, the following scenarios might result in undefined mug behavior:
>
> - Owner changing, or non-owner use of mug
> - **Existential difficulties of owner**

I suspect that your existential difficulties have led to your working with Logo. Square fractals are recursive, meaning that any time you try to work with them, you'll get back to somewhere similar to where you started. Therefore, whenever you try to drink coffee and work with them, you'll get back to where you started. . .

Any empty mug.

Answer (score 14):

You are most definitely missing a `break` statement. That thing won't get filled without a decent `break`.

Also, the `if` should be a `while`, obviously...

```
while (owner.isCoding() && mug.isEmpty())
{
    break;
    mug.fill('coffee');
}
```

Comment: ... but if I `break;` first, won't I exit before the mug gets filled?

Comment: No, that is a common mistake. In this case the `break` doesn't cause an exit.

Comment: Performing `break` with a mug might initiate garbage collection though, so you need to look out for that.

Comment: Never heard of that before. What runtime version do you have?

Comment: 2.18.5.1.11.19.5.1.19.25 it says.

Comment: Are you sure it is a mug then? Never actually saw a mug on that runtime.

Comment: I couldn't update to 8.1.18.4.1.19.18.15.3.11 for some reason. Apparently it would be fixed in that version.

Comment: @Simon I can't believe I missed your jokes last year. Here's a very late laugh: hahaha.

Answer (score 12):

This line:

```
mug.fill('coffee');
```

Does not state the amount of time it takes for the mug to be filled with coffee, or how it's done.

Put the mug, empty, below your pillow at night, and when you'll wake up, it will be full.

Tooth Fairies got some less known relatives, such as Coffee Fairies.

Answer (score 11):

The `&&` operator shorts the circuits, so `owner.isCoding()` is called but `mug.isEmpty()` is not. So if you're coding with Legos and you are the one true owner of the mug, it doesn't matter whether your mug is empty, the code will always be called.

The `.fill` method doesn't do any checking for `.isFull()` so in your case it looks like the Stack Overflowed and contents was set to 0. You can see using `.contents.toLiters()` how much is in `mug`.

I also recommend refactoring the code to make it more efficient. You can do that by [reversing the indentation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42510/20469). I think that worked for Mat's Mug.<sup>1</sup>

You can find more information about this [here](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ).

---

<sup>1</sup>citation needed

Comment: I hate it when my circuits get shorted.

Comment: Reversing the indentation? Geez have I been doing it wrong all this time?!

Comment: Umm... the link wasn't broken. (can't see how any of the links is related, but that's a different matter, lol! :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard My esteemed colleague in moderation runs the site that I originally linked to, but unfortunately he removed the redirect for that particular URL. So I had to adapt accordingly. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 10):

I've finally found a solution for Mac OS X!

Turned out the OS X flavor of Unix doesn't ship with all the required dependencies. The easiest way to install it is via Homebrew.

```
$ brew install coffee
```

Strangely the coffee seems to be mildly alcoholic, must be a homebrew issue.

---

What we really need is a way to run this from a browser. Maybe I'll try porting it to Coffeescript later.

Comment: But Java should be installed automatically the first time you try to drink it.

Comment: Also this runs fine on ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps they ignored the linker warning: `mug` was not correctly instantiated.

At least you didn't suffer a core dump. :)