# Enabling Dance Dance Authentication

Tags: support, security, april-fools

So I saw the Dance Dance Authentication post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/30/stack-overflow-unveils-next-steps-computer-security, and I thought it sounded pretty cool. But, I can't figure out how to enable it. It says:

> To set up any of these systems for your account, log in and head to Settings.

and I don't see anything in the settings

Comment: try [proctol chair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293225/the-next-step-in-computer-security)  instead ...

Comment: Maybe [dependency injection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277807/278543)?

Comment: @rene I'll take a look

Comment: And why the downvotes? I even put the april fools tag

Comment: No doubt, the most lame April Fools ever... oh well.

Comment: @Noah downvotes are because people hate fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I admit I was looking forward to practicing with the new system over the weekend, myself, to avoid an awkward "unable to access account" situation on Monday, so I empathize. I regret to announce that our dev team was unable to roll out the actual user profile setting at the same time as our feature announcement on the blog. Probably because they were hard at work finishing up the API...

> In a few days, we’ll offer a public API for Dance Dance Authentication. To receive a developer token, please send us your best dance video.

https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/847893282466267136

Comment: There @Pops, we managed to capture one of our bots testing your API https://twitter.com/SOBotics/status/848159291127324672

Answer (score 6):

I was confused by this, too: I saw the blog post the other day and thought this would be something that we users could play with, as in previous years. But it seems that there's "just" the blog post and an accompanying video.

The video's very funny, though. Nicely done, you SE pranksters!

Comment: I thought we could try it like previous years too :(

Comment: @Noah what I am confused about is that SE is supposed to give unicorn avatars to new users on April fool's day, but it isn't happening.

Comment: @John - that happened one time.