# Locked questions: add ability to bookmark

Tags: feature-request, historical-lock, bookmarks

[Historical Locked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) (e.g. [How deep are your unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153234/how-deep-are-your-unit-tests/)) should have an ability to bookmark (star / favorite). If it’s available for reading, user should be able to bookmark it.

Similar question was raised in [the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for#comment974259_126631) “Can a historically locked question still be starred, or is that behavior frozen too?”

Also as we have reopen link for closed questions, should be similar link to vote for unlocking the Historical Locked question?

Comment: Isn't that already possible? I just favourited the unit tests question.

Comment: The relevant info has been edited into the FAQ, so this is now a duplicate. Please note that it's policy to close questions as duplicates of FAQs even if they're merely related, and even if the information wasn't contained in the FAQ at the time the question was asked. This is to direct all users to the canonical source containing the relevant info.

Comment: @yannis, I can bookmark it now, not sure why I wasn’t able to do it yesterday

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim you were probably logged out, or there was temporary glitch with resource load, which caused the star to not appear.

Answer (score 4):

### It *is* possible to favorite locked questions.

[image]

I just favorited [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking#).