# Announcing Our Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2018, swag

> **Mar 5 UPDATE:** This order is proving a bit more laborious to expedite than our vendor had originally anticipated, so these boxes haven't been shipped out yet. Anyone who filled in a form should receive an email with tracking information as soon as their box is shipped. Anyone who didn't catch the email on time, please see [this other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324589/208518).

---

> **Jan 30 UPDATE:** [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat) just sent out emails to collect addresses — be on the lookout for those, **and try to fill it in the next two weeks**! :)

Did you receive any gifts that you'd appreciate a lot more if they were actually something that you could use, or even wanted? Do you still have some from the last few years? Don't feel bad, we've got you. Curious? Read on.

If you're reading this, there's a good chance that you've got, well, *stuff*. We've got stuff too, in fact, we have *so much* stuff that we really need to make room to order new stuff. And in order to do that, we need to give it away.

But we feel kinda bad about giving people that have an abundance of stuff even *more* stuff when there are so many folks out there that really *need* stuff, especially in colder climates right now. Our branded flashlights, keychains, stickers, mugs, mouse pads, aprons, and things of that sort are *super* cool, but they aren't things that charities can use directly without burning additional overhead.

That's where the stuff-a-way idea comes in. Here's how it works:

1. ***You*** give stuff that you don't need to people that need it. That could mean dropping off some stuff to a charity, food bank, making a donation to a non-profit that can help people (if money is the thing you have too much of), handing a blanket and a cup of coffee to a homeless person, or whatever makes someone's life better than it was before you did your thing.
2. ***You*** write an answer to this question and let us know that you did something and tell us about your random act of kindness. You can share as much or as little as you'd like; we're going to take your word for it. In your answer, tell us what sites in our network you like the most (we'll go by where you participate if you don't).
3. ***We*** will send you a shoebox full of swag that you'll be sure to like. See what we did there? Everyone wins because:

   1. Those in need get stuff they can use immediately (things like mouse pads, aprons, pens, stickers, notebooks, and keychains aren't on that list, we're sure).
   2. You get rid of stuff you don't need. We empty our warehouse for the most part to make room for all new stuff. Your sweat equity is getting out to do something nice, our's is handling all the shipping of the goodies.
   3. You get stuff you want, in the form of a loot-box style package from us.

If you'd rather not receive anything, just say so. This event is structured so that we make sure giving is all about what the recipients actually need and the warm feelings from it come secondary (which is why we don't just bulk-donate thousands of dollars worth of stuff); beyond that, we're cool with whatever terms you like.

#### The rules

1. Any user of MSE in good standing is eligible, including employees, but only one entry per person is allowed. Likewise, prizes are limited to one per participant.
2. ***You must ensure that your email address associated with your account is current and verified by our system to receive your box.*** Not hearing back from folks is a big problem for this kind of event, so make sure the email associated with your account works, and is one that you check at least semi-frequently.
3. To participate, you must make some kind of *needed* donation to a person or charitable organization in need of what you have. Canned food for a food bank? Good. Old laptops for any educational purpose? Good. A bag of fast food for a homeless person? Good. We trust that you will do good things and not require adult supervision, please prove us correct there. Also, homeless shelters need socks, sanitary pads, diapers, etc - a little research in your area can go a long way.
4. Sweat equity is accepted as a donation (in which you go volunteer your time somewhere that meets the spirit of this event). Again, we trust that you'll make us proud of you.
5. This event will remain open until it's *very likely* that we're just about out of stuff to send. That could be a month, a week, or whatever. It's hard to say with these types of events.
6. ***Oh yes, the prizes!*** Boxes will include multiple things consisting of pens, sharpies, stickers, drink holders, aprons, battery packs, flashlights, mugs, mouse pads, staplers and other office supplies, games, shirts, hats and other items branded Stack Overflow or after other Stack Exchange websites. *Some* items will also include rarer prizes like hoodies, other branded outerwear and bags, books, and other surprise items.
7. While we'll ask for your preferences, we can't guarantee what's going to be in any given box. It's a mystery, but it will be cool stuff!
8. Our code of conduct applies to any and all activity related to this event.

Now, head to those closets, attics, or those boxes that might be under a pile of more appreciated gifts and help everyone get something that they want and need at the end of the holiday season this year.

While we hope to be able to do this again in the future, it'll depend on what we've got laying around. If any of our customers signal that they want to throw in some stuff to sweeten the communal pot luck, we'll update the post (I honestly haven't talked to anyone about this yet, kinda winging it, so check back occasionally for updates).

***Commence the stuff-a-way!*** And, enjoy being good to your fellow living creatures that could use a little help right now.

> #### Thank you, everyone!
>
> The stories you've shared are full of great examples that we hope will inspire others to adopt new and creative ways of giving to those that need some help. From reminding all of us that donating blood can literally save lives, to ideas surrounding creative kits that contain essential supplies and some gift cards, you've given lots of folks great ideas and been an inspiration. This was an experiment, and because of you, it was a resounding success!
>
> We'll be reaching out soon (really, allow the full 6 to 8 weeks here as this is a huge effort) and getting everyone that wants one their boxes of goodies. We'll very likely do something similar to this as part of Stack Exchange Gives Back next year, so stay tuned, and thanks again to everyone that participated!

Comment: Gifts, **This** year? No. ;)

Comment: I like how this event lets the community be a part of Stack giving Back. <3

Comment: @MEE I thought of inventing a time machine and finding out where you live just to go back in time and give you something yesterday, but editing the post seemed easier. Fixed.

Comment: @TimPost who is not in need of free rep? Hopefully a bounty counts... :D just kidding. Great contest though.

Comment: What a great idea!  Does stuff we gave away in the few days before this meta post count too, or does it need to be in *response* to this meta post?

Comment: This is a 2018 Stuff-A-Way, so did the act of charity have to be done last year?

Comment: Thanks for encouraging giving *after* the holidays!

Comment: Best. Thing. Ever. But, why tag it as winter bash?

Comment: I don't like this. Charity isn't something that needs to be rewarded.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj: You can do charity without it being physically rewarded. This is just a way to promote even more charitable acts. (To some degree, all charity that people do is done for the "reward" of feeling good about yourself.)

Comment: Donate me StackOveflow branded hoodie already =)

Comment: @AvnishKabaj agree if we would have been given money for this. But SE swag is just pure fun, so best way to encourage us to do good things. :)

Comment: Do we need to add recent story or it can be from few year ago or future planned one? Because I do participate in an annual thing which happen in 2017 end but the 2018 one delayed a bit and will happen in a month or two.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Any recent event is fine. There's no hard 'cutoff' other than your own instinct; if it's fresh enough to feel relevant for you, it's probably fine. In the very unlikely event that someone posts something that isn't in good faith we'll deal with it, but we won't let the possibility of someone doing that complicate things needlessly for others, if that makes sense.

Comment: @TimPost great. Will be ready with my post soon then :)

Comment: @TimPost [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321614/182734) :)

Comment: That "special note" is a good point why we want to auto-protect a question only once.

Comment: When will we get the emails again?

Comment: It says 2018 Stuff-A-Way, but it wast posted on January 3rd, 2019...

Comment: is this still up?

Comment: is this valid in India?

Comment: @PriyanshiSrivastava, I have found Stack Exchange to be fair in ignoring country borders, so I say it is most likely valid in India, just donate, post and hope for the best.

Comment: @Mr.J I'd say yes as the post is still featured and there has been no notice of it being ended

Comment: @PriyanshiSrivastava I see no reason why it is not. Why do you ask?

Comment: because I see no Indian to post a story here that's why @Spikatrix

Comment: @PriyanshiSrivastava Indians do post... I did :)

Comment: ohh.. @Shachi didn't see your post so ..lol..and great gesture :) have upvoted you!

Comment: @PriyanshiSrivastava SE ships swag anywhere they can legally ship things to, though occasionally local customs in india does odd things I am told.

Comment: Following on the comment from @AvnishKabaj The whole point of charity is for the left hand to not know what the right hand is doing. If I perform an act of good will for someone, telling someone else about it denigrates it and misses the point, because it then becomes a self-promoting act: "Look at me; I'm so great because I did a good thing."

Comment: @AgiHammerthief Isn't the whole point of charity to help people? Maybe there's merit in being humble, but the real core purpose of charity is helping people in need; telling people about it doesn't make the beneficiary benefit any less.

Comment: I agree, @Ian.  And in particular, telling others about one's efforts to give back, when encouraged to share such stories, hardly makes a user sharing such a story any less humble than one who decides not to do so.  Indeed, sharing "good news" helps counter the incessant exposure to crimes and warfare and human misery, and in this way, helps folks to be inspired to contribute, rather than concluding there's no point in any thing, anyway.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief It depends on the context - if one is not being self-promoting ("Look at me; I'm so great..."), but rather sharing in joy, then perhaps it is right to share our joys with one another, just as we bear one another's burdens... "Joy shared is doubled; pain shared is halved."

Comment: Don't forget to use BCC on recipient list, [not CC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322152) `:)`

Comment: Did anyone received an email yet related to this event?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri They asked for 6-8 weeks to email all people and just have passed like 2 weeks, wait at least other 4 dude

Comment: Any updates? I've kept [checking my junk box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322152/more-than-15k-bottles-of-viagra-from-kenya-asking-110-people-for-money-seriou#comment1054023_322154) in the past few days and have seen no incoming mail.

Comment: @JNat Oh, good.  It's a proper BCC this time.  Yay for progress?

Comment: INORITE, @fbueckert! :P (checked and rechecked at least 10 times, and made a big pause and got back to it before sending, to make sure nothing was rushed or overlooked)

Comment: I feel like the need for a 'Contest/Giveaway ended' closing reason is getting more and more justification recently.

Comment: You all are amazing!

Comment: "Your response has been recorded. You can expect your swag to arrive in the next ~4 weeks! Or you can at least hope so... I hope so... :)" Can't wait! Thank you!

Comment: @Mooseman More like 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hoping for no odd behavior from the customs :D

Comment: @JNat I have not received any email from you (also not in Junk mail) - can you please check whether I was included in your mail-out?

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has received anything swag yet?

Comment: @Ian Nothing yet. I'm in the US.

Comment: Stuff received! Thanks guys!

Comment: @RhinoWalrus oooh! Good to now things are starting to arrive. Where in the world are you based?

Comment: Got mine! Thank you!

Comment: @Ian, I'm in Austin, TX

Comment: Yay! Got swag! Thanks! I'm in the US.

Comment: Received t-shirts. Thank-you, that was nice.

Comment: Why no mail for AWB this time. Can't track while others I know received it.

Comment: Just got my swag this morning! I'm super happy with it, thanks so much!! (I live in the Netherlands btw, in case anyone wants to get a sense of shipping time etc.)

Comment: Yay! Looks like the DHL-shipped stuff is winding its way to folks this week. I've been seeing the USPS stuff appearing on Twitter so that seems to be in full swing. Still folks,  give it a bit of time either way, it was a ton of stuff!

Comment: Yay, I just got it! TWO boxes full of swag!! I wanted to give most of the items to my teammates as a gift and there's plenty of them for everyone :D Best thing is they don't even know it yet, this is great ^_^ Thanks!

Comment: @AnkitSharma any updates? I'm in the same situation as yours.

Comment: Stuff received here in the UK too, thanks team!

Comment: @SouravGhosh mailed jNat and he will get back to me

Comment: I haven't received even the email D: I'm in Colombia

Comment: @JNat Received the gifts here in India :) Thanks to everyone involved. I am thinking of distributing the items to whosoever can make the best use of them in the nearby charitable school and orphanage.

Comment: Thanks from India! :)

Comment: Nvm, the boxes just arrived! Thanks from Colombia!

Comment: Boxes arrived a few hours ago, amazing gear! Thank you so much everyone at Stack!

Comment: Got two boxes full of fantastic stuff yesterday here in UK, thanks!

Comment: @JNat, Thanks for the gifts from stack exchange. This was my first experience with this group. Received 2 box of gifts today. Hearty thanks from India.

Comment: Got the boxes today. Thanks @JNat for the help with Customs!

Comment: Boxes full of great stuff arrived in Germany, thanks!

Comment: I guess the giveaway is over ? I looooove the mug so much but wasn't aware of this giveaway and it seems it's too late now. From what I've read there used to be a store to buy one but it has been closed...

Comment: I missed the email :(, can I fill and send it now ?

Answer (score 77):

I'm part of a team, made up of teenagers aged 15-17, who volunteer to be a part of this team, and then we go and do... stuff.

What we do varies, but there's one thing that we do regularly.

Here in our town, there are a lot of old Holocaust survivors who don't have a lot of family or anyone around too often. And so, for their birthdays, we'll come over, bring cookies, balloons, flowers, and a sign to stick on the wall, and then sit and chat.
We'll talk about their kids, who are often living overseas, and about them, how they arrived in town...

Sometimes, it can be hard talking to these people. I'm naturally inclined to be reclusive, and... to say I'm socially awkward is an understatement, and so I usually am not the chattiest one there... but it's important that I make the effort. Once you warm up to each other, these people are some of the nicest folks you'll meet, and usually have some amazing stories to tell.

At times, it can be really difficult. I remember one man in particular. We had come in to visit them for his wife's birthday. He was an Auschwitz survivor, if I recall correctly, and was a veteran of the IDF. He had... to say PTSD would be an understatement. He repeatedly showed us the number on his arm and was telling us about how we need to always remain strong. But once you work past that, and really start to get to know these people... it's really worth the effort.

It just so happens that today of all days, was the first time that we went back to a house for the second time. We had been there exactly a year ago, and it was her birthday again. We walked in, singing "Happy Birthday", and then we sat and chatted for about a full hour.

I feel that this is basically on the same level as "helping" as when I donate money to the local charity that helps feed some of these people. People have an emotional need to feel cared for, and that they're not alone. I've been stopped in the street by some of the people we've visited, and had them thank me for coming by. Never underestimate the importance of simply brightening someone's day and putting a smile on their face.

---

<sub>If we're talking about swag stuff, then I'd love Bicycles.SE, Scifi.SE, Puzzling.SE, and Music.SE stuff. Having Mi Yodeya swag would also be pretty cool.</sub>

Comment: I know I'm violating the "no +1" rule on comments, but this is an amazing thing to do, kudos.

Answer (score 48):

Where I'm from most offices do a form of [Secret Santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa). It's a beloved tradition of hoping you get someone you know quite well and then buying them something cheap and hoping they like it. If you're lucky you've got a programmer on hand to at least ensure it's both random and secret.

People really enjoy Secret Santa and I never want to get in their way. I don't really want to participate though; I don't need a random bit of plastic<sup>*</sup>. I've had to come up with a different tradition to not appear like a miser (:.

Instead of Secret Santa I organise, every year, the unfortunately acronymed, **Alternative Secret Santa**. If someone doesn't want to participate in Secret Santa (and even if they do) encourage them to donate the money they would have spent to a charity for those who are least likely to be having a good Christmas.

We normally donate to homeless childrens charities; this year it was also our [local food bank](https://southwark.foodbank.org.uk/) during a year when more and more people are needing this sort of help.

To be honest, I don't need another pen. I do hope that some of the readers of this answer might spread the word about ASS to their own (work)place and start their own traditions of donating instead of buying.

<sub>* tat</sub>

Comment: My congregation started the Alternative Gift Market a few years ago, so instead of buying people random junk they don't need, you can "buy" them a donation to people with more basic needs (and the people running the market take care of collecting and making the donations).  We do a mix of local and global.  Kids in our school make original cards to give to the recipients.  This is definitely a thing, and I hope the idea spreads.

Comment: Great to hear! My employer also organizes "Christmas giving" for charities and needy individuals rather than co-workers. Employees are encouraged to donate to a cause from list (sourced from employees suggestions) and the company adds their own contribution, potentially doubling the impact. It would be great if more organizations would do that.

Comment: Or you could name it Secret Santa, Alternative-Style (which has a bit of a sassy acronym).

Answer (score 44):

I guess every person has their own heroes. When I was young, I spent most summers at the sea with my family and I always admired the crews of the [DGzRS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Gesellschaft_zur_Rettung_Schiffbr%C3%BCchiger) ([English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Maritime_Search_and_Rescue_Service)) cruisers. It takes a special kind of human to volunteer to jump into a boat and head right into deadly storm brewing to help other people they have never seen before. And by volunteer, I mean volunteer. It's not their job; they don't get any money for it. Their organization gets no tax money from the state; it's donations only.

[image]

So yeah, you made me donate. For the first time in my life. I always wanted to, but it needed *stuff from the Internet* to actually get me off my lazy ◼◼◼ (redacted to comply with the code of conduct) and do it :)

<sup>In case you are from around here and want to help too: [Link](https://www.seenotretter.de/wie-sie-uns-helfen/)</sup>

<sup>I almost forgot: my favorite of the SE sites is the OG: Stack Overflow</sup>

Comment: Likewise the [RNLI](https://d144ujmy1n2alc.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/RNLI-Bembridge-1-cropped-820x547.jpg) in the UK. Long time favourite charity of mine.

Comment: Great call. Like @ArtOfCode, I have always been a supporter of RNLI in UK. I live in Germany now and didn't know about DGzRS until I saw an add on TV recently (over Christmas season I think). Thanks for reminding me to follow up.

Answer (score 35):

I was helping a client fix up her computer, and while we were there she found a lot of technical/computer related stuff which she didn't need.

I took it and donated it to a local educational non-profit (where I help out) which I knew could use them.

She was happy to get rid of some "junk". They were happy to receive some good equipment.

**win - win**

Answer (score 35):

<sup>/!\ Trigger warning: blood donation. I used my remarkable Paint skills to remove blood appearances from the linked picture but if you're uncomfortable with it, please don't mind my post.</sup>

---

I've been volunteering since age 14 (I'm 23 now!), be it in funding charities or giving my time for cooking meals for homeless people. But the thing I've been doing the most often is giving my blood, platelets and blood plasma. In France, where I come from, giving sanguine products is a volunteering act, you don't get money for doing so.

I am lucky my veins are wide and strong enough to allow me giving platelets and plasma. But even if it's not your case, please consider giving blood more often - which may be easier for you to give. Sanguine products are goods that are needed worldwide and they save lives. You may be giving away minutes of your time, but by doing so, you'll allow someone else to win back years of living.

[image: This is a picture of me giving my plasma in Tours, France. Taken in July 2016.]

I'm a DevOps engineer and therefore I enjoy spending time on Stack Overflow, Super User, Ask Ubuntu and Unix&Linux but my favorite site is [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), for as most of my volunteering was about helping charities in improving their communication skills, getting involved on a stack for interpersonal skills was the logical way for me to pursue helping people.

Comment: Should I be worried, why you had blood in your face that had to get covered? :4

Comment: @Zaibis Really, you should be worried if one _doesn't_ have blood in one's face.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 well, not the painted parts I‘d say, tho :p

Comment: This is clearly missing free-hand RED circles. I dunno whether it is legitimate anymore. ;)

Comment: I can tell you have done freehand Paint handwriting before :)

Comment: @BlackVegetable Erh, the red color didn't seem appropriate as a way to hide the blood. :p

Comment: @Clonkex [I don't know what you're talking about.](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/18091/how-to-try-to-get-my-neighbour-to-park-their-car-in-their-assigned-spot)

Comment: I guess I have really good blood. Every time I donate, they mark it A+ :)

Answer (score 33):

I'll add my own thing. It's not *really* a thing, but I like pointing out the benefits of focusing on local communities (it takes a village, after all), and my short story illustrates that a bit.

I don't really have a favorite site; Stack Overflow, Seasoned Advice, Arqade, DIY and other places have delighted me with questions that I'm able to answer (and once, I even got help [disposing of a dead body](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/how-do-i-find-and-dispose-of-the-dead-body-in-my-ceiling)), but I see our sites as many specializations of the same core group of people.

For those that don't know me, I cook quite a bit. I used to cook professionally (along with some other occupations while programming gigs got scarce in the late 90s to early 2000s), and it's still something I do avidly. I'm a firm believer in everyone having a right to wholesome food, and that everyone deserves the help and support of their neighbors.

I work from home. My spouse currently doesn't work (she will once our smallest child starts school next year). Our kids eat *really* well because I have an awesome job that allows me to have good work/life balance which lets me cook. As our kids started making friends in the neighborhood, we naturally had young guests for dinner.

Then, we started having more, and more, and more. On any given day, I feed up to ten kids. We don't just feed them, we also give them a safe place to hang out and play after school. Their parents work, many of them multiple jobs, and the kids just sort of gravitated to our house. There wasn't any formal arrangement, we just sort of ended up looking after quite a few of them, and it's something we very much enjoy doing. We picked our neighborhood very deliberately because it's extremely diverse, many families here are first generation immigrants that own very young small businesses.

We do what we can, and what we *can* involves helping other parents not need to worry so much about where their kids are, or what they're gonna cook for dinner. And the beauty of it is, this isn't any kind of arrangement that anyone discussed, it just sort of happened, and it perpetuates because everyone involved is just happy about it. Occasionally, they send a stash of chips and snacks over to say thanks, and that's all we'd ever want, no money ever changes hands.

It's great to have the privilege of being a part of so many memories that will last well into the future, and to put real nourishment (literally) on the table. For me? I hate cooking anything in small batches (believe it or not, everything  gets easier when you're doing it for 10+), so I'm just glad I can cook whatever I want and it disappears quickly.

For monetary donations, I use [Donors Choose](https://www.donorschoose.org) and support teachers in Baltimore (notoriously under-funded city schools) as often as we can. What I like about the platform is you have the ability to jump in and fund entire *projects* for a teacher (many as low as $100) so they can move with some agility to quickly meet student needs that they wouldn't have otherwise.

Anyway, that's it. I just like cooking, so I'm happy my skills there get to remain valuable to more than just me even after I stopped doing it for a paycheck.

Comment: When I was a kid, I used to go over to some of my classmates' house after school to hang out while my folks were working. Their mom always baked bread right before she'd come pick us up, so it'd be just about done cooling when we arrived. I don't keep in touch with those classmates or remember much about them at all - I must have been around 5 when we did this - but I'll always remember the bread and the warm fuzzies it generated. So I'm willing to bet those kids are gonna remember your snacks for decades (if not your name). :)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 28):

### The great earthquake declutter of 2018

I live in Eagle River Alaska, just outside of Anchorage. On the morning of November 30 we were [walloped with a 7.0 earthquake](https://www.npr.org/2018/11/30/672240051/magnitude-7-0-earthquake-shakes-alaska-tsunami-warning-in-effect). Other than a broken window and some cracks in the drywall, we and our house are okay.

However, almost everything in the house ended up on the floor. After the quake our place was a sea of broken glass. All the cupboards flew open and we lost just about every glass and dish we own. Shelves came down; bookcases emptied.

My wife, being a fan of Marie Kondo's decluttering philosophy, convinced me that now was the time. Rather than put everything back, it was time to go through everything all the floor (aka everything) and decide what is necessary and what really gives us pleasure and declutter the rest.

The month of December has been one giant stuff-away as car load after car load of books, clothes, and electronics are taken to local charity thrift stores.

Comment: +1 for finding a positive to the quakes.

Comment: So... now that you gotten rid of all that clutter you want some new clutter? ;)

Comment: If only I could get some Stack Exchange china a crystal @Ploni!

Answer (score 25):

I collected (donations of old and new) and bought (new) 55 sleeping bags That i donated to the Scoutreach program for underprivileged scouts. I intend for this to be an ongoing program.

[image]

I also donated $1000 to make sure that some of the underprivileged scouts can go to summer camp next summer, and I explained to the Scoutreach executive that if there are others that need help as camp approaches, that I will do what I can to help more.

Answer (score 22):

My work has been in the process of clearing out and fixing up a floor of our building for awhile now. Starting a little more than a month ago, IT began putting out a bunch of free randomness on a table (including but not limited to cables of all sorts, old monitors, etc...).

Before long, people were bringing a bunch of stuff from holiday parties they didn't need anymore. There was a day that our freebie table was filled with two dozen mason jars, a pile of mini horseshoes and even more randomness.

After a conversation with my IT buddy, I learned they were throwing away whatever people weren't taking at the end of each week!

Horrified, I sent an email to his boss. Since then I've been making weekly drives with a trunk full of stuff to [Goodwill](http://www.goodwill.org/) for the last month.

Answer (score 21):

I give anywhere from $1 to $5 to a homeless lady named Jackie who I see all the time when I'm downtown.  Last week, she said that she had nearly saved up enough money to buy a car, which will give her a shelter for inclement days.

Also, a homeless man asked me for money, and I told him I'd be happy to buy him something to eat.  He said he actually was hoping to get food for a holiday meal.  I took him to the grocery store and told him to get whatever he needs and I paid for it.

And, I don't smoke, but I carry an extra pack of smokes to give to homeless people, as an alternative to money.

My 6 year old daughter picked out a tag from a Giving Tree, for a 6 year old girl who wanted a particular toy, which we bought and returned to the tree.

And, I'm in the midst of a Sh*t We Don't Need purge of my house.  I have several bags/boxes filled and will be donating them to Goodwill soon.

Answer (score 20):

The Cellio foundation -- that is, I, the cat, and the checkbook -- met at the end of 2018 to decide on year-end donations.  We benefited from a surprise bonus at work, so there was more money in the budget than we'd expected when we did the initial planning for the year.  Nice problem to have!

There are several themes in our charitable donations.  Today I'm going to talk about one of them, food.  *So much* food gets wasted, thrown away, in some places, while in other places people are going wanting.  It feels like this problem should be easier to solve than it is.  So I take a multi-tiered approach:

I take extra *usable* items from my pantry to the [local food pantry](https://www.jfcspgh.org/services/squirrel-hill-food-pantry/) (just down the street), but this has been falling off lately -- not because I'm stingy but because I finally joined a CSA and started getting smarter about using what I buy and not buying what I won't use.  (Yay, I've moved from "reuse" to "reduce"!)  That means there's less extra stuff now, so I've increased my financial donations to them.  (It doesn't make sense for me to buy food for them directly; they get better bulk discounts than I can get.)

At the *extremely* local level, there are two people I see outside the store frequently, a disabled veteran outside the main grocery store and a homeless person outside the smaller store across the street.  I try to ask them on my way in what I can get them from the deli or prepared-foods section.  Sometimes it's coleslaw; sometimes it's a turkey sandwich.  Last week the homeless person got some surprise roasted chicken alongside the sandwich he asked for.

I feel it's important to support local organizations, but the biggest problems in the world are not local to me so I need to look there too.  That's why I support (among others) [Heifer](https://www.heifer.org/about-heifer/index.html), who provide not just food but the means of production worldwide.

---

My favorite sites are Mi Yodeya, Worldbuilding, Writing, and (ok I'm a little weird) Meta.  I cook a lot, so an apron would get used, and I have all the usual problems of heavy gadget users, so battery packs and ways to carry stuff around are always welcome.

Answer (score 18):

My wife just re-read the popular (and excellent) [Marie Kondo decluttering book](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1607747308) and we decided to start donating our we'll-use-it-someday-but-actually-won't stuff.

Made 3 trips to Goodwill over the past break week with clothes, kitchen stuff, board games, usable computer parts, etc.

(For those not in the US, [Goodwill](http://www.goodwill.org/) is a charity that takes donations and sells the useful items in their thrift stores, using the proceeds for their social programs.)

Answer (score 18):

My spouse and I have an extra room in our house, and currently it is filled with a woman who needed a place to stay and didn't want to go to the local mission.  She's gradually getting back on her feet, and hopefully will have a job soon.  Because we live out in the country, we bought a car for her to drive.  Once she has a job, I'll add her name to the title, and when she's ready to live on her own, I'll remove my name and it can go with her.

Her sons and teenage granddaughter recently moved and have lost their jobs.  So for Christmas, we bought food for her to take to them, and invited them to Christmas dinner and presents.  I saw the teen give a small shy smile when she opened one gift, but we mostly stayed out of the way, and made sure most of the gifts were from the house guest.

(We benefit from the house guests - we've acquired three god-grandchildren from two of our previous house guests.  It is never one sided.)

Comment: BTW, I mostly hang out on The Workplace.

Comment: Inspiring! Thanks for sharing

Comment: My box of swag arrived yesterday.

Answer (score 17):

Every year, my local grocery store sells these in the weeks leading up to christmas:

[image]

They are 5€ bags full of long shelf-life products that are for local soup kitchens. The exact contents of the bag are customized in cooperation with the local soup kitchens and the grocery store sells them at a bit under cost. When you buy one of those bags, you don't actually take it home, you just deposit it into a container next to the checkout. The store then donates all bought bags to local soup kitchens who distribute them to in need families and inviduals in the area.

I buy some every year, and the grocery store in my town is almost always sold out of them by the end of the week. This year, the store chain sold over 460.000 of these bags (and chipped in 40.000 worth itself) for in need families.

Comment: I used to buy them in the past as well, but unfortunately this year our market didn't do this. They're really cool and it's an easy way of helping people! :)

Comment: Yay, we do something similar in Switzerland (cantons of Geneva and Vaud) where it's called "Samedi du partage". Always feels good to join in.

Answer (score 16):

Some of you may already know that I like [crocheting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crochet) stuff, A LOT. This all started back when I was in University. The owner of the [Textile Research Centre](https://www.trc-leiden.nl/index.php?lang=en) came by and taught us a course on archaeological textiles. She ended her class with the message that 'you're welcome to drop by, and help out'.

I'd never really been a really outgoing person, but the following week I (really nervously) stepped across their doorstep and enjoyed being a volunteer there. It was there that I was first introduced to crafts, I learned to do a bit of [shuttle tatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatting) when helping to set up an exhibition. While I can't really help them out by donating stuff to their collection, I still like to give a bit to their fundraisers whenever funds allow.

Years later, I'm still into all sorts of textile related crafting, all as a result of that one encounter. And I'm trying to use it for good too. I crochet a lot of small stuffed animals in between bigger projects, and they go to charity. Last year, most of them went to an orphanage that some people I know volunteer for, they took them there on their yearly visit. A few have ended up in [shoeboxes](https://www.edukans.nl/programma/schoenmaatjes/) (sorry, Dutch link) together with other school supplies, going to kids in faraway countries. This year, well, who knows? They're going to a good cause again, that's for sure.

Whenever I'm doing bigger projects, I tend to buy yarn kits. Often, these are quite royal and I end up with leftover yarn. Whatever yarn I have left from such a project goes (through a friend) to the local establishment of the Salvation Army. Here, it is used in craft gatherings, where people can just walk in. It helps those that don't have the money to spend on anything besides basic necessities while giving them an outlet to forget their worries for a while and relax. I've heard most people really enjoy making either clothing they can use or toys they can give to their kids.

Answer (score 16):

A few years back, I donated blood pretty regularly (I'm O+). When a family member got cancer, I stopped donating so I'd have a pint ready if they needed one. The need never arose and, at this point, won't. (For those thinking about doing this, retrospectively I'd recommend that you continue your regular donation schedule unless your relative has a particularly rare type that you match. I think this would have done more net good.)

I've been trying to get in the habit of donating again this past year by inviting friends to donate with me. In practice, this has meant donating less than I otherwise would, but I think it's been a net positive: many folks want to donate and are up for it if they have a friend along.

One reason I feel it's important to donate is that a lot of people who would like to can't.

Remember the shooting at that gay nightclub in Orlando? Afterwards, many people wanted to donate, but donations from "men who have had sex with men" [are](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/16/health/orlando-shooting-renews-debate-over-limits-on-gay-men-donating-blood.html) [restricted](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/16/health/orlando-shooting-renews-debate-over-limits-on-gay-men-donating-blood.html). It sucks when you want to help someone and you can't. It sucks when things are out of your control.

Do you have globe-trotting friends? They may not be able to donate either. Spending time in the tropics, the United Kingdom, or a host of other places makes a person [ineligible](http://www.redcrossblood.org/donating-blood/eligibility-requirements/eligibility-criteria-alphabetical-listing#arc11) to donate (in the US) either temporarily or permanently.

It can also be more random. At one point people in Miami [couldn't donate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2016/07/28/fda-temporarily-halts-blood-donation-in-two-florida-counties-over-zika-fears/) due to Zika virus.

In total, only 38% of the U.S. can donate. And [only 10%](http://www.redcrossblood.org/learn-about-blood/blood-facts-and-statistics) of those who are eligible do.

96% of us in the US rely, every day, on the 4% of the US who does donate.

If you can donate, you should. [7] Do it for yourself. Do it for your friends. Do it because your friends can't and have friends who need it.

I'm going to try to be better at donating this coming year, and I hope you will to.

If you're in the SF Bay Area (or Seattle, Boulder, or Boston - I travel often) and would like someone to donate with, drop me a line!

[image: Donate blood]

^ This could be you! ^

<sub>(I primarily use StackOverflow and SciComp.)</sub>

Comment: I just watched this three-part documentary called *Blade* and it shows that the blood collection drives are actually just a scam to feed the vampire cartel.

Comment: Darn it: you've figured me out...

Comment: +1 for encouraging others to go with you and for pointing out how few people are actually allowed to donate.

Comment: This is so cool. I connect with you in so many levels (also O+, lol). I used to donate blood all the time and was always trying to brainwash my friends to come along. I convinced a few and I'm so happy when they text me saying they still go :). It's such a simple gesture and it's amazing how much it can help. It's easy to take it for granted.. but when you experience needing it you see how important it is. Keep up the good work, Richard. Hope you get lots of cool swag from SO :)

Answer (score 15):

Christmas this year was the year of the new laptops - my parents', my sister's, *and* my laptop were all something like 7 years old, so we replaced the lot.

Over the past week or so, I've erased each one and refreshed Windows so they work reasonably smoothly again, and gave them to a friend of ours whose charity takes them out to Kenya to use in education.

Comment: *Moves to Kenya* so that I can scrap the data off of your hard drives. 

Comment: That'd be why I erased them, @WELZ :)

Comment: @WELZ He'll be testing how *well* you erased them...

Answer (score 15):

After the 2010 Haiti earthquake, the church my wife and I attend decided we needed to do something that would lastingly help the people of Haiti and not just [dump free stuff that destroys the local economy](http://analytics.excellenceingiving.com/post/3461988-donated-caskets-killed-jobs-in-haiti) or [make a bunch of empty promises](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2013/02/28/172875646/what-happened-to-the-aid-meant-to-rebuild-haiti).

Instead we opened an orphanage called [Children's Hope](http://www.childrens-hope.com/). It's gone from a simple orphanage to a school, medical/dental clinic, and meal center. Instead of just going and leaving, we've made it an ongoing effort and it's making the kind of impact Haiti needs. I continually donate to this organization, as even small donations have such a major impact.

I've done most of my work on Stack Overflow (mostly just moderation of late)

Comment: The "dump free stuff that destroys the local economy" point is something I wish I saw talked about more often. That almost always points out giving that's more for the benefit of the emotions of the giver than the needs of the recipient.

Answer (score 14):

This post is about a sweat donation. Quite literally.

Years ago, our children both attended a local [forest kindergarten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_kindergarten) which has an amazing, dedicated staff and was just perfect for them. The kindergarten is run by a public charity / non-profit association and is at least partly funded by whatever fundraising activity the parents and other supportive individuals can come up with.

One of the backbones of the budget are bake sales a few times a year. Not the bake-a-tray-of-brownies kind, but selling handmade bread, baked in traditional wood-fired oven in a [bake house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakehouse_(building)). The breads are a huge hit and there's a loyal customer base that even pre-order their loaves. It's hard work that requires both physical strength and experience. Those ovens don't have a dial to set the temperature... I lead a team of volunteer bakers for six years while my kids attended the kindergarten.

This year, shortly after Christmas, I returned to take over responsibility for a full day of baking as my successor had had a baby shortly before. So in eight hours of hard work (and laughter), a small team and I together baked almost 300 loaves of bread plus sweet raisin buns, bacon buns, [hefezopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hefekranz) and other baked foods.

I don't know the exact numbers, but from experience, the net result should be around 1000€. What - in my opinion - is even more valuable is that by stepping in, the association didn't have to cancel the event, keeping the customers happy and hopefully securing their loyalty for the future (some of them are also generous donors).

[image: last few loaves]

<sup>I usually hang out on Seasoned Advice and Coffee, Gardening, Parenting, Lifehacks and German (which kind of fits nicely with this post, methinks).</sup>

Answer (score 13):

This post was exactly what I needed.

Today I received my first, post-graduation, salary. And, as I promised myself a long time ago, it was time to make a big donation instead of the 5~10€ I usually give (actually, the truly big one will have to wait until next month as I am still a little bit short on money).

I care a lot about different topics, so here are where I intend to give my money:

- Autism => already choose an association
- Animals well-being => already choose an association and also joined it
- Transgender people rights (and LGBT+ people rights) => already found an association, waiting to see if there is a better one
- Association for the safety of prostitutes => Didn't look yet
- Feminism => Found one in the USA, waiting to find another one in France

As it turns out, will I was looking for associations to give money to, I found one I'm willing to also give time to and joined it! It for animals' well-being and I already made my first contribution as a member of this association! (it took me only a few minutes but it did feel very good!)

I do care about a lot of things and, unfortunately, can't give to all of them. So to choose the ones on the list below, I asked myself this question: "What do I care about and feel other people don't care enough about?"

---

**Edit**: Reading all those other answers made me remember that I also deeply care about refugees and there right to live. That's why I intend to also give to an association for them and try to do more if I can.

---

<sub>In case you are wondering, I'm a big interpersonal stack exchange fan, even though I do lack in those interpersonal skills.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

We should serve back to the community where we live in, in one way or another. Since my college I've been associated with few of the organization where we tried giving back to society. Since it's a winter season, last week we organized an event in our society, in which we donated old woolen clothes to the nearby homeless people. I am also a member of [CRY](https://www.cry.org/) which works for underprivileged children.

During my college, I was part of one of our student group called **"Udaan"** which was aimed at teaching and helping the junior students. But during the weekends, we use to organize special classes in which we use to invite underprivileged students from nearby villages, and we use to teach them and provide basic stationary. Here is one of the picture from that time which I got from our group's Facebook page:

[image: Udaan Society]

Currently I am working as Software Engineer for Quotient Technology, and our organization also believes in returning back to community. Every year our company organizes few events known as [**"Power of We"**](https://www.quotient.com/power-of-we/) where we contribute towards our community.

Here's one of the photo from 2017's Go Green initiative, where our group of 30 people planted around 150 trees. I am the guy plugging away in blue T-shirt.

[image: Gog Green - Power Of We 2017]

Few months back, in 2018, we organized a **"Strike for Cause"** [*Bowling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling) event in our offices globally in which our company donated $100/strike *(don't know what was the target we achieved, but many Strike happened)*.

Comment: This post is both powerful and familiar. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 13):

I thought showing off all our awesome knitting projects was going to be my favorite MSE post of the holiday season, but this one has gone and raised the bar. I suppose it's no surprise that a crowd that likes to hang out on a Q&A site geared toward *helping people solve their problems* also likes to help people IRL, but it's been really wonderful to read about them all today. It warms the proverbial cockles of the heart!

I don't need a box (I work here so I'm up to my ears in Stack gear) but I'm inspired to share. This fall I began volunteering at the Bicycle Collective in my city. They take used bicycles in varying degrees of disrepair and either: strip them of useful parts and recycle the rest; fix them up enough to donate to folks in need of low-cost transportation; or repair and shine them up to sell in the shop (where the proceeds go back into financing the Collective's charitable activities). For folks who need a bike but can't afford to buy one, they have a program that lets anyone come into the shop and volunteer a certain number of hours in exchange for a bike. People learn bike mechanic skills, socialize with other volunteers, and earn their own bike, so it's a triple win!

Just before the holidays, we partnered with some university students and a social worker who connected us with a housing complex for refugee families. We piled 30 little kids' bikes onto a trailer and trundled on over to distribute them as part of their holiday gift assistance program. Watching a bunch of kids zoom around the parking lot on their new(-to-them) bikes was the highlight of my December! (One kid was already a solid BMX rider, hopping and skidding all over the place.)

The shop was closed for the holidays, but this week I'll resume my normal volunteer activities - I either work on bikes that need fixing, or just help organize the shop and keep things running somewhat smoothly. It's a good cause and it feels great to be of help, but honestly it's also just a good crowd and a really fun way to pass a few hours.

Anyway, it's not so much a stuff-a-way as a time-a-way, but Tim says that counts so I'm sharing it.

(Also, in our house we buy toilet paper from [Who Gives A Cr*p](http://whogivesacrap.org). Because, well, we do! It's a super easy Good Thing to do - we gotta buy TP anyway, might as well make it count a little extra.)

Answer (score 13):

I recently saw a homeless man holding a sign on the side of the road. I always keep some canned food and water in the back of my car just in case I see someone in need, so I pulled over and brought him some food and water. As I talked with him, he mentioned the weather, and I know it gets really chilly here in the winters. I gave him my coat since his clothing wasn't going to be enough to keep him warm during the freezing nights and I had an extra jacket at home anyways.

He mentioned that he's been trying to talk with other people to get back on his feet but hasn't had much luck. I usually don't give money to homeless people, but I just got some money from relatives for Christmas and knew that he needed it way more than I did, so I gave him some cash so he could find a hotel or place to stay like he said he was trying to do.

I've never had a bad experience helping homeless people, or anyone in need really. They've always been grateful for what I could offer and I hope to get more involved in helping the homeless in my community in the future.

Answer (score 12):

My partner and I moved three times in 2018 but finally landed in our first house a few weeks ago. As we unpacked our boxes we collected all the clothing, household items, and kitchen gear that we hadn't used at all in the last year.

We took everything (several boxes spread out over two or three trips) to two local charities:

- [ARC Community Services](http://www.arccommserv.com/index.html) runs an advocacy and case management service for women, femmes, and others who experience gender oppression.
- [St Vincent de Paul of Madison, WI](https://svdpmadison.org/) runs a food pantry, charitable pharmacy, and housing projects, among many other services for those experiencing homeless and inadequate housing.

Answer (score 12):

I work in a country where, up to June 2018, all employees must [pay their union one day of work as a tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_labor_reform_(2017)). Since the end of this tax was [confirmed by the Supreme Court](https://www.araujopolicastro.com.br/en/publications/compulsory-employees-union-contributions/), I ended up thinking on what to do with this, rather small, amount of money and decided to give it to other people who would need it much more than me.

I usually help people by donating my no longer used clothes in the winter time and "adopting" poor children's letter to Santa, so they receive the gift they asked for, but donating money directly to people is not something I'm used to do.

I know some people might get offended if you directly give them money, so my plan was to be extra-generous with tips and I just did that during my short summer vacations (which ended today). It felt really good to talk to a waiter, get to know him a little better instead of just shouting "another beer please" and in the end make him smile with an extra tip, which I know is needed for him and his family. It felt so good that, after all, I gave more than I planned!

I hope other fellow brazilians see this post as an opportunity to start donating to charity. Even a small amount of money as one-day work and a chat with someone who is working for you, even for a few minutes, might make a difference! As for myself, I'm planning in doing this more often, not just once in a year!

<sub>I primarily contribute to Travel and Portuguese SE, but am an avid consumer of Stackoverflow, AskUbuntu and anything interesting I see on the hot network questions ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 12):

This year, one of my colleagues, who has a friend who runs a refugee center, had the luminous idea of organizing a Christmas party for the children in the center. They could not spend Christmas at home for obvious reasons, and presents weren't really on their parents' mind (if their parents were even there). She asked all of us, when we went for Christmas shopping, to buy an extra present for one of the children in the center. (In case you're wondering; I've bought a football. Sports are fun *and* important for the development of children.) Together, we've managed to shine a tiny bit of light into 76 children's lives.

Just to be sure, this project is more work than just sending out an email to the entire company; you have to gift-wrap some of the presents, sort them by age and gender, buy some additional presents with funds provided by colleagues who aren't regularly in the office, transport the presents from the office to the party, etc. But it's a very nice idea which I can recommend to all of you for next year. You really get the feeling that you're making the world a better place *together as colleagues*, which is special; normally, we're only doing things together because it pays our salary, it's fun (or if we're lucky, both). If this entry qualifies for the swag, I'll be more than happy to share it with all of them (they're all (semi-)frequent Stack Overflow users).

Answer (score 11):

My extended family decided to skip a gift exchange this year at our Christmas Party and instead collect donations for a local women's shelter.  Items such as hygiene products, socks, towels, etc.

I primarily spend time on Stack Overflow, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Movies & TV, and Worldbuilding.

Answer (score 11):

This New Year, one of the organizations I donated to was [GiveDirectly](https://www.givedirectly.org/), which donates cash directly to the extreme poor, who then typically spend it on necessities like food, medicine, and education.

Notably, GiveDirectly and other direct cash transfer programs don't restrict what the recipients can spend the money on, on the theory that the recipients know better than the distributors what they most need. This approach has [strong empirical support](https://www.givedirectly.org/research-on-cash-transfers), is [endorsed by GiveWell](https://www.givewell.org/charities/give-directly), and makes intuitive sense, so I'm happy to support it.

I've also been volunteering time and Ruby on Rails expertise to work on the website of a local library, and plan to do more this year.

Favorite Stack Exchange sites:

- Stack Overflow
- Science Fiction & Fantasy
- Bricks

Answer (score 10):

This year my family and I spent the morning of Christmas Eve wrapping gifts in a mall to raise money for a local non-profit which supports persons with developmental disabilities. It was really nice because we got to spend time together doing a thing, the people who had their presents wrapped got beautifully wrapped presents, and the non-profit got a bunch of funding to continue doing the valuable work that they do. :D

I'm not sure if this counts for the event since it happened more than a week ago, but it was something I wanted to share :)

Answer (score 10):

My kids received so many presents last month! And they grow out of old toys, books, puzzles, games, and clothing so quickly.

I like to reduce, reuse, recycle, and donate. So one kid might get the other's hand-me-downs, and our friends' kids might get some things, but much of it gets donated to the local thrift store.

**I even involve the kids by asking them what should go where because I want to start a new generation of givers.** :-)

Answer (score 10):

As part of the drive to give, and in the spirit of [10 Years of Stack Giving Back](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/20/10-years-of-stack-giving-back/), I will also be creating a contest in contest here.

**Make your vote count!**

### By the end of this contest, whatever the end score of this answer is, I will donate the dollar amount of the score to the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/).

---

The contest has ended, and the total stands at 10, which is a little low, so I will just do 25. Here is the receipt:

[image]

---

This has to be one of my favorite MSE events thus far.

Every year I donate to a set of charities, and then to one select place with a larger amount. For 2018 it was a local City College's Computer Science Department.

The money went towards three categories: scholarships for women, entry into the ACM-IPC International Collegiate Programming Contest, and sponsorship for a female student to travel to a conference.

However, that was prior to this contest so I figured I would choose some non profits to donate to as well for this specific event. The pictures below are from the receipts. Each link will take you to a donate page for the respective non profit as well if you too were interested in donating.

- **[St. Jude's Children's Hospital](https://www.stjude.org/donate/donate-to-st-jude.html)**
  [image]
- **[Wounded Warrior Project](https://support.woundedwarriorproject.org/Default.aspx?tsid=10043)**
  [image]
- **[Doctors Without Borders](https://donate.doctorswithoutborders.org/onetime.cfm)**
  [image]

Answer (score 10):

I fill up gently used purses with feminine products, nonperishable snacks, hand sanitizer, a nail kit, lip balm, a bottle of water, $5 to Dunkin Donuts, and anything that might be useful depending on the season. While driving, whenever I see a homeless woman I offer her a bag. This way she has some needed items, hopefully a few little extras, all in an easy to carry bag.

A very proud moment for me; I had bought my kids some donuts and as we were stopped at a traffic light my older son (10) asked if he could give a homeless man his donut. So he rolled down the window and offered the man a donut. My son is autistic and only has sweets rarely for medical concerns. So for him to think that someone else might want his prized treat more, really moved me.

Thanks Stack for giving Back!

My favorites would be Stack Overflow, Database Administrators, and Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a great idea!  I never thought of filling up purses (or canvas bags for that matter).  I'm stealing this idea. :-)

Answer (score 9):

I spent a few hours of my time over holiday break preparing and delivery food baskets to people in need.  The baskets were provided by the church and donations from the congregation.

Answer (score 8):

I was very confused about sharing this story here as it was more of collective work and others were also there to sort it out.

---

It started by forming a committee in our office where our aim was to help HR with all those fun activities as she was short of helping hands. And while deciding our first Christmas activity together in 2018, someone suggested we should do some charity work too and all of us come on-board. We targeted a few orphanages, but it was not an easy deal as during Christmas and new year they have more visitors and we have to get a dedicated day for what we have planned. So we come up with idea to target small scale orphanages where we can go easily and also help the one who don't get that much limelight for their work.

It was *Shalom Home*, an organisation which don't only keep orphan kids, but it also helps poor ones with their education where their real parents are able to educate them. We asked them to give a kid's wish list as our "Make a wish" secret Santa theme. And we got so many generous employees in our office who openly participated with either sponsoring gifts or money. Even a few came as volunteers. We just got instruction to not give expensive gifts as they want to keep their wishes grounded and reasonable as they are the kids who are not as lucky as us who can easily buy iPhones or iPads and raising expectation will not help them in long run, so we have to adjust them with alternative gifts.

The day when it was all planned fun committee member and with other volunteers arrived there. We met the head of Shalom Home who was a very nice guy and running the whole place with little helping hands and providing those kids proper education and also extracurricular activities. It started with their talent display with singing, dancing, and display of how well they were in playing those musical instruments which most of us can't even handle.

Then we had lunch and we thought to go with pizza. It was better; we got a chance to sit among them and have food. Those kids were very well mannered and it was delight for us to spend time with them. After food we started distributing gifts and there curious faces and the excitement reminded me of my childhood. After that we clicked some pics and they were very fun with poses :D I can't share them all here as I need to get permission from others  but here is one glimpse:

[image]

Then we played fun games like musical chair and in the end, we met the uncle, and he got so emotional and said that he loved our visit and will expect us to come again some day.

To be frank I really thought to go again, but I never worked around it, but a year is already over and we as fun committee will be planning a similar event soon and I am so excited about it.

---

My favorite SE sites are of course [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) where I recently retired as moderator. And the second favorite will be Stack overflow which always come as helping hand with my work and then [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6006/ducky-momo) and [Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/). And I do have an eye for the [hoodie from long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271392/182734) ;D

Answer (score 8):

I quite enjoyed reading stories of others good deeds so thought I'd share a bit of my own story.

My wife and I have a few chosen charities that we support but the main one we support, both financially and by volunteering, is our local blood bike group.

[image]

For anyone unfamiliar with what these groups do, we support hospitals by providing free emergency transportation of anything that will fit on the back of a bike as long as it will benefit patient care. Typical items we transport are units of blood/platelets, various samples, and patient notes. Blood bike groups cover almost the whole of the UK and there are many groups offering similar services around the world. More info here http://www.bloodbikes.org.uk/

---

Another shameless plug for a charity I support is [Ride To The Wall](https://www.rttw.org/). If you're a biker in the UK I would encourage you to look at attending the annual charity event on the first Saturday of October each year. All funds raised go to supporting the [National Memorial Arboretum](http://www.thenma.org.uk/). A beautiful national memorial to all our heroes who lost their lives in the line of duty since WWII.

[Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) is my favourite StackExchange site though I'm also an regular lurker on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Every month my Father and I save 10% of our incomes to buy warm socks, "कम्बल"s (it's kind of like a thick blanket) which we distribute among the not so fortunate homeless people living on streets during the brutal cold weather, like every year this year too we distributed them hoping it will be of some help.

This year we also decided to start contributing to a local NGO which provides free education to under privileged children in India, hopefully this will make a difference in at least one child's future.

Answer (score 7):

#### Small efforts do make a difference

I've not made a significant contribution to the society since I left college 2 years back.

So, this happened just before I left the company for new year weekend.

There's a local vendor who stands outside our office premise and sells warmed nuts and bhelpuri at extremely generous price. It gets extremely cold this part of the year in north india. He does not own proper clothes to keep himself warm but stays till late to earn maximum amount.

On asking why he jeopardises his health, he said this is the most profitable time of the year and he wants to make sure he has enough savings before `holi`, when he goes back to his village to his family.

Since he would not take any monetary help, I gave him my spare jacket so that he can himself warm. Also, after lunch when my team comes back I make sure to sway the group near his stall so that people buy stuff from him.

Just sharing this to make a point that even small efforts can help a person more than we can think of.

Answer (score 6):

My wife and I moved recently, and rather than deal with extra boxes of general stuff, we chose to give away our excess electronics and clothing despite our recent financial stress. Most went to our local Goodwill, but some went to a friend who just had a child, some went to family, while some of the electronics went to our (now) nearby elementary school.

Answer (score 6):

Good timing. I just received the last few parts I need to fix up an old gaming PC, so that I can give it to a young friend who's learning how to code. Also to stream old Nintendo games on the interwebs, but that's par for the course these days.

I'm mostly active on the Music Stack Exchange, which is an extension of doing various community music things in my spare time. I wanted to get better at explaining Stuff™, and it seemed like a productive way to help out.

I'd encourage all of you 20-somethings out there to get involved with the next generation. It's a lot of fun, and it really means something to the kids. It turns out that teenagers are just garden-variety people, so you can just talk to them. Nothing too challenging, even for stereotypical engineers like myself. And spending time with people is usually more valuable than just giving them stuff.

Answer (score 6):

This post convinced me to organize and find some clothes I didn't use last year. Donated 10 t-shirts, 5 pants and a coat.

Answer (score 6):

I got a new bicycle and gave my older one to [Bike Athens](https://www.bikeathens.org/engage/brp/), a nonprofit company which repairs old bikes and gives (or sells the nicer ones to pay its rent) bikes to those in need of transportation. They also have a repair-your-own-bike class and run mostly on volunteers to fix up old bikes.

I've also built a relationship with a couple of the homeless people in town through [Athens PB&J](http://www.athenspbjs.org/about) which uses food as a medium to build relationships with the homeless in the city over time. It's a very slow process most of the time, but being in their life helps them have some (minor) form of accountability and helps them know that someone cares about them.

<sub>I participate mostly on GraphicDesign and StackOverflow.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

My wife and I have 4 kids and toys aplenty.

This year someone new to our area posted in a community group on social media they'd just moved to the area in adverse circumstances and didn't have resources for gifts for their young children. We had two different doll houses for our girls, and so cleaned the smaller but sturdier one up and gave it to the family as a gift they could give their kids.

Next year we plan to participate in a toy swap program for even more of our kids gifts where we give things away our kids aren't playing with, and "shop" for many of our kids gifts among things others are done with.

Less buying? Less stuff? More giving? More toys that get played with longer? No Toy Story 3 tales?

Yup, winning.

Oh, and Superuser is my home.

Answer (score 6):

My wife and I always scrounge together as much cash as we can around new years to donate to a cause we want to support. This year, we donated a few hundred dollars to [Maggie's Place](https://www.maggiesplace.org/) to help fund utility costs, buy material/food needs, and help procure transit for mother's in need.

> Founded in 2000, **Maggie’s Place** provides life-changing programs and
>   services for pregnant and parenting women and their children by offering a warm and welcoming community, a safe place to live and learn, and on-going services to help them become self-sufficient.

If you feel inclined to help, you can support their cause [here](https://maggiesplace.networkforgood.com/).

[image]

[image]

<sup>*I use Bio.SE the most, followed by SO, CV, Academia, etc. (see my profile for full usage "ranking").*</sup>

Comment: Also, for those looking to help out those in need but convinced neither you nor your local thrift store or Walmart have anything worth sharing.... Hint of the day: COUPONS and SALES are your friend! We just bought a $180 men's coat from JCPenny's for a gift giving tree for some needy folks in our community for Christmas...after working the coupons and sales (that we got *at* the store), that jacket cost a cool $23!  GET CREATIVE AND GET OFF YOUR a** :)

Answer (score 6):

When you grow up, you outgrow clothes. It was the same case for me too. Whenever there were enough clothes, my mother sold them in exchange of utensils. One day, when my mother was selling those clothes, I saw a homeless kid of my age wearing worn out pant. So, I took one pant out of the bundle and gave it to him.

After that a tradition started. Whenever I get a handful of clothes to give away or see a person in need, I give those clothes to them. I mostly do this in winter when people are in need the most. There were some sweaters and a pant this time, which I donated just last month. Since I don't take pictures of me giving stuff, so can't post one.

I am giving my entry here so I can give away stuff I might receive. :)

<sub>And my favorite SE sites are Stack Overflow, Movies & TV, and Interpersonal Skills, regardless of order by the way.</sub>

Comment: Ohh, nice gesture and intentions :)

Answer (score 6):

I am into books. My idea of a happy evening is a mug of coffee (yes, a cup ain't enough!) and a good book to accompany it with. Hence, at any instance in time, I have a lot of books with me.

Now, some fellow bibliophiles may disagree with me, but I like to donate those books instead of keeping them in my closet (why should knowledge be limited to those who can afford it?). I do keep the ones that are too close to me, but most of the rest go to the local community library we have going here in my area.

Because no soul should be deprived of books.

Comment: Nice thought, I agree. Knowledge is nobody's monopoly, let's share it as much as we can.

Answer (score 6):

I donate 20 euro a month to [UNHCR](https://www.unhcr.org/) since 4 years right now.

When I started working 5 years ago, I took the habit to have breakfast in a bar with coffee and a brioche (the equivalent of 2 euro in Italy) every workday, because when I was student I couldn't afford this kind of expense. After a year I decided to quit this habit and give the equivalent month expense to people that really needs help. 
I chose to give the money to refugees because to me nothing is worst that loosing your house, your family and your country because of war and people greed's.

My favorite SE site is StackOverflow

Answer (score 6):

My partner and I have been volunteering with a [Harm Reduction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harm_reduction) organization for the last several months. For those that are unfamiliar, Harm Reduction, the way our org does it at least, is essentially peer to peer education about drugs, and health. We acknowledge that people are going to use substances, but that the harm associated with those substances can be drastically reduced by arming people with factual, unbiased information in a judgment free environment.

What does peer-to-peer education look like? Well, we travel all over our region setting up booths at clubs and festivals, and for the most part we just talk to people. Where the venue allows, we also offer no questions asked substance testing, free water, ear plugs, and condoms.

Substance testing is probably the most impactful part of our work. I can't begin to tell you how many lives are saved and how many emergency room visits are avoided by field testing. Most people who get adulterated substances don't know what they were about to put in their bodies. Once tested, we can have an honest dialogue about what the substance is, what the risks are, symptoms of overdose, risk of dependency, and so on.

One of the major things we look out for in the Harm Reduction world these days is fentanyl. One of the leading contributors to the epidemic of opioid related deaths. We provide free testing for fentanyl as often as we're allowed, and we sell take home test strips that are as simple to use as a basic litmus test.

I know that this kind of work is seen as falling into a gray area by some. People perhaps don't like the idea of "enabling", but to those people I usually say:

> This is a public health issue. It doesn't discriminate. Rich, poor, young, or old, most everyone will know someone who has been directly affected at some point in their lives. By providing these services we can save lives. By simply educating people, we can empower them to make better choices.

Answer (score 6):

I donated four units of blood to Red Cross this past year and I gave four medium boxes of unneeded clothes, pots and pans, and other items to Goodwill.

Answer (score 6):

I helped purchase a bike for my company's annual Toys for Tots bicycle drive. In addition to the bikes pictured, money was raised to purchase 40 more bicycles!

I use Stack Overflow the most.

[image]

Comment: What a clever idea for a Toys for Tots drive!

Answer (score 6):

I was fortunate enough to land a pretty good software development job in 2017, and since then I've been blessed with some disposable income. In 2018, I donated over $1500 to various charities, but mainly to St Jude's Children Research Hospital and Hilarity For Charity (a charity for Alzheimer's research/patient care) My grandmother has Alzheimer's/dementia and it has been pretty tough for everyone in the family, so that cause is especially important to me, and St Jude's helps children pay for and fight through things that no child should ever experience.

It's been hard for me to dedicate my time or resources, but I do have the extra income to at least help that way. So here's to another year of donations! In honor of this post, I'll be making my first charitable donations of 2019, starting with $100 to St Jude's and $100 to Hilarity For Charity!

Thanks for everything you do at Stack Overflow/Exchange. This community is an amazing place! I mostly hang out on Stack Overflow, but I'm also fond of the Superuser and Ethereum communities as well.

Answer (score 6):

As most others have said aswell, this is an amazing idea and a good way to help those in need! I approve big time!!!

Now for my own story, just like some other people in this thread I donate my blood. I've been doing this for around a two years now (I got into it right as I turned 18) and I still have no regrets. It was a very easy decision for me since my blood comes back eventually so I don't lose anything, and it can help people stay alive. Feeling like a tiny superman over here!

I'm also a full organ donator and I'm even donating my brain to research facilities (both only when I pass away though, I kinda need them to live for now).

I highly encourage everyone to join this trend aswell. You do so much good and perhaps you'll even save a life or two, what more could you want?

<sub>My favorite Stack Exchange site has to be Stack Overflow</sub>

**Warning, spoiler contains a photo of me donating blood. If you're afraid of needles, don't look!**

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

This year my wife and I were hosting a New Year's Eve party and about 11:00 PM we realized to our horror that in the midst of the end-of-year rush we forgot to do our annual charitable donations. So I pulled out a laptop and got the donations done, amidst much hassling that I was both a super-nerd and a super-procrastinator.

Needless to say, donating to charity after boozing it up all evening is a recipe for, er, unadvised levels of generosity.  ;-) For the good of humankind it's a good idea, but not for the good of your bank account!

My favorite beneficiary of our drinks and cash sloshing around was an online donation to sponsor sending a civics class of charter school kids to Washington DC.  I have zero connection to the school or the teacher-- I found the requested sponsorship via Google. But at 11:50 PM it seemed like a great idea to ring in the new year... with civics!  The teacher responded with lots of gratitude but I'm sure she was thinking "WTF?"

Friends: don't let your friends drink and donate!  Actually, do, because it's good for us all.

P.S. - Thanks Stack Overflow for building a force for good in the world of nerds.  I'm old enough to remember developer support before SO and it was expensive, crappy, or often both!

Answer (score 5):

The partners of our work welcome the opportunity to donate to the community, so I and a few coworkers prepare and donate older computers to families and organizations that work with families that cannot afford computers instead of tossing them in the recycling pile.  I did not keep track of the quantity we donated so far but it is probably over twenty.  We have 24 to go for 2019 so far.

We tear down the computers, clean them, thermal paste them, and put newer/lightly used HDDs in them as we replace HDDs with SSDs at work.

We would donate any of the stuff we receive to those organizations as well.  The sixth grade class for example raises money for a trip every year of which we currently help.

Answer (score 5):

I donated a video camera, various electronics parts and wiring, and a drone to our local hacker-space so they could be used by their members in the pursuit of STEM learning.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to accumulate quite a number of surplus electronic components, sometimes I have to order more than I need for minimum order quantities, sometimes projects get cancelled and other times  it's just  components and microcontroller development boards that are perfectly fine but just no longer recommended for new designs.

Rather than binning them or saving for an unlikely rainy day during the year and currently I've been putting them into grab bags and offering them on Freecycle and to anyone else I think might be interested  along with a description of what sort of age / experience group they are likely to suit along with several related electronic books / magazines. It's been good to see them going to a lot of kids with a keen interest in electronics along with a few older folks looking for something new to experiment with.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I congratulate for encouraging others who has done some noble cause Or inspire them to do in future!

We should always help poor and other needy.It doesn't matter you pocket allow it or Not.

Recently in our office we collect cloths of our colleague which they are not using for long time and occupied their wardrobe.

One of our senior suggest we should collect all cloths and should distribute them to small village near to us.

We requested all the team member to bring them in neat condition with iron and collect at office.

We distributed them to required people.

Really when they smile, you fill proud

I like [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) and I am only active there!

Answer (score 5):

Throughout the year, I have occasionally visited senior activity centres to interact with the seniors and learn more about them. In recent years, I’ve made it a point to visit the same activity centre throughout the year so that we can be familiar with one another and I was always able to learn something new from them.

I’ve also donated daily necessities to community centres as I believe in sharing and the importance of giving and the community spirit.

Lastly, towards the end of the year, I often participate in walks conducted by an organisation whereby they would donate 2 bowls of rice every 200m walked. (I’ve just participated in this again 2 months ago.)

I have thoroughly enjoyed such events and I’m glad to do my own part to contribute to my community.

Answer (score 5):

Like many of us here, I also believe that social responsibility is a continuous process, it's not a one-off activity. So, I do whatever I can to the best of my abilities to have it spread around the year. None if the contribution is great / big on it's own, but cumulatively, it makes a difference (*at least, I hope so*).

- In my workplace, I am part of a program which is called "Power of One" where one buck is deducted from my payroll everyday and contributed towards a charitable fund, which is then used for the social activities for underprivileged children (clothing, books, medicine and some toys). Oh, and as employees, we do volunteer for those activities.
- Being a citizen of a geographic where English is not a first or second (not even third, in some places) language, it is difficult for some people to be able to communicate in English (at least, spoken) at a later stage. This creates problem for students in their academic progress (not all the schools use English as teaching medium), this create problems for people living in a metro city and working as small vendors (roadside shops, stalls etc.), daily labors and alike. Being in a city where more than 60% residents are outsiders, there is literally no common tongue other than English. I am part of an initiative taken up in our apartment by the residents, to run some evening classes for anyone who is interested - to teach basics of English and communication, so that they can go out and live freely, without a fear of being "left out". [I could only join during the weekends - due to work timings].
- Recently, when I moved to a new accommodation, while packing there were many stuffs I found which were just lying around and I never actually used them. I had given them away to the underprivileged kids who used to come to play in the ground next to my apartment - some water bottles, two old backpacks, notebooks, some old hoodies, t-shirt and trousers. That day the kids were very happy and allowed me to bat at the very first (we were playing cricket) when I went to play with them. That happiness and smile on their faces - it's just priceless. :)

Thanks for reading this long ... none of the acts are great singularly, but all small steps, combined together, can change many lives around us. I will continue to being part of these activities and will try to involve more, as time permits.

Thanks to all of the contributors here, and to those also who did not create a post but still reaching out to help the humanity - Kudos.

Happy new year 2019 - onwards!!!

Answer (score 5):

An online community I'm a part of of Warhammer/miniature wargame players put together a drive to replace the collections of about 16 folks who had lost their things in the Camp Fire in California. Collected some kits that I had been saving for "someday" projects and sent them on to people to hopefully help them rebuild a small part of what they lost.

Answer (score 5):

I donated to [United Hatzalah](https://israelrescue.org/nasdaily?utm_source=stackoverflow). This amazing EMS organization provides all life-saving services completely for free to all Israeli citizens whether they are Jewish, Christian, Muslim or of any religion or race. The organization also has volunteers from every community in Israel.

Answer (score 5):

Last year around this time my grandfather passed away suffering from leukaemia and one of the members of an online community I participate in has been diagnosed with blood cancer as well. So the one thing I did was donate 50€ to https://www.dkms.de/de and registered as a stem cell donor.

Cancer is a backstabbing piece of garbage and nobody deserves to suffer from it.

<sup>My favorite is Stackoverflow.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

I would like to say, this event is amazing, encouraging people to help others and raise awareness.

Every year myself and my wife (and now my child) will pack multiple shoe boxes for the christmas shoe box appeal (Operation Christmas Child).

We have been doing this probably around 5 years in a row now without fail, This year we were able to pack around 10 boxes to send them off!

We also give regularly to our local food bank at our local grocery store, usually tinned food. Just go in to buy our usual shop and add in a few extra tinned goods, it doesn't cost a lot and I know that some family really struggle and would appreciate this. I always try to think, if myself and my family were in a bad position, I hope there would be people willing to help us. At the end of the day we are the same species.

Answer (score 5):

We (fiance and I) ran two school supply drives this year for the local [Family Services](https://childrenservices.franklincountyohio.gov/). They are underfunded (they all are) and the children involved have been removed from dangerous, abusive, or neglected situations, so they generally don't have anyone. So, to help give them some normalcy in some part of their lives, we ran supply drives at both our workplaces. Backpacks, pencils, calculators, tissues, etc.

The school supply drives are surprising because you think (atleast I did) that they only need them in the fall when children are going back to school, but the sad fact is that children are being removed from their homes throughout the year, so there is no bad time to run these for you local child protective services.

Also, they ran a Christmas drive for the children that was directly beneficial to the children and very convenient as they provided an Amazon wish list and you could have the items directly shipped to the agency.

I thought this would be a good way to help bring awareness to this community of something simple and directly helpful to do at your workplaces for the local community.

My favorite SE sites are https://diy.stackexchange.com/ and SO

Answer (score 5):

My wife and I cleaned out our closet of all items that we hadn't worn lately, and donated them to a local charity!

We also regularly give to several charitable organizations:

- World Vision
- Make Way Partners
- LifeWater
- Children Without Worms
- NetsforLife
- Food for the Hungry

My favorite SE site: StackOverflow

Answer (score 5):

**What**: Platelets donation

**To whom**: ex-coworker diagnosed with leukemia

**How**: It takes about 3h , blood is drawn from one arm then the platelets are extracted using a machine, and the remaining blood components are returned to you through the other arm.

**Why**: Not everybody can donate to anyone, it demands compatibility. He needed 10 people and was looking urgently for donors.
I was (and in fact I still am...) terrified of blood donation, but then when you stop to think, your agony is nothing compared to the good it can do to others.

**Consequences**:

- Since my blood (O-) is "universal donor" I decided to become a regular donor.
- Also, I became a bone marrow donor (and everyone should, you just register yourself as available for donation, and if ever someone is compatible with you [odds are 1 in 10.000] you can save a life).

To be honest, I am neglecting my blood donation, I am taking way more time between each donation, but since this post reminded me of how simple can be to help others, I scheduled donation this saturday. ;)

[image: platelets donation]
<sup>Following @avazula's idea, I also free handly covered sensitive information</sup>

Answer (score 5):

My Grandmother called me out of the blue to ask if I could give her a few hundred dollars (which is a big, big deal for my family.) I agreed on the condition that I would be allowed to look into her finances. I found a lot of unnecessary spending between her and my aunt that was happening largely because of ignorance of personal finance. My grandfather had handled all of the money until his death several years ago, and they've apparently been slowly bleeding their account dry.

I took the advice and tips provided at [money.stackexchange.com](https://money.stackexchange.com) and [reddit.com/r/personalfinance](https://www.reddit.com/r/personalfinance) and got them to a stable budget with a net positive cash flow. My aunt (the caretaker) has a monthly stipend, no services were cut, and now they're free of the stress of making ends meet.

This was kind of a "teach a man to fish" moment, but I also wound up feeding them until they learned to fend for themselves.

I'm a moderator over at Robotics, so any Robotics swag would be huge, or any moderator swag. I'd like to do more with the local robotics clubs and competitions this year, so this would all be awesome to rep at the meets.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if I'm eligible (good standing on meta?), but I would like to share anyway to at least give ideas to others.

---

We have a family near our home without any permanent source of income, which even forced them sometimes to begging. We have set up a small shop for them (for selling vegetables), this year.

Life will still be tough for them, but let's see how it goes.

---

The favorite SE site is [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 5):

### ReStore.

Habitat for Humanity builds houses and helps people get into them who otherwise wouldn't be able to afford it. The organization runs on donations, but also runs a [donation-based thrift store](https://www.habitat.org/restores) that resells ... everything. Literally. Want an old wooden window with panes of high-lead glass for that pinterest project? Go to ReStore. Christmas decorations on a budget or for giving to a local place you like? ReStore. Computers, appliances, tools, kitchen decor, ... I've found Dell monitors there for $5! Not the latest and greatest, but they work and now I have a multi-monitor setup.

We donate fairly often to restore - just sent a load each of the past few months and have another pile ready for departure - and we shop there too. If you want to contribute to their mission, you can donate or shop ... and if you're a true bargain hunter, most of their locations try to purge inventory quickly, so they offer discounts (75% or more) on items they've had for a long time.

Everybody wins.

---

<sub>If it makes a difference, my favorite network sites are probably security, gaming, diy, unix, apple, vi, codereview, workplace ... and can't forget interpersonal. Thanks to everyone who keeps the site running and thanks to everyone who contribute answers and information!</sub>

Answer (score 5):

A woman in my community just had a baby. She doesn't have much family around to help her, and her financial situation isn't great either.

As a mother myself, I know how thrilling, and at the same time challenging it can be to bring home a new little person to join the family, especially when there are other children at home to care for.

I sent over a lovely meal for the weekend and she was so grateful!

I also recently sent a large bag of clothes to a local charity that "sells" the clothes for next to nothing to needy families. It's a win win because I get rid of the stuff I don't need anymore, the families feel they can buy their clothes with dignity and the charity shop uses the money they receive to keep doing their good work.

My favorites: StackOverflow, The Workplace and LifeHacks

Answer (score 5):

My wife and I chose five charities to contribute to this year. Some years we choose organizations like the ACLU and other politically-oriented groups; other years we have donated to animal rights and protection organizations.

This year we chose organizations which help the needy and the homeless, especially children.

For 2019 we chose:

[CityMeals](https://www.citymeals.org) which provides nutritious meals for aging New York City residents.

The [Coalition for the Homeless](http://www.coalitionforthehomeless.org/) which provides legal services, job training, shelter, and food for homeless Americans, including children.

The [Salvation Army](https://www.salvationarmyusa.org/usn/). Even though we are atheists, that doesn't stop us from giving money to religious organizations who help the least fortunate amongst us.

[Women in Need](https://winnyc.org/) to help homeless women and children in New York City.

The [Fresh Air Fund](http://www.freshair.org/) which brings NYC kids out into the great outdoors.

<sub>I visit AskDifferent multiple times a day, and participate in English Language & Usage frequently.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I lost a cat last year, and had a bunch of in-date elderly-kitty cat-food that my new little monsters won't touch, so I've given it to the local wildlife rescue centre for the rescued hedgehogs and fox cubs.

Today I donated an old pair of glasses (never used) to be sent to India to do some good.

And a neighbour who tends the garden of an elderly neighbour took away a bunch of stuff from the garage/shed that I can't use (health problems). (Honest disclosure: I will get veggies next year as a result, as well as a clear garage).

And Oxfam agreed to turn up with two men in a van to clear my 'book room; (30 years accumulation of books and CDs that I don't use any more.)

I could get into this... However, My partner has locked away his entirely excessive clothes collection. And the cats do not seem inclined to share their toy mice.

Answer (score 4):

I am CS student and most of my Friday is off from the college stuff. I teach as lecturer assistant in my campus and get a salary at every end of the semester since one and a half year ago. Starting that day that I got my own money, I save up some of the money and use it to buy ingredients to cook lunch and give it to the beggars or anyone who want it in Friday. I do the shopping and cooking while my partner is the one who distributed it to people in need. At first, I can only cook up to 10 serving, but a couple of months ago, my mom voluntarily helped me on the shopping and cooking and we could make about 50 servings. That activity had been done approximately once in every two or three months. Now I still haven't graduated nor have a settled job yet. But every time my partner and I get an additional project (means additional income), we try to save up and use it to share with others.

[image]

There is another story actually that I want to share. So for two times, I received two gifts from my friend, really useful things that long I have been desiring. That two friend, was not really a close friend actually that makes me think of, why giving me?

Recalling the moment, as a student in the last year study, there happened some of my friends who ask me for a "guidance" related to their thesis. I thought that it is normal since I often "standby" in the campus laboratory so I was easy to be talked to. They are not that "internet person", even that we are on the CS major, so if they found difficulties they often came to me. Long story short, I heard that they have finished their thesis, in term of the project, not the manuscript. So I guess they were thankful to me because I gave them my knowledge? Well, I am thankful if what I am sharing is useful for them.

<sub>my favorite sites: I enjoy learning through StackOverflow and PuzzlingSE (can't decide which is the most favorite)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let me say I love this event!

Here in Belgium, we have this huge event "Music for life", 
It's an entire week which is based on supporting people in need and more particular organizations that support these people in need.

This year the people of Belgium managed to raise 17.286.122 euros. How we do it? By organizing tons of events - everybody is allowed to initiate an event on their own and the money of the event will be donated to a good cause at music for life.

Together with a couple of friends we organized a small low-profile party, each inviting their friends - whom invited their friends - etc. 
We managed to raise around 500 euros of profit, which we donated to the an organization that fights cancer.
It's not a huge sum of money, compared to some of the other events organized for music for life - but considering the fact that we organized this quite last minute and the fact that we were not prepared at all- I believe this is a nice achievement!

Lastly, it's lovely to read about all the nice things everyone here on SE did! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4):

At the beginning of a year or in between I use to purchase clothes, also I receive few T-shirts/shirts as a gift each year.

Last year my dad asked me about my old or new clothes which are not in use or brand new those just tried once but don't like, we collected all and gave it to the person we hired for running small local business, so his kids can wear it. Indeed! It was really a pleasure to see the happiness on their faces.

Answer (score 4):

I'm part of a small volunteer group in the UK that organizes pinball events for charity. For us 'pinheads' it's a win-win.. We introduce this amazing silver-ball hobby to a new generation of kids that have never seen a pinball machine before, and we also contribute all the profits to charity.

Organizing the largest pinball show in the UK (usually with up to 130 pinball machines, brought from all over the UK) is a significant amount of work. We all spend hundreds of hours a year, and personally I end up using most of my vacation days on these things - but the rewards are in the amount we've donated to charity, which I'm very proud to tell people is over £30,000 to date. Most of that has gone to Teenage Cancer Trust over the last few years, where we've also helped introduce pinball to one of the patient therapy wards. I'm told by the nurses there that the patients absolutely love a chance to take their mind of their illness and we all feel that there is a great community behind the pinball scene, so we absolutely welcome any new players that pick up this hobby from our events.

Most of the stuff I give away each year goes towards these pinball events, and specifically to our charity tombolla which is always in need of gaming related prizes.

Seems like an opportunity to promote our events too ;) so I'm happy to announce our next show is at Manchester Central on May 4th/5th
Check our website or facebook page for more details and discounted entry tickets soon when we announce this event: [www.ukpinball.com](http://www.ukpinball.com), [facebook.com/nlpinball](https://www.facebook.com/NLPinball/)

Answer (score 4):

I live in Colombia and there are multiple villages with very poor people that are always in need of something.

Once every 2-3 months I collect old-but-in-good-state (and sometimes brand new) clothes, shoes, and toys from my family, friends, and neighbours, and send them to those poor people.

They are always very grateful and receive us with kindness and generosity!

<sub>My favorite sites are SO and Arqade.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Some coworkers and I donated a number of electronics to a local charity specializing in helping law enforcement forensically interview children who have been abused. The agency works with specially trained officers, social workers, doctors and therapists to help the children both testify via recorded video and audio (to prevent the child from having to face their abuser in court) as well as post care to help them and their families through the ordeal.

The electronics donated are used for raffles and fund raising and this is the third year we’ve done so.

So far we’ve donated More than $2000.00 in brand new electronics and are looking forward to donating further this year.

I’m a stackoverflow user primarily

Answer (score 4):

I donate ten bucks a month each to a variety of charities.  Up to around 30 charities at this point.  They are automatically deducted from my credit card monthly.

I also give old tech and stuff I no longer need to either Goodwill or a local charity that gives stuff for free to people who need it.

I also asked my family of origin to donate the money they would have spent on my gifts to [Community Outreach](http://www.communityoutreachinc.org/), a local group that provides care and lodging to folks who are going through a rough patch.

Answer (score 4):

Every couple of months, my family donates a large bag of clothes, toys and general stuff that we no longer use or require to our local charity shop. This is largely driven by my wife, in order to free up space.

If it was left to me, I would likely hoard it all for life...

> I might need that t-shirt/pair of jeans for painting and decorating... ok, I have 7 painting t-shirts and 3 pairs of jeans...

So I'm glad my good wife organises regular clear outs and that it might be useful to others.

Also, if I see someone sleeping rough on the walk in to work, I will try to buy them a coffee and some breakfast.

I participate mainly SO and MetaSO.

Clear out evidence with clothes ready to go to charity shop:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Every year I and my family donate what we can to a local shelter called "El Amor de Dios" (the Love of God). They receive abandoned kids from 0 to 18 years (legal age in my country).

The past two years we donated clothes and for this Christmas, they asked us for some big trash cans:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have a poor fund that I keep around when I drive, It's usually a combination of singles, 5's or 10's that I put away after getting change whenever I shop. I don't like to give just a dollar to the poor so I use my fund to give them anywhere from 3 to 10 bucks so that they can get themselves some food.

Just last week a peddler approached my car while I was at a red light. I beeped, he came over and I gave him five bucks in singles and asked him to get some food with it. He gave me a huge smile and thanked me multiple times.

I have to say the biggest satisfaction is seeing people's smiles as I give them the money, it's like they've just won the lottery. I will keep doing this as God permits, the more money I get, the more I'll give away. My favorite Stackexchange sites are Stackoverflow and Sitecore.

Answer (score 4):

I was doing a consulting job where I was asked to evaluate the feasibility of using raspberry pis for certain domain specific tasks that until now were being done on windows servers.

I was given around 40 - 50 pis for the project, and after the job I was told to keep them. I donated them to a local organization which runs a coding class for under privileged kids and teens.

My favorite sites are Stack Overflow and Raspberry Pi Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Right before Christmas, a local homeless shelter flooded. In the flood, the sewer and everything backed up. Ugh. It was a mess. Everything had to be thrown away. My family and I, along with the people from my church, gathered clothes, blankets and other necessary items and brought them down to the shelter because they were quite literally starting from scratch with all their supplies.

Favorite Sites: Aviation.SE, Stack Overflow.

Thanks for giving back Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 4):

I recently started volunteeering as a [guide runner](http://www.unitedinstride.com/), available to train and race with visually impaired runners.

If that sounds like something you could do, please click on the link above!

---

<sub>Should have mentioned: if that *doesn't* sound like something you could do, [charity: water](https://www.charitywater.org/) is my favorite "traditional" charity. 100% of donations go to actual water projects; their overhead is completely philanthropist(s)-funded. I challenge my classes every year to donate/fundraise enough to build a well a year!</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I am residing in Kerala, India where it affected flood in August 2018. I am also a victim, and we(with family) moved to a safe place. Moving to safe place is not an end, there's more social media can do at that time. I mostly used WhatsApp.

- Shared details about those who are seeking help at different places.
- Shared tips about shifting from one place to other(by walk) from flood affected areas.
- Shared tips about back to home, cleaning, health etc.
- Few doctors of our locality joined as a group for providing health assistance for flood affected people on every Tuesdays(started on Sep 2018). I took part in campaign as a volunteer.

It was a good experience and proud to be a part of it (Social Media data sharing), and mostly aimed at saving even one person's life from flood affected area.

I joined in Stack Overflow, now mostly using [Android enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I am from Kolkata, India.

Recently, we went to the kali temple (lake kalibari) on New Year's day. Along with my family, we carried with us about 20 packets of biscuits for the needy. There are many poor homeless people near the temple (especially children). We distributed the packets of biscuits among them! The smile on their face on receiving a small packet of biscuit on new years was really sweet and fulfilling :)

I have also bought more such small packets. They don't cost much but can feed a child for a meal.

P.S. I don't have any rep here but am usually active on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I donated last year a lot of clothes for babies to our local hospital, including a very cute baby body with the label "Future Stack Overflow user". I hope I could make a lot parents happy with that.

Comment: LMAO I like the idea "future StackOverflow user"

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. However, I still die for a Stack Overflow T-shirt for myself. :]

Answer (score 4):

We made our annual donation to a local shelter for women and children who need a way out of abusive relationships. This is a very important institution for us, as they provide a useful resource for the local underserved population and are working on healthcare, refugee, and feed-the-homeless initiatives as well.

Stack Overflow is my favorite Stack Exchange site and the one I contribute to the most.

Answer (score 4):

Ooh free stuff!

Fun fact! Last day at school, we gathered books to give at a local children charity.
Guess who gave 25 books! Well, not me, I gave 10 random I had lying around

---

Oops, I guess I am supposed to say that StackOverflow and Travel are my fav sites.

Happy New Year!

Comment: 10 non-bestseller books are probably better than 25 copies of bestsellers that the charity probably already has a hundred copies of. I've seen signs like "Please, no more fifty shades books" because they're so often donated that the last thing the free book store needs is yet another copy to store.

Comment: He indeed gave 25 copies of `50 shades of grey`. Question is, how did you know?

Answer (score 4):

My parents taught me at a young age to give and I have been giving 10% of my income before taxes to my church since I was 6 years old. It wasn't much to begin with, and through college it felt like a sacrifice sometimes, but now it is quite a bit. I believe the principle of generosity rings true no matter who or where you are: you will always get back more than you give.

I am most active on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

I have done multiple kinds of kindness across the years, even in 2018

While most of my kindness have been small like helping people find directions for public transport, or giving people back their lost items, there is one task that I did that was a large effort

This task that I (together with my father) was removing an old cut down tree that was already  cut down from the ground near the dance school in our town.

While removing a old tree doesn't sound as much effort as other people have done, it was actually a lot of effort, as the tree was more than 30 cm in radius. We actually had to take 2 evenings of digging and and cutting away the old water soaked roots before the tree finally went loose, but we were so tired that we didn't had the strength to pull the tree rom the hole we dig to get to the roots, this basically we had to come back here 1 evening later to finally move the old remains of the tree behind the building of the school and making the place tidy again

Answer (score 4):

I recently purchased a new laptop to replace my previous one, which was insufficient for my gaming and other needs. In lieu of discarding it or sending it to E-waste, I instead reinstalled a clean environment, and gave it to a fellow student at my school who did not have a laptop to use (with the software they needed pre-installed)<sup>1</sup>. I'm hopeful that the laptop I considered a clunker might get at least two or three more years of life before it undergoes E-waste recycling.

I've also committed to donating some of my old clothing/shoes that is either too worn or no longer fits me well. I've identified a location that will accept it, separate reusable vs recyclable articles, and put everything to good use. Unfortunately, since I'm home on break I won't be able to actually do this until next week.

<sup>1</sup> It included all of my tech company and hackathon stickers, including a Stack Overflow sticker.

My favorite Stack Exchange sites (in terms of recent use and academic benefit to me) are Stack Overflow, electronics.SE, and Code Review.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this idea, and for the additional encouragement. Reading some of the other posts, I believe that this swag initiative has inspired some people to give a bit more.

You know what I really love? Libraries. I love libraries. I love free access to books, magazines, information, and tools, and convenient non-religious centers for organizing civic activity. In fact, my local library is my primary node in my network of donations: they collect cans of food and warm clothing and money and help get these to the organizations that distribute them. I'm proud to donate food and money to these organizations, but I'm also proud to donate directly to my library.

I like local libraries, and use my libraries all the time. I donate additional money and books to my library, and this last year I became a much more significant monetary donor.

My wife is from a very small town in Eastern Europe, and we donate money to the library in her hometown. We also sponsor the education of a young student named Magda (although admittedly we found out that the nonprofit we were sponsoring her through has some problems, so we expect to need to find a different donation outlet next year).

And I'm a mathematician, and I consider the arXiv like our essential public mathematical  library. And archive.org and Project Gutenberg. I donate to each of these each year as well.

Libraries are awesome.

---

<sub>I'm most active on Math.SE, MathOverflow, and StackOverflow. Cheers.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Every year my company provides a gift for employees, with an option to donate to a charity instead. This past Christmas I used this to donate to [Childhood Cancer Support](https://www.ccs.org.au/) - a charity which at that time of year helps to support children going through cancer treatment. In the spirit of the question asked, I guess it was pre-emptively giving something away I didn't really need.

Also like a few others here, I'm a regular plasma donor. If you are in Australia, check out if [this is something you can do](https://www.donateblood.com.au/). One in three Australians need a blood products in their lifetime, so if not you then someone you know will benefit one day.

Answer (score 4):

This post is about books donation. 
Here's the short story : Normally all the postmen would just leave any package delivered in the society near the building's lift and the packages would get lost / damaged most of the times but this guy delivered a very important and time sensitive package in the rainy season by actually coming to my flat as he thought it must be important. I couldn't thank him enough and when we got to talking he told me he had a son two years younger than me. That's when I decided to give away all my entrance exam books to him. Whenever I see him now, he has the biggest smile on his face :)

My favorite sites are Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

The company I work for is very involved within their community. This year, we participated in the 500K Meal Pack Out drive for Islamic Relief USA. While I don't keep much extra food stocked at home, I went to the store to purchase a bunch of canned goods to donate for the drive. We dropped the food off in December, and a group also volunteered to help actually pack the boxes.

In addition to this, my wife and I tend to make multiple trips throughout the year to drop off extra clothes, electronics (so many extra computer parts!), and home goods at Goodwill. We also donate to various charities, but those mainly tend to be environmental and science based organizations (World Wildlife Fund, VA State Parks, planetariums, etc.).

It's very inspiring to read the stories of how people are helping people. This event is amazing. Thanks for putting it together!

---

<sub>Most active on StackOverflow.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As part of our supposedly annual, but often bi- or even tri-ennial house clean-up before xmas, we at the end of 2018 donated 5 large bin-bags of good used clothing & 4 still serviceable [up to at least Win7 if not newer] computers to local causes.

We didn't do this so anyone would "think well of us" or even say, "thank you" - we did it because it simply seems the right thing to do with things perfectly usable but no longer required.

That it may win me a flashlight feels like I now need a round of applause... but no, I'd just very much appreciate a new flashlight.

Answer (score 4):

Went through our closets and was able to fill three garbage bags full of clothes and blankets that we don't use anymore and took them to Goodwill.

Answer (score 4):

I have volunteered / contributed for multiple causes. I will list them below :

- Since the age of 18, I am a regular blood donor. I am 28 now and till now I can say I've done it for almost 28 times. All it started because my uncle wanted blood for bypass surgery and I donated mine to him. And since then I regularly visiting any nearby blood bank and volunteer by donating blood.
- When I was studying in college I used to visit [Gurudwara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurdwara) which was near to my place. Every Thursday they organize [Langar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langar_(Sikhism)) for all. That time I wanted to help them and contribute something from my end. But because that time I was not earning I do volunteer for serving food to them. So every Thursday I visit Gurudwara just to help people serve food. Even today when I get time I visit Gurudwara and help them as much as I can. Even I visit nearby orphanage sometimes and bring some snacks and food for the little angels.

Apart from this I also do contribution for cause like Relief fund, Fund for Martyr, make homeless children happy by giving them whatever they wants.

---

My favorite sites are [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/),[Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/), [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and [Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/)

PS: As of now I don't have any pictures or any receipt available with me but If I will find something I will definitely update it over here.

Answer (score 4):

I donated to a charity that runs a year round day camp for children who are sick. The camp has medical staff so they (the children) can experience camp without much worry about their illnesses.

I participate in SO, RPG SE, and recently Martial Arts SE.

Answer (score 4):

Posting here for the first time. Too scared to post here as many heroes have posted their stories. So this about last year on Sep 4, 2018, that is my birthday. I was watching all the stories on WhatsApp as most of them are about me. So one of my friend's post came across, who have posted a blood donation ASAP request from a hospital source.

So I called that given number as they required A+ same of my blood. Then I visited that hospital first, while the doctor was injecting needle I don't know what went on my mind I thought I'll be dead after this (newbie in this work also I have a phobia of injections). But all went well I did feel weakness for about 15 to 20 mins but after that, I've executed my all birthday plans.

There are more stories as my parents believe in donation but this story is a favorite of mine as I had decided to donate blood every 3 months. So last month I did that again.

Comment: Blood donation is a really noble act. There are no big or small hero and you're a hero too. Kudos and keep it up! It was the best birthday gift that you could have given yourself :)

Comment: @NimeshNeema tq :) :)

Answer (score 3):

**International Aid**

I have organized two fundraising events to help refugees, homeless, and malnourished children in Venezuela.

We receive donations (and I have donated some items myself) to use in our silent auctions and raise more funds.

If anyone is inclined to help, here they can donate here:
UNHCR fundraising page: https://fundraise.unhcr.ca/team/184796

---

As for my favourite site, I spent most of my time on StackOverflow... with the odd visit to meta, arduino, and apple's stacks

Answer (score 3):

Old story, but thinking back it was the best good deed I've ever made, though it doesn't have happy ending.

About 15 years ago, I was young, had a decent job already, and had very little expenses. I was very active in online programming forum (it's shut down by now) and acquired several good friends there. One of them was a 60+ years old programmer who worked as freelance for long years, called Daniel. (From USA)

Daniel kept in touch with me via email and we wrote each other regularly. At some point, he said that he got only one big project he's working on, with a client who promised to pay when the project is done, some big amount of money. Time passed, and about a year after that he said he finished the big project, sent it all to the client (who wasn't in the US), and the client.... vanished into thin air. No money. No client. No way to contact them anymore.

He didn't find new projects, being dedicated 100% to that  big project and counting on the money to arrive, and it reached a point he was totally out of money. He also had no family that could help, and no IRL friends.

Realizing it's really serious, I asked how I can help, in any way, and he said that only cash money would help in that stage. I asked for his address and sent to that address a big programming book (forgot what it was), with 25 bills of $100 each (attached with transparent adhesive tape so they won't fall) hidden inside it.

After few weeks he sent me the last email I ever got from him, saying big thanks for the money and that it's not enough to keep him at his home, and that he's being thrown to the street very soon. He made it clear it's pointless to try and send more money, and that he'll contact me if things will get better. He didn't.

Comment: Thats's really sad.

Answer (score 3):

Me and my wife are passionate gamers, so we always have the need for the latest hardware. Not because we actually *need* it, but because we can afford it.

Instead of having multiple rigs catching dust I spend my freetime fixing our old stuff and once in a while when we replaced or fixed enough hardware to have fully working PCs (or even consoles) I donate them to the friendly neighborhood youth club where I used to hang around for years. (Don't worry, I keep our hard drives and install new ones instead.)

I'm still grateful for the stuff they do with the kids and teenagers to get them off the street, so I'll likely keep it up in the future and donate hardware to them whenever they can use it. They gave me a lot when I was a kid and it's the least I can do to give something in return.

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I make a monthly donation to a local charity organization.

This organization focuses on helping people pull themselves out of poverty, by mentoring, helping them build a budget, and finding ways for them to increase their incomes and lower their expenses. It's a charity organization that aims to make itself unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I just started supporting [The Skeptics' Guide to the Universe](https://www.patreon.com/SkepticsGuide/overview) with a monthly donation on Patreon.

The SGU's mission is to spread love of science and critical thinking – a thing we really need in a world that is increasingly full of fake and with a rising contempt for reality. So for me, this is about joining forces to make the world a better place, at a really high level.

They produce an awesome podcast! Take a listen. And I encourage you to support them as well if you agree with the mission.

---

I don't know if the above digital donation counts as "stuff"... Just to be on the safe side, I can say that we also just did a major clean-up of our house and gave away loads of cool toys to our neighbours who have younger kids than ours. Toys are stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Long time lurker here...

My office donates gifts for disadvantaged children to St. Vincent de Paul, a charity that fights the effects of poverty in Ireland. This year I chose two 10 year olds, a boy and a girl. The boy I got Lego, and for the girl a really well illustrated book about famous Irish women in history. These were probably the only gifts those children got this year, I hope they enjoy them.

Shoutout to StackOverflow for all the help through the years!

Answer (score 3):

I just recently relocated and changed a lot of my bad habits due to a new job and a new person I wanted to become connected with that.

One of the bad habits I had as the previous person I was, was that I had been sort of an compulsive hoarder. I fortunately already successfully overcame that habit within the last 3 months. One of the things I hoarded en mass, were my clothing. I always felt like "for some reason at some day it might fit again, so I have my clothing of almost the last 10 years hoarded in my old flat, which I have to empty out by first of April. I planed to just trash anything I won't have use for and just give away my clothes in an easy way. But this meta post made me reconsider it. I decided the time to get rid of my old clothing is not "sometime till April", but now when it is most useful for others. Also I will be more considered about what might be of use for others and what in fact is just trash, when the time has come for getting my flat empty.

My favorite stacks are, **Stackoverflow**, as that was the site that gave me a head start into my career; professional speaking and also I just found out through SO of the whole network. Then **Arqade** as.... well, I like gaming, and I am someone playing video games on a metagaming way, so I come every now and then up with questions, that not many gamers come up with, so not necessarily easy to find that in the internet, but there my questions get answered quick. And last but absolute not least, **Interpersonal Skills** as that site helped me so much in becoming who I am right now, and even the job I am in right now (which is awesome) I only applied, because on IPS someone adviced me applying at this company, as that company supports employees with conditions like I have, when I described my situation in one of my posts there.

Answer (score 3):

We took the opportunity to declutter and donated clothes and household items to local charities that provide for needy families and the homeless. Coats are a much needed item this time of year and we were able to donate several to our local 'Coats For Families' charity.

My favorite Stack sites are Seasoned Advice, The Workplace, Ask Different, and Music.

Answer (score 3):

I donated blood someone indeed ( one of my friends of friends ) . Helping people who troubling with small tech issues related to mobile or laptops are my main job over these years. so much friends and aged people trust me for that.

Last year, our state face a huge disaster as the form of flood. we use social media as well as physical help to someone indeed. proud to be a part of that rescue as much as I can.

i am mostly using stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Last month, I realized I had way too much stuff, so I packed up half my closet (including hats, gloves, formal and casual wear), and the majority of my dishes and food storage containers, and dropped them off at a thrift shop. This helps me out too, as my kitchen is now much better organized and convenient to use.

I'm mostly on StackOverflow and dabble in Music.

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of clothing that I don't wear anymore, so a few weeks ago I dropped off a box of clothes to a local charity so that someone else can use and enjoy them.

**Favorite website**: Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

Not long ago I donated to a foundation '[HulpHond](https://hulphond.nl/)' and participated in a nationwide event where dog owners were asked to bring their dog and join the 'Big Walk', to help raise awareness for this foundation.

This foundation aims to improve the lives of physically/mentally impaired people by using assistance dogs to support them.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a collaborate effort from multiple people, stretching over months** though i'd say my personal part in it relatively is small. I would still like to share what these amazing people do.

---

This year we learned that a colleague was planning to go to Belarus with two minivans and a couple of friends to deliver clothes, electronics and toys to families who live in often poor and bad circumstances.

They do this entirely non profit, in their own spare time. And not without danger.

to help these people out we and a couple of other families collected all our old clothes, toys, electronics and other essentials for those people and gave it to the people who were going there.

Despite not going there myself the photos and videos were heartwarming. One of these I will never forget. There was a young girl (probably around 14 years old) that had received a plush bunny. The happiness radiated off her as she walked around with it all day, showing it all the places around.

I truly hope they can manage to do this again next year, and am already saving up stuff to give next time around. Lets give more children their smile back, and cloth the people for the upcoming winters!

---

<sub>StackOverflow is my place to hang. And actually a mousepad short at work...</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I donated a couple of old winter coats to the New York Cares Coat Drive. Also we had a catering service at my office and I bagged some of the leftover bread and gave it to a couple of people who asked for help in the subway :)

Also moved recently and donated some appliances and pillows to a local Goodwill  near our old apartment

Answer (score 3):

We regularly give clothes, housewares and toys to our local St Clare Hospice. Our little boy is growing like a weed, so it is becoming a regular stop.

Answer (score 3):

This past holiday season my department adopted a family to purchase gifts for to make their holidays special.

If I recall, our department raised about $600 and was able to purchase everything from their list, including necessities and toys for the little ones.

I donated $20 to help the management team pick out items and helped carry items up to our floor so they could be wrapped up after everything was purchased. ( I would have helped wrap, but I'm **awful** at that stuff. )

I mostly use Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I recently helped an elderly couple who was downsizing pack up their whole house. Some of it they kept, but most of it was taken to a thrift store charity. Some of the furniture went directly to children coming from other countries as well.

In leiu of commenting on the other 93 (and counting) answers, I wanted to add how encouraging these all are to get out and do some good!

Answer (score 3):

Last year my family had to bid a sad farewell to our family pet of 13 years, our beloved schnauzer Casey.  It wasn't until we started getting all of our dog stuff together that we realized how much we had.  Instead of throwing it all away, we donated everything to the local dog rescue.  A full car load of beds, leashes, toys treats and food(cases and bags, since my wife shops in bulk for this).

Due to the emotional pain, I thought it would be a while before we got another dog.  However, through our continued interaction with the rescue folks, we met a loveable little puppy from the [Sato Project](https://www.thesatoproject.org/).  She had been shaved nearly bald due to the conditions of her fur and has a massive over-bite.  She wasn't getting much attention from adopting families but she grabbed our hearts.  We adopted her and are so happy to have her in our home (and start accumulating dog stuff again).

---

I quite often hit up Stack Overflow as a consumer and I am a contributor to Workplace

Answer (score 3):

I regularly donate blood to the American Red Cross (over 2 gallons so far), and a portion of each paycheck to my local church that supports mission trips to build homes Mexico and drilling for wells in Africa, among other things.

Last year I donated my time (four 12-hour/day weekends, and then some) to build a coffee bar/buffet for my kid's school auction. It turned out really good and the whole package brought in $1700 for their class! That was my first time trying something this big, and I'm so glad it turned out so well.

Here is a picture of the coffee bar I built (other families donated the items on it):
[image: Farmhouse style coffee bar]

<sup>I like a lot of the StackExchange sites, but I use StackOverflow the most. Woodworking and Home Improvement were helpful for the coffee bar. I also like reading the questions on aviation and cooking. I'd prefer something wearable (even an apron), but most everything else looks good, too. I definitely don't need a mug or mousepad, though.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I recently moved, which gave me an opportunity to find a lot of clothes and children's toys that I donated to the [Salvation Army](https://www.salvationarmyusa.org/usn/). As my kids outgrow things (or I simply realize I'm never going to wear something), it's nice to be able to give it to somewhere where it is more likely to be used.

My family also donated to a children's hospital in El Salvador, where some of my in-laws are from and have connections to.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I make small purchases, I always try to pay cache (5/10/20 dollar bills).  I save up the coins I get as change and give them to some good cause at the end of the year.

Although I prefer not disclosing the amount, I am always surprised how many coins pass through my hands in a year!  Last year I sponsored CoderDojo and Tim Hortons Children's Foundation, amongst others.

Answer (score 3):

I entered into a raffle for the Kentucky State Police Trooper Island program where they take underprivileged kids to a camp out on an island in Kentucky Lake and teach them all kinds of skills. https://kentuckystatepolice.org/trooperislandcorvette/

I have also donated some canned goods to local food drives.

Answer (score 3):

This Christmas my brother and I volunteered at [Crisis](https://www.crisis.org.uk/) with their *Crisis at Christmas* period. We spent Christmas day and the Sunday beforehand there. It is the first Christmas we spent without our parents (who are perfectly healthy but in another country) so we signed up to do something else worthwhile with some of our holiday period. My brother and I spent a lot of time cleaning (taking out trash, cleaning rooms, working up a sweat scrubbing pots and pans) and doing door duties (either guarding entrances to staff-only spaces or welcoming guests and signing them in). It was fulfilling and I'd like to make it a tradition, volunteering around if not on Christmas day.

This year I've also lost a lot of weight and gone down a size, so I have a large sack of oversized clothes I'm donating to Crisis as well.

Crisis is a UK charity with the mission of ending homelessness. During the Christmas holiday period most homeless shelters in the UK close down leaving many people on the streets without food or shelter. To counteract this, Crisis at Christmas is a two-week period in which Crisis provides locations where those who are homeless or in dire circumstances can come in for shelter, meals, company, games and movies, etc. They also organise for doctors, hair dressers, psysiotherapists, Alcoholics Anonymous, and other support sources to be available during the Christmas period. It is pretty awesome, and there's something like 200-300 volunteers each day at the center we volunteered at.

I like RPG.SE, GameDev.SE, and BoardGames.SE the most.

Answer (score 3):

This year, I bought a small stack of $5 gift cards to Subway, McDonald's, and other places where food can be obtained relatively cheaply, to keep in my car.  I hand them out in lieu of cash to people asking for food money on the street corners I pass by.

I also regularly keep bottles of water in my car to hand out similarly.

<sub>The main Stack I haunt is U&L, though I peruse vim, AskUbuntu, and some of the gaming (electric and tabletop) Stacks now and again.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I am currently in the process of building a website for a non-profit all on my own time. I Just recently donated money to a family in need that has two mortgages to help pay off their debt. Also Gifting a $100 Walmart Gift card to someone in need.

Answer (score 3):

On new years day while walking home I helped an elder woman in a broken wheelchair move her chair and possessions through a subway turnstile. It felt good to start the year on a positive note, definitely better than the hangover I was nursing.

I make small recurring donations to a few organizations that I support. I've been donating to Planed Parenthood for years. I also donate monthly to the Children's Miracle Network which started by me supporting a housemate with their Extra Life charity marathon. I also make a larger donation to NorthStar Self Directed Learning Center to support their goal of never refusing a teen because of an inability to pay fees. My time there as a teenager was integral to me becoming the person I am today. I'm glad that to be in a position where I can give something back to them.

Last year was far from the best, but I was fortunate to find myself with a stable job and few unexpected expenses. I'm adding the EFF, SPLC and ACLU to the list of organizations I donate to monthly.

Answer (score 3):

I, along with a colleague of mine, built a website for a local charity, that helps kids from less-insured families get christmas presents with what they **wish for**. The kids wishes and anonymized identifiers are put up on the web, and people from all over the country will then buy the gifts for the kids and take them to a collection point. 2018, the charity ran with >800 kids and everyone got a present!

Favorite site: Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

This feels a little weird, but here goes...

Good timing. Recently I've been going through my own personal stuff-a-way, cleaning out my <s>junk room</s> second bedroom. I've donated a desk, a chair, and a bunch of toys, picture frames, CDs, and clothes. I'm looking for a place to donate a bunch of comic books as well- any suggestions?

I also regularly donate to the [Processing Foundation](https://processingfoundation.org/). In their own words:

> Our mission is to promote software literacy within the visual arts, and visual literacy within technology-related fields — and to make these fields accessible to diverse communities. Our goal is to empower people of all interests and backgrounds to learn how to program and make creative work with code, especially those who might not otherwise have access to these tools and resources.
>
> We do this by developing and distributing a group of related software projects, which includes Processing (Java), p5.js (JavaScript), and Processing.py (Python), and facilitating partnerships and collaborations with allied organizations and individuals, to build a more diverse community around software and the arts.
>
> The Processing Foundation is specifically invested in expanding the communities of technology and the arts to include and support those who have not had equal access because of their race, gender, class, sexuality, and/or disability. We sponsor a Fellowship Program that funds exploratory, creative, and technical research; support an Advocacy Program, which focuses on nurturing diverse communities and their specific projects; produce public events that provide platforms for collaboration between our contributors; and take part in panels and talks that spread the word about the need for diversity in these fields.
>
> At our core is the philosophy and politics of FLOSS (Free, Libre, Open Source Software.) We see software as a medium, something that connects two things. We view it as a means for thinking and making. We believe it should be free. We believe that learning to program is not about acquiring a certain skillset, but is instead a creative and exploratory process. We believe software, and the tools to learn it, should be accessible to everyone. We believe software literacy and an understanding of media of all kinds is essential knowledge for today.

And [Donors Choose](https://www.donorschoose.org/), where you can donate to local (or non-local) classrooms. Teachers create a project (basically a request for materials or new tools for their classroom), and after a project is funded, Donors Choose purchases the items and ships them to the teacher.

Oh, and I donated a bunch of toys to [Toys for Tots](https://www.toysfortots.org/) a couple weeks ago. Full disclosure though, that was for an event at a bar, and I did get some free french fries in return.

**Edit:** If you're looking for an easy way to donate money, check out [Amazon Smile](https://smile.amazon.com). Just append `smile.` in front of any Amazon URL next time you're shopping, and Amazon will donate `0.5%` of your purchase price to a charity of your choice. It doesn't increase the cost for you at all. It's a small thing to do, but it adds up over time.

Answer (score 3):

I had just got back to my University city from a 4 hour car-bus-train-train-tram journey, and decided KFC was the best bet.

I walked past 2 homeless men on my way there, and was annoyed because I didn't have any cash on me.

I arrived at KFC, and a man was sitting next to an ATM, just outside KFC. I am about to get money out for the man, but change my mind, and instead offer him some KFC. He was incredibly grateful; more-so than the offer of a small amount of chicken would be to me!

I have a student discount at KFC, so I got a mini-fillet burger for free with my meal, and added on a snackbox for the homeless man. He was incredibly thankful as I popped back out to give it to him, and I was pleased that I'd made more of a difference to him than just giving him a bank note and walking on - there was much more of a connection.

---

Remember that many cities have a number you can phone for a charity social worker to check on a homeless person. This is one of the best things you can do; it's means the charity know who is where, and ideally they can provide a warm bed, especially for the cold winter months.

---

<sub>Stack Overflow branded goodies would be my preference, followed by either Meta Stack Exchange or Ask Ubuntu! Thank you for hosting this, it's a really good way to make a positive change in the world!</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a family that makes sure to include charity in daily acts of life, I pledged to donate a part of my income every month, having contributed financially to EFF, Wikipedia, Mozilla and OWS. When [Kerala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Kerala_floods) and [the North East](https://qz.com/india/1307939/floods-in-indias-assam-manipur-and-tripura-kill-25-displace-thousands/) were hit with the worst floods, I couldn't help but contribute with water purifiers, blankets (thanks to Amazon wishlist) and the relief fund.

I also tend to the street dogs(since I was 4!) and help them with food, meds, and preventing abusive actions against them.

Thanks to this Stuff A Way, I get a platform to receive any suggestions for charities globally (accepting electronic contributions). Or if you are pooling funds for a cause.

Warm hugs!

---

<sub>And my favourite SE sites are: StackOverflow, UX (as I work as a front-end dev), Travel and Aviation (for the joy of flying)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I've "adopted" a family most years for Christmas. I have a few rules for this:

- Be anonymous.
- Have the receiver be someone you don't know.
- Find someone who needs help.

That last one pretty much defines how I handle it - through my church. Sure, they may *say* they need help. But now I'm leaving it in the hands of God.

I have a monetary limit. US$500. (I'm not really wealthy.) I have a time limit also - if you need help in no-monetary ways (painting, cleaning, laundry) I'll give you may entire day (and use of my car within reason)... but only one day and during the holiday season.

This past year it was monetary. A single mother with two children (boy age 6 and girl age 3). My wife really enjoyed buying clothes and toys. We got something for the mother. We only knew one name - the mother's. We showed up with wrapped gifts on 22 December, introduced outselves by first name only (along with our church) and left less than 15 mites later knowing that we made three lives happier for the holidays.

Answer (score 3):

Our Church participates in a charity called Interfaith Hospitality Network. This is a network of churches that give homeless families a safe place to spend the night, food, counseling, and help finding a job. They need various things, usually food items and cleaning supplies, as well as the occasional overnight host to stay with the families when they are using our church. This Christmas my wife and I dropped off several bags of cleaning supplies to their office in Cincinnati.

Answer (score 3):

In preparation for our move into a new home, we've de-cluttered and donated a large amount of items including clothes and blankets to homeless shelters. We've also donated all kinds of children's clothing and toys.

We also have and continue to volunteer time at Feeding South Dakota, packaging food to be distributed to non-profits around the state of South Dakota.

My favorite SE site is Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I worked with a small group in my company to organize a donation drive for Hurricane Florence relief.

Florence wrecked many areas on the east-coast of the U.S.  The storm flooded many homes and businesses, causing a shortage of clean food, water, and loss of electricity.
[image: Picture of Hurricane Florence over the east coast of the United States]

---

My company was very lucky to be in a town that was not heavily affected, which gave us a great opportunity to provide support to neighboring areas that *were* hit.  The below picture are the donations from one of our three buildings that participated in the relief effort.
[image: Donations to Hurricane Florence Relief]

Answer (score 3):

In early December, my wife and I donated about 10 bags worth of clothes that we have accumulated and rarely wear to the [Purple Heart Foundation](https://purpleheartfoundation.org/).  I, myself a veteran, come from a long line of veterans, so helping out fellow vets is something very important to me.

We also donated a couch to [Habitat For Humanity](https://www.habitat.org/restores).  Hopefully our donations brought someone joy this Holiday Season!

My favorite sites are Puzzling and Stack Overflow (specifically the C# tag).

Answer (score 3):

After recently moving apartments to one with less closet space, my girlfriend and I decided to donate old clothes. So between us we filled about three cardboard boxes with shirts, t-shirts, pants, etc. and also about three or four pairs of shoes. We have already donated many of these clothes.
Now for 2019, my resolution is that every time I buy or receive new clothes, I'll separate at least one old item of clothing to donate to charity.

Aside from that, we have a system for sending money to other people (similar to PayPal) called PicPay, which sometimes offers a bit of cash back on payments made through their platform (5 or 10% of the money you sent). Instead of just transferring this bit of extra funds to my bank account, I've decided to always donate it to charity institutions, like the Red Cross, which has an account there.

Last year, my girlfriend sent a message suggesting people who were about to get her Christmas presents instead donate some money to Brazil's [WWF](https://www.wwf.org.br), who have many wildlife preservation projects here. I was the first donor, and even sent WWF a bug report with a problem with one of their payment methods.

My favorite site is definitely StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

A few days ago an earthquake of magnitude 5.3 [occurred](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us2000izyd) ([local news report](http://news.cctv.com/m/a/index.shtml?id=ARTI80y1Dh8hvpvAdWgAvTSp190104)) near Yibin, Sichuan Province. I am busy preparing for my finals these days and can't do much, so I saught out the student organization of donation and dedication and donated 100 CNY to their funds from my savings, in response to their regular activity after these natural disasters' happening (mostly high-magnitude earthquakes - particularly frequent in some parts of China).

It's not really what I'm good at, but I feel honored doing so. I hope some day developing/maintaining software could be a sort of "dedication" (that's what I'm good at :P).

I love Android Enthusiasts, Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange the most.

Answer (score 3):

I gave some rare reference books to a student who wanted to have them for her studying purposes. She picked it from my library and was very happy when she found them as there are no these books in bookstores anymore.

[This](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) site is my favourite :)

Answer (score 3):

I give routinely to charities and non-profits (such as United Way, Wikipedia and GovTrack, among others). But I recently realized that I had a very hard hearted attitude toward anyone who approached me on the street. I would usually say no to any request, and sometimes I'd be unconsciously rude about it too.

One day, after witnessing such an interaction, my wife challenged me about it. I was defensive at first, but the more I thought about it the more I convicted I felt. I think this story, [told by Walter Hooper](https://www.ncronline.org/news/media/cs-lewis-couldnt-touch-anything-without-illuminating-it) about an experience he had with C.S. Lewis, was a major breakthrough for me:

> On the way to an Inklings meeting, he gave some money to a street beggar, and I made the usual objection: "Won't he just spend it on drink?" Lewis answered, "Yes, but if I kept it, so would I."

So I made the decision to take people at their word, and to be charitable toward anyone that asked so long as I had the means. And to ensure I had the means (since, as is common among my age group, I rarely carry cash), I made a point to add a budget line for charitable giving.

Since then, I've had some wonderful encounters.

A few days before Thanksgiving a woman approached me on the street on my way back from lunch and told me that she was between jobs and didn't have enough money to make Thanksgiving dinner for her kids. Since I still had plenty of budget left, we were able to walk to the nearest grocery store and I told her to get whatever she needed. I learned her name and a bit of history about her family, which gave me a new appreciation for folks in her life situation.

Another time a guy was asking for some money from a couple that was clearly ignoring him (like I used to do). So I approached him and asked if he needed help. He told me he was recently divorced and now homeless. He was living at the local shelter, but they require a small payment after the first week. He said he had already started a job but was getting paid in arrears, and he didn't have enough cash to pay the small fee. Because I had a budget, I knew that I had enough to set him up for a couple weeks at the shelter. So I drove him to the bank (so I could withdraw the cash) and we talked. Once again I had a new window into the struggles that some people go through and how we are all just a few bad days away from the same situation.

I've gotten to know some names and faces and histories from my local community in ways that I wouldn't have otherwise. I've learned a lot about how badly things can go and also how helpful just a little generosity can be. I've also become less hard and cynical about the needs around me, and more OK with being a "sucker" because, for every time I get "taken", there have been other times where I think I helped someone who really, genuinely seemed to need the help.

Comment: My father instructed me much the same: "imagine how hard-up you would have to be to swallow your pride and ask a complete stranger for *anything*, even just a dollar. Then hand over whatever's in your pocket while you silently thank Providence you've had it easier."

Answer (score 3):

I spent a weekend this past December volunteering at a community hospice down the road. I spent a bit of time doing busy work/chores, but the lionshare of the weekend was spent with hospice patients. Many of them did not have family come by and visit, so it was nice to be able to provide them with some company. I played a *lot* of card games. :)

My favorites are Stack Overflow and Worldbuilding. :)

Answer (score 3):

As a teacher for years, I gave free courses when I could afford it, as sharing knowledge and education are soooo important.

Beside giving food/coffee/money to people who need it, I also give clothes to a charity, and buy food for another. But hey! It's unfortunately so common. Many many people do that. I was looking for something different. And the mother of one of my students, coming to my office to pay for some courses, saw something, asked, and gave me a wonderful idea!

Now, I need these pens!!! Lots of them :)

I often receive, as gift, from suppliers, pens and notebooks. Use some, lots of spare ones. I put them as decoration in the office. She saw them and ask for them. She's part of a charity that helps children who can't afford to buy stuff to go to school. And twice a year, she goes to Madagascar island and give all the pens and books to the kids.

How come that I never had that idea by myself?... Never mind...

**NOW**, SO, you open those drawers, pack what's inside, and give me these spare pens of yours :)))

Thanks to you, lady ;)

Answer (score 3):

Each holiday season my wife and I enjoy purchasing gifts for needy families in our community. The past few years we have begun involving our twin daughters in the selection of gifts and it has been awesome to watch them become more involved every year. This year in addition to those families in our immediate community we purchased requested items from a giving tree benefiting an orphanage in Africa.

I feel a bit strange typing this up as we are generally pretty quiet about our philanthropic endeavors, but I love Stack Overflow swag (my Arqade and Stack Overflow shirts are some of my favorite geek ts) so figured I'd put it out there.

My favorite Stack Exchange sites are: Stack Overflow, Arqade and Seasoned Advice.

Answer (score 3):

I had donated some amount for a charity. They make sure poor kids don't stay hunger. The amount I donated will help one kid stay healthy and eat nutritional food that serves up to one year.

I had also donated to someone unknown who was need of some money who was in a typical condition in hospital after a road accident, this I saw through a Facebook post.

I wish many others who can donate also do their best to help someone in need.

I like all stack exchange sites, but out of interest I browse through https://aviation.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

On the streets of India, it is not an uncommon site to see children begging. I see such children of all ages almost every day when commuting or biking.

It always saddens me to see these kids of the same age as me and my siblings on the street, when they could be learning or playing.

As a student myself, there's not much that I can do, but I volunteer at after-school teaching programs whenever I can - and we stay back after school to teach less privileged children.

Today evening while going out biking, I'm going to go purchase as much candy and chocolate that I can with my saved up pocket money, and go distribute it to the kids who can inevitably under the nearby overpass. It's not much, but at least it'll bring a smile to a few faces.

I'll update in a few hours.

Comment: Update: The deed has been done :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Empowering children with a gift of knowledge

I am a voracious reader and ardent technology enthusiast. That way I ended up accumulating loads and loads of books and tech gadgetry.

During my visit home this Diwali, I could't help but notice the pile of books and magazines that I have created over the years. There were some unused but working computers and laptops too, those that folks like us, living on the cutting edge tend to call *obsolete*.

Most of the books have been really useful in gaining knowledge during my formative years, in the age of limited Web access and lack of content. The content in the books is really useful, but in the day and age of digital access, carrying books is not relevant to most of us folks. I am way past collecting books and carrying them when everything is available on a smartphone within seconds.

That got me thinking, what's the best way to give the stuff away to someone who will really appreciate it, and can make use of it. Simply throwing away in trash or selling it off will serve the purpose of freeing up clutter, but didn't feel like the right thing to do.

That got me thinking and led me on a hunt to explore places which could best utilise the stuff. Charitable schools, orphanage and shelter homes for needy were the places I visited. Finally, I ended up donating the collection of books and the computers to a couple schools which lacked even the basic facilities like a library or computer labs.

Upon learning that those schools also lacked funds to set up even the so called basic resources, I felt inclined to utilise whatever free time I had. A couple computers, a laptop and a Kindle kept stacked in the almirah for years with no one using it? Let's wipe the dust, set it up, take it to school and take some time to introduce computers to children who weren't fortunate enough to use one in the day and age of smartphones!

It was a really humbling feeling to share the *unused* stuff with someone who will feel enthused just to *see* it. I had the best time of my life spending time teaching kids to draw and type on a computer.

The smile and excitement on the faces was my best holiday gift ever for me!

There's a kid's magazine called [Tell Me Why](https://subscribe.manoramaonline.com/subscription/subscriptions/manorama-product-details-magazines.subscription.TY.html) that I have read for years.

Published once a month with very high quality content on a specific subject. I had a big pile of the said magazine and loved reading them in my childhood. I donated my entire collection to a school which didn't even have a library, effectively setting up a mini-one for the children :)

I am mostly active on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema) with occasional visits to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6995250/nimesh-neema).

Answer (score 3):

Some boxes of items we don't use anymore donated to The Kent in Kitchener. It is run by the Mennonite Central Committee which uses funds raised to provide relief work, refugee resettlement, and people in poverty.  A Stackoverflow network user here.

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I regularly collect items to donate to Goodwill (and have a bag of items right now that is ready to be dropped by).  We also contribute monetarily to the Atlanta Community Food Bank to help them feed the hungry around Atlanta.

We also keep a couple bags of items in our car to give out to those asking for things which contains some food, pads, water, etc.  Great way to be able to help out.

I'm most active on Stack Overflow, but also like Ask Different, Server Fault, Unix and Linux, and Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

I give an annual donation to the [Björn Steiger Stiftung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rn-Steiger-Stiftung) ([English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rn_Steiger_Foundation)) in order to help making defibrillators more accessible in Germany. They work with donations only despite playing such an important role in helping people quickly.

Unfortunately most of them are in public buildings which do not always have open and are apart several hundred meters usually so if you or someone else have an issue, this important help is often too far away to be effective which is one of the many problems the foundation tries to work against.

Other projects of the foundation include:

- Reanimation training in schools
- A special built baby ambulance for premature infants
- SOS-telephones on German streets

I am mostly connected to Stack Overflow (work and chat) and Aviation.SE (hobby) :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Feed the homeless, help the little ones.

This morning, as we do on the first Saturday of every month, our men's group at church prepared and served breakfast for the people at the homeless shelter downtown; usually about 200-250 breakfast tacos, coffee, bottled water, and donated fresh fruit.  (We are part of a rotation of local churches who do that on the weekends).  Each November I roast a turkey at home and deliver it to the dinner at the shelter on the week before Thanksgiving.

This past August we went out to a local facility that takes in children who have no parents (ages infant to mid- teen) and keeps them safe and secure until the foster parent system gets them a place or a relative can legally become their legal guardian.  How each one got there is a sad story ...
The children were all in the west wing for the day, and we stripped, cleaned, and waxed the floors in the east wing (the living quarters).   (A few weeks later, another church men's group did the other side ...)

This was in addition to the picnics we put on for the kids in the spring and fall: we buy and cook the food, get the bouncy ball rides, shaved ice vendors, and so on.  Different faces each time, but the need never changes.   I am glad this shelter is there, but I do wish there wasn't a need for it.

---

Most active on Aviation, Christianity, History, RPG, SF&F SEs.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of receiving goodies from `Stack` was so thrilling that I like to participate too. :) (Although maybe it is better to do such things without telling everyone, but I love to get these Stack gifts).

A week ago, I gave some clothes to a charity that I knew for four years. I usually gave stuffs that I don't need to them to gave them to people that refer to them.

Also I know a person via a close friend. This person has no permanent job and he have to work daily to have an income to support his and his wife expense. Sometimes when he came short in supplying their needs, or an unfortunate situation like sickness occurs, he asks my friend for help and my friends tries to raise some money from his friends for him. As my friend is so close to me, he always tell me and I try to help an amount that I can.

And I think it is better to do something new as a result of participating in this announcement. So I commit myself to check my closet and give some warm clothes to someone in need in this week.

Answer (score 3):

This is so awesome! thank you all for doing this! :D

My participation was to donate to an organization that supports immigrants children especially for medical needs, the cool thing was that my company matches our donations!

Answer (score 3):

I try every year to donate directly to already existing scholarships at my graduate school alma mater.

My undergraduate thirty-year reunion was last year so I donated to my old department and the "club" that I enjoyed the most: the handbell choir!

With 2 young kids, I seem to always be sorting through their clothes for too-small or not-worn items. These go to our local assistance league. Last week I expanded my hunt and cleaned out my "good clothes" closet--from which I haven't worn anything for probably 10 years. The results (several bags worth) will hopefully provide people with some work clothes.

For general charities, my go-to has been Medicine Without Borders although I try to donate to friends' charities via FB.

I am very glad to be in a position that makes donations possible and easy.

My favorite sites are [Travel.se], [Expatriates.se], [scifi.se], and [gis.se] although I also lurk on Academia, Workplace, Personal Finance, and Law.

Comment: And my box of swag arrived yesterday! I had asked, if possible, if I could get two gaming or arcade t-shirts for my 2 kids...sure enough, the shirts were in there! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My spouse and I were inspired by this post to go through our old clothes today and ended up making two trips to Goodwill drop off locations. We even threw in shoes and jackets too! Coincidentally, my brother and his wife, who are expecting their first child in May, visited our house today in the middle of our donation vibe and we sent them home with bags full of breastfeeding supplies and maternity clothes.

As an active StackOverflow member, a holiday donation that really resonated was donating a little-used Chromebook to a single mother who can't afford a new laptop and now uses it as their everyday computer primarily for night classes.

Incredibly inspiring to read through all these stories, makes me proud to be a member of the SE community :)

Answer (score 3):

For me I prefer the simple ways of helping which is donating my old and replaced items to goodwill or other charity organizations.

Old/replaced cloths off to a goodwill. Old electronic devices off to goodwill. Old furniture, appliances and other house hold items off to goodwill. To me this is a great thing that can help people in need and also reduce waste as these items can still have plenty of good life left in them.

Another fun way to help out  is when possible to purhcase items from services that will also donate to a charity. Examples of this are humble bundle for different items or amazon smile which can donate a small amount from every purchase.

Answer (score 3):

I, along with other members of my church, donated things like soap, toothbrushes, socks, shampoo, and toilet paper to our local homeless shelter.

---

I like Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange (if it counts), Puzzling, and Stack Apps

Answer (score 3):

I've got a box with a handful of new remote-controlled toys on its way to Make-A-Wish this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

I've just booked in an appointment to give blood about this time tomorrow. Assuming all goes well, I'll give 470mL of whole blood, which will be used to help people with serious medical conditions or injuries, maybe even help save a life. It's been a little while since I last gave blood, so this was a good reminder that I'm overdue. I'll update once I've made the donation.

My favourite site on this network is the TeX stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

What a coincidence!

A couple of days ago I cleaned and packed up a lot of clothes that I don't need anymore. I thought I'd rather donate all that to someone who needs it.

Then, I saw this post on SE! Wow! Yesterday, I donated the clothes to the German Red Cross organization which surely can forward the donations to all people who are really in need.

Nice idea, SE! Hats off to you!

(BTW, I'm primarily active on StackOverflow, if you ask.)

Answer (score 3):

I am a Sri Lankan resident, where the education is free of charge, even for your first degree. (Which is why I am here today, if there wasn't anything called free education, I will not be a Software Engineer today).

Even though we have free education, I've faced many difficulties during my studies. We have to buy stationeries and school uniforms which some people do not have enough purchasing power find it hard to do. Me, and my mother (She's a single mother) went through really tough times. But today, I earn much better.

Hence I am helping some children in need around my resident area, who find it hard to buy new books and cloths for the school, in the new year.

I have bought books and cloth packs for 5 kids, whose parents do not have funds to do so.

My team in the office this time replaced our ***Annual Secret Santa*** program, to help out some children in an orphanage too. We bought cloths, food, and stationeries for them, and we are currently planning a day out with them, with some music and fun items.

I contribute to `StackOverflow` primarily. I am also a user of `IoT beta`.

Answer (score 3):

I just gave a big garbage bag of all my old clothes to the homeless people that live near me. These people stay alive from begging and selling marijuana in Johannesburg. It's an extreme life and many don't make it for very long. Clothes are things that are always needed especially with all the rain and for when Winter returns. The guys are very humble and are always happy to receive some donated items. I have been doing this kind of thing in the same community of homeless people since I was at school.

Answer (score 3):

I generally try to avoid having too much *stuff** so I don't have much to give away. Not spending too much on physical *stuff* leaves me with more numerical *stuff* (i.e. on my bank account) which I can share.

So I just donated a few hundred bucks each to two local charities: a homeless shelter (focusing on homeless alcoholics aka the "not so cool" homeless people, which tend to be the ignored among the ignored) and a children's hospice.

<sub>* Because I know I don't need most of the existing *stuff*. The offered reward *stuff* is actually useful, though. Except for, I guess, hats.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This was the perfect excuse to get spring cleaning out of the way early this year! I have so many clothing items I never wear... Donated 2 garbage bags of clothes along with some hats and gloves (Minnesota is a cold place). And although it's not money or "stuff", we regularly volunteer time at our local animal shelter.

It's wonderful to see all the stories here. Shout out to all those giving blood; I wish I could do that without passing out :)

Answer (score 3):

Long term SO user and SE lover in general! (For recent feedback on some controversy, What I love the most is the Hot Questions list ^^).

Every year, around this dates I usually donate some amoutn of money to the Tech companies I consider they do the best work for our online/tech world. Wikimedia Foundation is a no brainer every year, and this year Mozilla and EFF won my 10€ each. Just because Firefox, Rust and Online Rights are rightly indispensable, and great efforts to secure and improve our lives online.

BUT, as I did not know if this would count towards this, I inmediatly gone to our nearest food bank and gave several rice packs to them. It happened that I met some way-old classmate working there, so, double win!

Keep up with the good work! SE, this site deserves the same respect as Wikimedia!

For the lulz, I would really fancy somehting from ServerFault, or SO in general! But whatever you had at hand would be awesome!

Happy 2019 everyone.

Answer (score 3):

With nearly 200 answers as I write this, I think the SE community can be very proud of it's achievements!

For my own contribution:

For the past 18 months, I've been volunteering at our local heritage railway, which is entirely run by volunteers. This has entailed leaning a number of skills that would otherwise be dying out as technology evolves, but which are important to preserve for posterity, while also helping to educate future generations about our industrial heritage and 19th-20th century history - and it provides a good balance to my day job in R&D.

Answer (score 3):

I donate 20 euro to the UNO every month to help on their refugee program.

My favorite SE site is stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

My few neighbors and me, collect our old woolen clothes. Every one of us spread words to our close friends as well so that we can have as many clothes as possible. We start doing it from the middle of December because actually unbearable winters start from new year in Delhi. By the end of December, we segregate clothes according to gender and Age. We distribute these clothes outside railway stations, slum areas, Temples, Gurudwara, Masjids, Metro stations (Tube/Subway) on the first weekend of the new year. We've been doing it from past three years now. I Would like this opportunity to share nice initiative happening in a couple of cities in India. Maybe, someone else can start it their own city/country. Some of city/locality resident mark one wall in their area as "[Neki ki deewar](https://www.google.com/search?q=neki%20ki%20deewar&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFm5nY6dvfAhVWU30KHayBBkAQ_AUIDigB)" which literally means "wall of goodness". People put stuff which is not in use, there. A person who needs something, can walk up to that wall and get whatever they need.

I primarily use stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

In India you'll find beggars near temples, mosque, traffic signal, market, bus station, railway station etc. I have always believed that no one should pay a penny to them but I find it really difficult to do so every time so I hold my self strong to ignore them and let them pass by. One day, a friend of mine gave away 20 INR to one beggar, I asked him whether he know where his money will be spent, may be that beggar will get some drug or spend on alcohol, he looked at me and said, "I don't know but I know that he was hungry!". I was surprised how he can be so sure, so we decided to follow that beggar and make sure he don't spend that money on something unethical or illegal stuff, to my surprise that beggar bought a large cup of tea and 2 packets of biscuit. I thought why we ignore the needy because of those who cheat, may be number of people who really need help are very less compared to those who pretend to be in need for money if I talk about India.

From that day, I decided to save small amount of money from my salary for those who are hungry and can't earn money to get food. However, I don't donate it to any NGO or charitable trust because I can't completely trust them. Whenever, any beggar ask me for money I counter him by saying *"Do you need money for food?"* If he says *"Yes"*, I simply buy him some food packets or order something for him in restaurant near by. Trust me, most of them refuses to have food, instead they insist to give them money. Also, I don't only limit it to human, but feed many street animals whenever I feel they need food.

Not sure whether this is really an act of kindness but I strongly find it a part of my moral duties as a human being. That's it!

My favorite site is [`stackoverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I donated two working monitors to the school in which I completed my secondary education. Also as I am an Engineering student I had notes of various subjects of my own, so I provide my notes of every semester to the needy students. I also designed a website for making easy the process of blood donation for the people living in my locality.

Favorite Sites: Stackoverflow, Quora.

Answer (score 3):

I operate an ad hoc chapter of The Burrito Project in San Antonio. We try to once a month get together and roll about 500 warm rice and bean burritos and then hit the streets by bicycle handing them out to those who are hungry and living on the streets. No proselyting, no politics, just people helping people. We held our last roll 'n' ride on Saturday.

Also around this time of year, my family and I take our old coats downtown, and zip them up around telephone poles with a tag saying free to take. We did that about two weeks ago.

Favorite sites: StackOverflow and CodeReview

Comment: This is a pretty awesome idea! Thanks for sharing :o)

Answer (score 3):

So I've donated to two main charities:

1) St Leonards Hospice who raise money for those with life threatening illnesses. Have donated toys, books and lots of clothing there (partly to clear out space!).

2) I also managed to salvage a whole load of stationary & equipment (including a very large and heavy laser printer... not fun to shift!) to donate to the local Foodbank in my city as they've just moved to a new office.

*I primarily use StackOverflow*

Answer (score 3):

Since I was 10, I was doing volunteer work for spreading positiveness & spirituality every week for couple of hours, where we get together & talk about our great history, share food, tell stories of great characters etc.

Since last few year, as I started doing job, I regularly give away my clothes, shoes etc. to local community store so that it can help the one who need it.

Also whenever I see someone who earns money by performing on the street, I generously give money to them. (I promise, it's worth giving)

My Favourite site is "Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 3):

Where I live there is a strong social expectation that those who don't get drafted into the army for whatever reason spend a year or two volunteering. I just finished my year of volunteer work doing tech support at a small local school that didn't really have anything in place prior to this. I rebuilt their website, taught a computer usage class, set them up to use the modern digital standardized testing system instead of paper where possible, and in general did tech support for whatever wasn't working to the best of my ability.
For "extra credit" i also paid weekly visits to an elderly gentleman who lives alone, and sat and talked (and helped with his computer). Even having officially finished i still visit him, including today.

<sub>My favorite sites are Stack Overflow and Mi Yodeya.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Italy, this is a really great initiative from the community! Glad to be a part of this with some little contributions.

I have made donations to some organizations, listed below.

- [Unicef](https://donazioni.unicef.it/) - For poor children.
- [Associazione Nazionale City Angels Italia](https://www.cityangels.it/) - Which helps homeless people.
- [The Ocean Clean Up](https://www.theoceancleanup.com/) - To help cleaning up plastic in the oceans.

I'd really like to thank you again for the initiative. It gave me that little push to start giving something back!

Thank you!

Mainly I'm active on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Sweat donation ahoy!

My family has a tradition of volunteering to help our local Food Bank. We don't donate ourselves, but we organize, deliver flyers, and collect and sort food so all the Food Bank has to do is pick it up and deliver it to the people who need it. We've been helping with this for about 8 years in a row now.

We had a big weekend event where we managed to collect 500,000 lbs of food in a single day (not all my family, it was a province-wide event) by delivering flyers to peoples doors and picking up any donated food the following day. Needless to say, it's great to give time for a good cause, and even better when you hit ginormous numbers like that.

Answer (score 3):

Time is something I have plenty of so I work with what I know, writing software for charities which are normally taken for a ride by vendors.

http://www.deafchildren.org.nz is the latest work for a deaf children in New Zealand. All work and hosting is done without charge.

Answer (score 3):

I donated a new scarf, new pair of socks, and bags of like new clothes to a local shelter.

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I support a local non-profit that provides single parents, low-income families, and pregnant mothers with resources needed for healthy pregnancies and caring for newborns. This includes educational material, counseling, and physical resources. We went through a bunch of our kids' baby clothes and donated a box of clothing items to the organization.

Answer (score 3):

We do our usual end of year donation and angel cycle. The things that we do as a family:

1. Go through all of our books, and any that we no longer read actively (Especially the kids books), we donate to a local lending library for homeless.
2. Go through closets, and any clothing or other items that we no longer wear are collected and donated.
3. Christmas Angel - Salvation Army - As a family, we go and we pick out 1 card tag for each of the kids, and one as a family, and purchase the gifts requested on the tags. If our coworkers participate, we also get tags to match the dollar amount that they donate, and purchase those gifts as well. This year was 5 tags.
4. As part of our martial arts school, we participate in various clothing drives and once a quarter "Feed my starving children" food packing events.

Answer (score 3):

This year I made a (university matched) donation equal to one week's salary to the United Way of Milwaukee and Waukesha County (WI). (Why not, when your employer essentially doubles your donation!)

But more rewarding was helping the United Way assemble and deliver "care packages" to accompany holiday gifts for women in domestic abuse shelters, for homeless men and women, and for disaster victims.  The care packages are part of "The Shoe box Project", in which boxes are designated for male, female, or "either". They include everything from toothpaste and a toothbrush and dental floss, soap, lotion, shavers, tissues, 2 washcloths, shaving lotion, body wash, shampoo, a comb and a brush, deodorant, postage stamps, stationary, envelops, and much much more.

It was a great opportunity for me to feel grateful for what I do have, and a reminder that we may easily take for granted some of the basic necessities for hygiene and communication with others.

Favorite site: math.se

---

where's the promised swag???

Comment: @MonicaCellio Almost three months later (almost three months since your comment above, to an answer I posted 2 months preceding your comment I), I have yet to receive the "promised swag."  So, I'm guessing that for some reason or another, I've been deemed ineligible for it? (It would be good to know why, in that case.)  It's not a huge deal for me, but I thought the idea and spirit of the OP was great, and the idea coincided with "an act of kindness" I had already undertaken.  If SE has run out of swag to give, it would be great to be sent a message indicating as much.  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have better information than you do.  (I don't work for SE.)  I suggest contacting SE to ask about it (there's a contact link in the page footer).  I suspect it's a missing shipment or the like, not disqualification.  Good luck.

Comment: You were sent an email with a link to a form to collect your address, @Namaste, on January 30th — you never filled that form, and that's why you didn't get anything! You're in the same boat [this other user was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324589/208518), so please refer to the answer there for more information and context :)

Comment: Thanks, @JNat.  I edited the post with "where's the promised swag"; I wish I knew then that I missed out on the initial email.  But I get it: there were a **lot** of users answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is universal everywhere, but here in the UK many supermarkets have food bank collection bins. We'll often get a few extra items while shopping to put in the collection, especially at this time of year.

Certainly not anything out of the ordinary, many people do this - but hey, every little helps.

Answer (score 3):

My family and I in New Zealand we donate things that we need and use to Red Cross and Salvation Army. Then we buy stuff from there to help them. 
I have been planning next year on christmas to get homeless people to go to my home let them shower, eat a Christmas meal with us and pray.
All The best

Answer (score 3):

I love your approach!

Today, I gave a couch, ottoman, bench and coffee table to Salvation Army. We've got a new couch on the way and figured someone else could use our stuff, which is still in good shape.

If you would like to send me stuff I can use with your logo on it, I'd appreciate a coffee mug, flashlight or pen. I'm most active in sharepoint.stackexchage.com, so if you have stuff with that logo, that would be a bonus.

If you'd like to send me stuff I can give away at a user group I help organize, you can send most anything. They tend to like t-shirts and hoodies.

Answer (score 3):

I donated (mainly food) to [Brisbane Youth Service](http://brisyouth.org/), an agency that support homeless and disadvantaged young people (12-25 years) and their children. I invite those who live in Brissy to do the same if they haven't already.

Answer (score 3):

I was already planning to do this when I came across this post -- which is awesome by the way! -- so now in honor of this post I:

- Donated clothing items.
- Donated house items I had extra of.
- $ contribution to those in need in my community.

I'm primarily active on Stake Overflow; it's definitely my favorite site in the network! You can view my profile if you want to see other sites I accidentally built reputation on, it's a hodgepodge for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think its a good idea to encourage others to help those in need.
While, its a saying in India that "If you donate from your right hand, your left hand shouldn't know about it". But, I prefer to inspire. :)

People out here are truly charitable and it inspires me to do more. 
I wish to share these accounts for probably first time in my life.

To start with,

There is this one story that I am truly proud of in my own way. 
My first donation was at the age when I cudn't count. It was Diwali. On seeing a lady begging for alms near our home, I took 1000 bucks (They were a big deal before 20 years) from my father's wallet and gave it to her saying, "Its Diwali, buy new stuff for yourself." My parents while appreciating my gesture also scolded me for taking money without my father's permission. But, the scolding didnt affect me at all. I proudly said that noone should be sad during a festival.

Since then, our parents make my sister and I donate clothes every year. And blankets in winter. 
My husband too, took me to an old age home on my birthday. It was highly satisfying to see a smile on the faces of old people and seek their shower of blessings. 
Trust me, everyone should go there once.
However, I dont have the courage to go to an orphanage yet. The mere thought of young children without parents just brings extreme sadness in me. My parents send our books over there.

I don't donate money anymore as people might use them in bad ways. So, I keep a bag of biscuits with me and whenever I see someone needy, I give them the food. And in summer, I try to buy icecreams for children. The smile on their face is truly satisfying.

My husband and I have decided that one day, we will take responsibility of fully educating atleast one child once we are capable enough to do so. Our search has begun.

I would point out that extending our hand to animals is also necessary. In our society, we try to treat hurt animals and send them to vet if the need be.
I have this crows' scar on my head bcz the crows mother hit me with its beak as it thought I was harming the little crow who fell from the tree and couldnt fly back.

Don't know if this counts, but yesterday, it was freezing cold here.At a nearby place, a maid was cleaning utensils with cold water. My sister and I got the hot water arranged for her. She was happy. And so were we.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty cool event - love the idea!

This weekend I sorted out books I no longer need, ranging anywhere from children's books from my childhood to novels or tech books. I donated the children books to our local hopsital and the novels and other books to the retirement home in our city.

Everyone was so happy with their new books and I was happy to have more space in my book shelf - just like StackExchange does it now!

Answer (score 3):

I along with my college friends teach kids from the slum area! The slum is near our college and we go there and teach them alphabets and numbers. We also donate them clothes and books. We also conduct a campus tour for them!

In the end, their smiles make our day.

With this kind of exposure, these underprivileged will surely be motivated to do something good. This can help them discover their potential to cause a lasting change in society and make an impact. There is also a positive change in attitudes and views in the slum society.

I enjoy answering questions on StackOverflow (also it is my favourite site along with Github :P)

Answer (score 3):

> It would have been a shame if someone hadn't shared the idea of
>   purchasing handbags or small pouches, filling them with hygienic
>   supplies and a pretty universal gift card, and just handing them to
>   people on the street that you encounter in need of some help. Because
>   I'm taking that idea too. It's fine to not want stuff, and I very
>   specifically said that all too often charity is more for the benefit
>   of the giver than (the) recipient, but don't you have some words that might
>   help people think and give creatively or efficiently? That's all we
>   want ;) - [Tim Post ♦  (13 hours ago)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/321906#comment1053530_321906)

Absolutely. It's wonderful reading the answers on this thread! At first, I was a bit embarrassed to participate in this giveaway contest. My charitable contributions, as far as "people" are concerned, are just regular stuff like occasionally giving some money to the panhandlers, which I think almost everyone does. Apart from that, I'm a student with a limited monthly allowance and don't really have much to give out in the way of charity. However, some of the answers from the students and the teenagers, on this very thread, have inspired me and given me some excellent ideas, just as Tim says. It seems that being a student is no excuse for not being able to be charitable and help the society out, in our own little ways. Devoting one's time and patience to those who need it, doesn't require money!

I'll share my story. It's not about "people" as in "humans", so I don't know if it counts, but I'm giving it a shot since [@Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell) encouraged. In Indian university campuses, it's pretty common to spot [street dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_dog) and unfortunately, it's also pretty common to see the canteen owners kicking them out whenever they go nearby. Since the past year, it's been a habit of mine to buy an extra plate for the dogs whenever I buy food from the college canteen, during recess time. Mostly it's chicken-cheese sandwiches or rice with curry or egg-chicken rolls. Sometimes it's burgers or pasta. Luckily, our canteen food is available at government-subsidized rates for university students and it's reasonably cheap for me.

There's a small field nearby where I go and have to wait for a bit. 4-5 dogs "magically" sense the smell and gather there within a few minutes. They do indeed have a very sharp perception of smell...but I guess it's more because the dogs roam nearby that field during the daytime! I like to stand and eat there with them. Initially, I used to feel a bit *uneasy* about others staring at me when I gave the dogs food but gradually got over it. Seeing me, even some of my classmates started sharing a part of their lunch with the dogs!

The dogs seem to be more or less healthy these days, which is a good sign.  Anyway, this was just a tiny bit from my side. I hope this answer motivates at least a few people to take care of the street animals a *little* bit more. That's all.

<sup>My top 3 favorite sites on the Stack Exchange network are [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/), and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for helping animals too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm monthly supporting a godchild in africa via the german kindernothilfe. They help financing her education and support her for example in growing their own crops.

Apart from that, I monthly donate to unicef to support education for children around the world. I'm hoping at least that improved education will have a long lasting effect improving their current situation and perspectives.

PS: Favourite SE site is Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

Not much, but here it is.

On 30th December while coming back from dinner, I heard my Uber driver get into an argument over phone. Apparently some guy left his mobile in the cab and wanted it back immediately. He lived around 30km away and wanted the driver to drop everything and return back the mobile. The driver told him he has to drive all night and he can have his mobile back next morning. At this point the other guy threatened to involve police and started calling him names.

I usually don't talk during the rides but that day we had a nice chat. I paid him 2x for the ride and thanked him for doing the right thing even when the other guy was being a dick.

Answer (score 3):

This winter, I went to visit my aunt, before the Christmas holidays (I know I'm a Muslim from Pakistan, but we do get one holiday for Christmas). I had known that she was going through some rough times as her husband's filed for divorce and she had to leave her husband's house with all of her children. So I planned on giving her some money (not much but whatever I could afford). She happily accepted and gave it to her son who then complained that it's still not enough for a new jacket.

That's when I realized that he did not have a jacket IN THE WINTER SEASON. Right there, at that moment, I thought, well I can afford a new jacket anyway, let's give him mine. I asked him if he liked the jacket I was wearing and I gave it to him.

It wasn't anything expensive or *posh*, but it was good enough to keep him warm. And this weekend I also bought my aunt and her daughters, new dresses as well.

*I mainly contribute to AskUbuntu.*

Answer (score 3):

I made donation of 100 INR, via my college, which sent students to give the needed things, to help Kerala flood affected people.

---

I am studying Masters in Mathematics. I like others to know Math Overflow, History of Science and Math, and Math Stack Exchange sites. I prefer Math Overflow over others.

Answer (score 3):

My wife and I have been especially blessed this past year and she encouraged me to join her in donating a few thousand dollars to a humanitarian organization that we support. Our donation went specifically to helping get [food parcels to Syrian refugees](https://christianaidministries.org/program/food-parcels-for-syrian-refugees/) that are in need. I hope SE has a great new year and am super grateful for **StackOverflow** and the folks that make it happen! I couldn't do my job without it!

Answer (score 3):

My wife works in a middle school affected by 2018's Merrimack Valley gas explosions. This meant that many students at that school were forced out of their homes. The co-workers at my office got together to donate needed supplies for these students: everything from toiletries for families living without hot water to shower, to extra holiday presents to student's who might not otherwise get one, to grocery store gift cards to help families returning to their homes after being evacuated for months.

I'm a big fan of Stackoverflow and Arqade

Answer (score 3):

This year, I gave to support:

- [Ministry of Hope](http://www.ministryofhopewnc.org), a chaplaincy group helping women in the Swannanoa Correctional Center for Women, after hearing the stories of women in the prison system;
- [Community of Living Traditions at Stonypoint](https://stonypointcenter.org/multifaith-community), a multifaith community in NY, after hearing Eboo Patel speak to the importance of interfaith community;
- [Montreat Conference Center](https://montreat.org), who graciously hosted us.

It is my hope that they will put their funds to good use to fulfill needs that I cannot dream of.

---

This spring, I will also fulfill my commitment as Service Coordinator for a campus club, where I will organize and participate in events to serve and relate in our local community. I hope to place a particular emphasis on prison ministry and our dining services employees.

---

P.S. Thank you, SE/SO, for inspiring people to come together in thoughtful ways.

P.P.S. My favorite sites are vi/vim and rpg, though honestly I love the content across the network.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a New Year's Resolution not to pass a person in need without helping. (Actually it was more of a winter resolution, since I started it in November, simply because 'no time like the present, amirite') I've had to start going to the bank more often for small bills, since I sometimes pass several people a day.

I know it's not flashy or huge, and I know some people would say that it doesn't help them in the long term, but I've come to believe that *each person knows their own needs best* and I should extend a tiny bit of faith in the human race and treat homeless people like the adults they are and just give cash that they can use for medicine/hotel room/phone charger/hearing aid battery/shampoo/whatever they actually value and need right now, rather than hand them another fast food meal or something like that.

My favorite stacks are Stack Overflow, Interpersonal Skills, Pets, Parenting, and English Language & Usage

Answer (score 2):

This is an amazing idea!  I have donated my baby supplies to goodwill (car seats, swings,high chair)  I also signed up at charitychallenges.org and donated to them.  They work with veterans groups such as green beret foundation and team RBW.  As far as what sites I like I am a huge Apple fanboy!!!  I also enjoy stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

We haven't spent any money on fireworks for ~15 years - the most we buy for new years eve are sparklers for the kids. Instead we donate a similar amount - this years donation went towards wikipedia (me) and Brot für die Welt (wife).

---

My company has a "take for free" cleanup where they give employes a free choice of outdated chairs and desks (before disposing them). They are all worn down and got replaced with new stuff. When I heard about it we secured some of those for the lokal youth center where my wife works. They got free (worn) chairs and descs and replaced even worse ones they kept because no money for replacing them was alloted the last years.

---

When traveling to work, I pass the train station where I live. There are always begging homeless around. I never give money - when asked for it I instead (mostly in winter) get a third and fourth bagel and extra coffee and donate that to the one that asks for it. There is a train-mission (a non profit) inside the train station where they get coffee and warm up without needing to pay, but some rather beg for money.

Answer (score 2):

This year donated lot of lightly used baby clothes to local thrift store and started recurring donations to St. Jude’s childrens hospital.
Gave extra donation as a holiday gift last month along with a greeting card.

Ofcourse the charity that is dearest to me is https://www.sos-childrensvillages.org/child-sponsorship-form 
Doubled my contribution this year to celebrate an important personal event.

I use stackoverflow, data science, ask ubuntu, unix and linux, personal finance and money most.

Answer (score 2):

I will be donating about 4 large garbage bags of clothes to Goodwill, as my kids continue to grow like weeds.  (Who gave them permission to grow?)

I also have 4 bikes I will be donating to good will (those meddling kids again!), as well as two grills, and a large fire grate this Spring, to finally reclaim a parking spot in my garage.

Favorites are Board Games, Arqade, and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that a local charity runs an annual event where the community comes together to raise money for Cancer research. Having some skills with iOS development, I have been developing an iOS app for their event later this year that will allow those who attend the event to donate money online, find out more about the event, and hopefully encourage them to attend.

It all started when I got into communication with the team behind the event, and they were extremely grateful for my offer to volunteer to develop an app for them. I'm halfway through the process now, and it's coming together.

I will be attending the 2-day event to look after the app as well as pitch into the amazing cause they're raising money for. These people are truly remarkable and their dedication to the event and the cause is mind-blowing. It warms my heart to know that I'm helping them out with my own skills. There is truly no better feeling than dedicating your time for others.

I'm a reasonably new member to the Stack Exchange, but my favourite networks are Stack Overflow and Super User.

Answer (score 2):

Each year my wife and I help serving breakfast to the homeless around Easter as part of a community service offered by a local charitable organization. It's always humbling to dedicate time to serve others in need.

We also hoard our grocery store loyalty points throughout the calendar year, until Christmas time when we shop for food supplies that are desperately needed by local food bank.

Being beekeepers, we're fortunate enough to have buckets of liquid gold... they make sweet surprise gifts as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

We started cleaning out the house between Thanksgiving and New Year's Day, and here's what we did with the things we found:

- Usable clothes and shoes that we didn't like or didn't wear anymore were donated to the Red Cross. While most other places accepting used clothes will ship them to Africa, our local Red Cross branch has a free shop for people in need, where they can pick up clothes and shoes without paying - really useful in Winter. We donated a total of 10+ bags.
- Old and unused furniture was given away for free on eBay Classifieds. We made sure that people in need got these. Instead of throwing stuff away, someone else can still get a use out of an old table, chair or shelf.

We continue to go through the house and uncover more stuff to give away or donate. It feels good to give back...

As for the SE sites: I'm mostly on SO and on Ask Different - both are fantastic resources.

Answer (score 2):

I donated some unused networking supplies to my church today.  We're running a new TV display, and network cable is much easier to run than an HDMI cord the same distance.  It's not a charity as such, but it will help those in the back see our presentations that much better.

Answer (score 2):

I am in 9th Grade (or Form 3, as we say it in Malaysia), and I have some extra sets of uniforms (I bought new ones as the old ones are too small). I donated them to the Consulting Department in my school, and they will give it out to people who can't afford to buy uniforms. :)

Update 1: Ah, and I wrote a blog post [here](https://veehz.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/a-little-act-of-kindness/) to spread kindness!

Favourite Site: Math StackExchange

Answer (score 2):

I have recently done 3 acts of kindness:

1. Gave a student my old laptop.
2. Gave out $2 bills to homeless people.
3. This morning I donated to an open source project that I have been using for years. The first time I have ever donated to a software project!

<sub>Academia.SE and SO are my favorite sites.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post I have done a post-holiday clear out of old clothes, all of which have gone to a local homeless charity. Coats, gloves, shirts, shoes all now off to a better home :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have certainly been letting my Stack Exchange freak flag fly this season but I might as well throw my hat into the ring again, if not just as an excuse to promote some great causes.

Aside from clothing donations to Goodwill, most of my good works have been as a result of my 8 year old being a [Girl Scout](https://www.gssef.org/) and my wife the co-leader of her troop. In late November we spent an afternoon team packaging 800-900 meals with the [Big Heart Bridage](https://bigheartbrigade.com) which cooked, packed, and distributed 50,000 meals for the needy leading up to Thanksgiving. In 2017 I spent that time tearing down 4 or 5 full, roasted turkeys to bite-sized bits, by hand. It's definitely an experience: absolutely destroying turkey under tents with music pumping and encouragement being shouted at you!

On December 1st we spent a brisk morning cleaning up the beach with [Friends of Jupiter Beach](https://friendsofjupiterbeach.org/beach-cleanups/). People do a fairly good job of keeping our beaches clean, but it is amazing what you find - this time the standout was hundreds of little circular pieces of confetti near where some kind of  celebration had occurred the previous night.

This last one is just an excuse to fit one last good link in. At the end of Girl Scout cookie season my daughter and her troop will donate 1/3 of their cut of sales to [Loggerhead Marine Life Center](https://marinelife.org/) which nurses ill and wounded sea turtles back to health (amidst other public outreach).

Roll on 2019!

My favorite site is Stack Oveflooooooow. <3

Answer (score 2):

I've recently moved from Brazil to Germany due to a job I found here. As extra baggage is too expensive, I could take only two suitcases with me. Therefore, I took all my extra clothes (winter and summer clothes) and donated it to my local church, that helps homeless people. It was about 4 large bags. Felt really good, for I had never donated so much at once.

Favorite website: StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

My family and I regularly donate to the clothing ministry run by our church. We also help out during the donation day where people can come get close for the year, along with canned goods.

Answer (score 2):

I'd love some swag :)

I'm a huge fan of thrift stores. So, in those phases when I realize that I have way too much *stuff*, that's where I head. I'm back at my parents house for several months where most of my *stuff* is stored. So, this Christmas I bagged up some usable toys, books and shoes and brought them over to a local charity store. I'll definitely be doing some more loads over the next couple months.

---

My favorite SE sites are: Stack Overflow & Software Engineering. I would really appreciate getting at least 1 sticker :).

Answer (score 2):

Every year I buy a few cases of feminine care products and take them to my local womens' shelter.

Comment: That's a bit creepy

Comment: @CodyBugstein Donating condoms to a childrens's shelter is creepy (kinda). Helping to make sure women have the products they need to feel comfortable as they get back on their feet and/or recover from domestic abuse is definitely not.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that qualifies as an answer, but I remember it like it happened yesterday!

A couple of years ago I was leaving San Francisco for Athens, and was shocked by the vast amount of homeless people. Long story short, I gathered some extra clothes of mine, and gave it all away to a homeless guy in Bryant and 3rd str.

But he was sleeping, so I just left them aside him, and rushed to the airport.

And I remember, after a couple of blocks, a man who my brain photographed in a non-ephemeral fashion, riding his bicycle, holding everything I had given the homeless person!

And I stoped and looked at him, as he was rapidly passing by, and he had such a cold, casual-everyday look, like nothing has happened, like he didn't (wasn't) even care! His look froze me, and by the time my brain shouted at me to do something, that guy was already gone - and with suitcases and stuff, there was no chance in catching up . . .

The Epimythion: On an act of helping the others, make sure you that you complete the task! Or you might find yourself trapped in an eternal question of whether you could have done better...

Lesson learned and last year I made sure that I jumped all the bureaucratic hurdles to actively help in the oil spill in Hellas!

Answer (score 2):

Excellent way to unload old swag and benefit needy persons. Well done, Stack Exchange!

For me, I have a very nice Adidas heavy coat that I've had for a decade. It has spent almost all of that decade hung up in the closet. I tried wearing it recently and my wife commented that I look like a kid. Well, I'm approaching "grumpy balding dad" these days, so it's not really my style anymore.

It has no damage or stains at all and I'd say is still stylish. There's an orphanage near my house that I donate things and money to on occasion. I was going to take this over there anyway, but I wouldn't mind an SE loot box for myself.

I would prefer branded swag for the following sites, in the following order:

1. [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/11643/)
2. [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/4276/) (only if you have branded material, which probably doesn't exist)
3. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934286/)
4. [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/458/) (Not there much, but love the branding)
5. [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/26460/) (same as above)
6. [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/2185849/)

If you don't have those brands anymore, meh. Pay it forward to someone else. A mug would go well with that "grump balding dad" motif I'm going for these days ;)

Answer (score 2):

I seem to collect friends who are artists, disabled, and/or down on their luck, so I generally give them my slightly outdated electronics, like iPhones, iPads, laptops, even networking gear. This Christmas one of them complained that her building's WiFi had been out for 2 months, so I gave her a WiFi router.

I spend most of my time on StackOverflow, but I like Ask Different best.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare recently started onboarding people to their domain registrar in waves, and if you wanted to get access sooner you could donate to Girls Who Code - an organization helping to close the gender gap in technology -, so that's exactly what I did.

Despite getting access sooner, none of the domains I currently own were eligible for transfer. To me the greatest thing about this service is that it was a driving force encouraging me to contribute to a better cause.

> [image]

My favourite SE site is Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This year we did the usual: Round-up the kids' toys that are in good condition (some even unopened!) and get them along with their latest batch of outgrown clothes to Goodwill before December so they can be in the hands of less fortunate kids by the Holidays.

Unusual this year: A friend mentioned that a local church's orchestra was in need of violinists.  I'd never been to that church, and I hadn't really played my violin in many years, but I was classically trained.  So I gave myself a tune-up, showed up for orchestra rehearsals, and was actually surprised at how much that little orchestra means to people.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect timing! I have some clothing and things that may be donated soon, but I actually made a charity donation recently! In the lead up to the Christmas holiday, I made my first donation to the Detroit Water Project.

I hope to see future campaigns like this! I always like getting swag from things like the cheese/hat competitions, but using it to incentivize donation is even better!

I am primarily a regular of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

A great idea!

As every year I donated clothes that I don't want any more. I also donated a little bit money directly to a few particular charities and organizations that I think should be supported more.

*Edit: My favorite site is Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 2):

I like to help out where I can, and last year I had a few opportunities to do so.

I recently reorganized my room, including my closet and noticed I had a lot of clothes that I never wear, either because they no longer fit, or I didn't wear that style anymore. So I collected all the clothes I didn't want anymore (about 4 trash bags full) and gave them to my neighbor who is a pastor at a nearby church to donate to those who needed them.

One of my friend's father recently passed away from a brain tumor, and was in the hospital for quite some time. He was the primary source of income for their family prior to becoming ill, so a friend of the family setup a GoFundMe to help them with medical and living expenses and I donated what I could afford to spare to help out.

I also try and give a small donation to the college I went to every year to help fund scholarships as I know from personal experience, receiving a scholarship can be the one thing that allows you to afford to go in the first place.

---

<sub>PS: I mainly participate on Arqade, and a mouse pad would be cool :)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

My wife and I made a habbit a while back to donate to charity around 50€ every month. We picked a new one each month to try to reach out to various subjects. We even asked friends and familly to donate to charity (acting in domains around childcare and pregnancy in general) instead of gifting us excess stuff for our newborn last year[¹](https://yael.mettinger.fr).

But the habbit went from every month to every month or two; to sometimes. So, even though we sent a month worth of meal vouchers to a national food bank in december, I made sure to pick a charity again this month.

Reading a lot of other answerers donating their blood, platelets and bone marrow, I also registered as potential bone marrow donor (will need a medical exam before being on the official list) and will plan to give my blood in the next days.

---

<sub>Greetings from a CodeReview regular</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't going to post, as I have plenty of swag, but I have been persuaded that I should. I can always give new swag away :-)

Each year I typically choose one or two charities to help out, and over the last 18 years they have been children's charities (as I have a few kids)

For a long time I'd raise money through marathons, running for [NSPCC](https://www.nspcc.org.uk/) or [CHAS](https://www.chas.org.uk/), and posting times ranging from moderately slow, a bit under 4 hours, to very slow: my worst two were done with injuries and were a 6 hour Paris marathon and a 5 hour 30 minute Edinburgh marathon.

With the bands I have had over the years I have played charity gigs - again, mostly for children's charities. One that stands out from many years ago was a 3 hour epic playing all the cover versions we knew.

In the UK we have annual events for Children In Need and [Sport Relief](https://www.sportrelief.com/), and my favourite fund raiser was a mile climb, along with a stuntman friend of mine, at Europe's biggest indoor climbing centre. To get to a mile we had to climb the tallest pitch there (a 6C) 65 times. Was fun by the end of it...

In the security industry in the UK we have the [WhiteHat Rally](http://info.whitehatrally.org/p/home.html) - a fairly competitive car rally, that has taken in routes such as London to Monaco, Brighton to Blackpool and various others, with the aim being to solve puzzles, navigate and carry out tasks to raise the most money as a team for [Barnardo's](http://www.barnardos.org.uk/challengeevents/uk_challenges/uk_challenges_detail.htm?ref=86129). And the two years I took part, the team I was on raised the most!

And along with my family, we raise money for a local children's cancer support charity, [Jak's Den](http://www.teamjak.org.uk/jaks-den/).

Along with another couple of Security Stack Exchange folks I have run BSides Scotland, an annual security conference in Scotland as a charity, helping educate the local community, and this year I am running a kid's track to help teach them safety online, hacking, understanding security, lockpicking and career planning.

I'm mostly active on Security, Parenting, Music, Outdoors and Motor Vehicles... as you could probably guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

As part of a school project, me and my friends volunteered at a school for children with physical and learning disabilities.

It's not exactly donating money or items, but the children we worked with were facing difficulties and we were able to brighten up their day a little bit and put a smile on their face

---

As for favorite site, I am a programmer so I spend most of my time on StackOverflow, even if I'm new to this network.

Answer (score 2):

I've always been helping one in need ever since I've started earning a bit more than needs of my family.

Though extending our used to the one in need has always been a good act - I usually avoid giving it directly to one in need, I instead give it to NGO's who refurbish them and make something good out of it for the needy. I believe in giving new stuff only as the one in need also have craving for it - used items all must have been donating to them.

I try to extend my help mainly to areas where I've myself struggled / craved getting same in my childhood, like paying semester fees for someone in need, giving textbooks, buying new clothes for orphans, buying fancy toys (remote controlled car - I always craved for it in my childhood but was not fortunate enough to play with it), I am not directly associated with any NGO but I extend these helps via our company's CSR activity every year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not generally one for giving to charity a lot, maybe once or twice a year depending on how much stuff I've amounted recently but other than that I don't do much. I do, however, buy clothes and what not from local charities that do things in our local area for people in need. This year I was also able to give large donations to a few because I've just (literally just: 20<sup>th</sup> December) moved home and so had a lot of stuff I had pre packed to send off to charity. I managed to give away a lot of clothes to people that need them, games to some children less well off than I was and some furniture we no longer had place to, to a local charity that gives out furniture to those who can't buy it themselves.

---

<sub>For swag I'd generally prefer SciFi.SE stuff as that is the only site I really frequent often (waaaaay too often if you ask some people) but other than that Gaming.SE, PPCG.SE and M&TV.SE would be cool too.</sub>

Comment: I _used_ to do a lot of volunteering working with younger children, mainly with sports such as coaching football and what not and volunteering marshalling at events and the like but I haven't been able to do that for a while so I left it out of my post.

Answer (score 1):

In Israel, small beverage containers (cans and little bottles) are worth money if collected and brought to a store (equal to approximately 8 US cents). I tried to collect the containers that I use and bring them to stores for a refund. But quite frankly, the amount is not enough and I just forgot about it, causing my car to be filled with beverage containers.
Instead, what I do now is I still collect them, but instead of trying to remember to give it back at a supermarket, I leave them next to trash cans where I know that people search and collect those cans and bottles. I always leave them next to the trash can and not inside so that they wouldn't have to rummage through trash to get 8 cents. If I see someone collecting cans, I would approach them and give them whatever I have collected by now.
I fill that in this way everyone wins, the people who need it get the small amount of money, which is significant for them. I get to make sure that the cans get to be recycled.

We also try to "get rid" of unneeded stuff in a responsible way, donating old clothes, books and toys. There was a project in my alma mater that took computer parts and created computers for underprivileged kids, but they stopped taking parts and now only take full computers. So if anyone knows of a place that will take old computer parts in Israel, I would gladly donate them.

Answer (score 1):

In figuring out how to donate, I discovered that my work has a benefit that doubles my donation to any non profit!

I was able to find the EIN's (tax codes) for several local charities punch them in to my works donation page and 'double' my money in donating to them, now I feel twice as good for donating!

Answer (score 1):

I donated 2 bags of clothing to the Salvation Army last year and I gave away a box of Domino's Pizza that was left over from a meetup to two homeless people at a local subway station. They were so happy to receive an entire box of pizza that would have otherwise been thrown out. They literally said, "Seriously?" and they thought there was more to it but I told them no problem and went about my way back home.

I also donated to a little girl that needed surgery while I was at the Dominican Republican.

Besides that I organize a book club and try to get copies of books if my book club members can't afford to purchase the book.

My favorite Stack Exchanges sites are StackOverflow and Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

I gave my student solutions manual for Calculus 1 & 2 to the Tutoring and Learning Center at my local community college. They probably would have been helpful when I inevitably forgot how to do something, but I think the students taking those classes need them more.

Last semester I started volunteering as a tutor at said Learning Center, and I am very grateful for the opportunities this has given me for helping out the students. It's truly wonderful when you see a student finally understand something they've been having trouble with.

Although I agree with some of the other people who have said that you shouldn't volunteer or give things to charity because you want a reward, I also think that's not really what this is about. I think the purpose of this is to get people started with helping other people, and maybe they'll realize they want to continue doing so. I think the purpose of this challenge is similar to that of banquets to recognize firefighters and police officers (although on a much smaller scale). We always want to recognize people who do good in the community. Also, who doesn't want SE swag!

My favorite Stack Exchange site is Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I get gifts from family. Unfortunately, they are rarely useful to me. So every year I donate them to the Jefferson County Pet Food Pantry Thrift Shop (trying saying that 3 times fast). Anyway, they have a thrift store and the money is used to buy pet food to help the low income and elderly keep their pets at home and off the streets and out of shelters. They also spay/neuter and will provide limited vet bill help. So every year right after Xmas I drop a car load off. Deb is kind enough to let me know what it brings in so I can calculate it as I fed 30 dogs, 10 cats and spayed 4 of each with my donation.

Answer (score 1):

I love being able to help this night happen (at this point monetarily).  I'm also considering volunteering my time to help there as well.  It's a great event for people that are easily ignored most of the time.  http://centralpanighttoshine.com/

the Main Stack Overflow is the site I enjoy and contribute the most. Second would be Arqade.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do some "Winter cleaning" after watching the Marie Kondo show on Netflix and me and my hubby donated some clothes to an organization called Grassroots Givers, they give away (*NOT SELL*) clothes, books, shoes etc. to homeless people entering shelters and transitional housing in my area. I made a conscious effort to find an organization that actually helps these people because while Goodwill is nice, they make money off of donations, and I'm not such a big fan of that.

Additionally, earlier this year after moving to an apartment I donated a table and chairs set that were not needed to Habitat for Humanity furniture store, where they sell some furniture and give some away to people who receive new homes from the organization. All the money goes to Habitat for Humanity.

I'm new to Stack Exchange, and I enjoy spending time on Interpersonal Skills and reading questions on Geographic Information Systems and Seasoned Advice.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm part of a paramilitary program called the US Naval Sea Cadet Corps., which in a nutshell, is a mini-Navy without the combat. Over my winter break, I took 9 days to train 28 (27 after one got kicked out.) how to march, among many other things, as well as supervise them over the 9 days. I got 4 hours of sleep a day on average, and went as hard with the recruits as myself. I also worked with the adult staff to make sure everything was in order for them to graduate and look good in from of their parents. for confirmation, I'll give you a thing to post in the search bar of Facebook for the group: "USNSCC TC NBK WINTER RT 2018" I hope you all have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow user here! Just donated some bags of rice and macaroni to a food drive at my local boardgame store!

Answer (score 1):

SE reminded me before answering that I might improve on previous answers. I can't. It looks like people did some incredible stuff here.

We gave away 4 dining room chairs to a local Goodwill-type place. We just figured someone else could use them more than we could because it's 4 more than the size of our family.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly donate my old cloths to people living in the streets. I also donate blood every year.

---

Stackoverflow: spend most of the time there.

Answer (score 1):

Now this is the kind of thing that gets me excited about SE :) Not the free swag part, although that's cool, but seeing positivity and goodwill.

I've been volunteering at 2 ferret shelters in the Chicago area for over a year, once a week, an hour's drive each way. On top of that I have my own 9 ferrets to take care of. My recent adoptions have all been sick or unwanted ferrets (who had been at the shelter for over a year). It's a ton of work and heartbreak (I had 12, lost 3 in October, still not over it), and I've basically stopped traveling or having a social life.

The 2nd shelter is much smaller and basically run by one amazing woman and her regular helper. Her helper has had the flu so she's been by herself lately so I've made sure to visit twice in the last week to help her out.

And I recently donated to the Prairie Wildlife Research organization which is dedicated to the preservation of prairie wildlife species, especially the endangered black-footed ferret. I made a $500 donation which was matched by my company, and then 3x matched by a federal grant! Felt pretty amazing to see them hit their $18k goal and I helped with almost a quarter of it! Unless that was a pre-grant goal in which case I merely helped with 1/18th :p

My favorite sites are Sci Fi / Fantasy and Worldbuilding

Answer (score 1):

I explained to my kids that many children don't get presents on Christmas because they don't have a home and so Santa cannot find them; and that it would be great if we took all those toys that we didn't use anymore and gave them to those children so they could have presents too.
So we as a family spent a whole evening sorting through old toys, throwing away the broken ones and putting the rest in a huge box that I later took to our local Red Cross. My kids were thrilled to find old toys that they thought lost, but still understood that other children would make better use of them. Proud parent!

We also did the usual giving to local charities. On holidays they have stands inside most supermarkets, so you just have to buy some additional items and give them to the people in the stand before walking out. However instead of lentils or rice, which is what most people give, we donated some infant formula because we know what it is to have a baby not adapt to breastfeeding. It's not much but it's honest work!

Answer (score 1):

In my daily commute, I have to walk quite a bit. During these walks I don't like to use main streets, as they are crowded with people rushing to work.

In these back alleys there are some nice, covered areas where quite often homeless people lay to rest, mostly sheltered from rain and wind.

When I have any cash money on me, and see these people, I tend to give them all of it, which ranges from a few euros, to several tens of. As I personally don't tend to use cash money either way.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started volunteering my free time via the Royal Statistics Society to a help a couple of charitable causes with some of their data analysis - it's a good opportunity to help out smaller charities that don't necessarily have the statistical or analytical capability to deal with their data.

Shameless promotion - if there are any other statisticians/data scientists/data analysts who want to help out:

http://www.rss.org.uk/RSS/Get_involved/Statisticians_for_Society/RSS/Get_involved/Statisticians_for_Society.aspx?hkey=c7977c58-1558-495a-9e5a-e99d64ea9cfd

I'm also a charity runner, running 10K's, half and full marathons for donations.

I primarily use stack overflow (but I also love PPCG (code golf) and depend on cross validated quite a lot).

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor thing, but before Christmas I donated some gently used toys to Goodwill, and some gently used clothes to our church. Though you've reminded me that I need to get some things together for their monthly pantry requests.

Answer (score 1):

We work with the Eagle Academy in Lone Tree, Colorado. This is a high school that caters to homeless/neglected kids. The school provides meals for the kids Monday-Fridays, but often these kids go hungry over the weekends. Our organization donates food and assembles 70 food packets a week for students on to take home on the weekends so they have something to eat.  This is a great program as we have involved the local Scout troop to help with donations and assembling the packets. (We assembled 70 of them last night for distribution this weekend.) It helps the kids at Eagle Academy and lets the boy in the troop see how they can help kids their own age who aren't as fortunate as they are.

Favorite Stack Exchange sites:

Stack Overflow

Physics Stake Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Like a lot companies, we do Secret Santa in our office. This year we also did a Xmas bake off, which a lot of people participated in. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on who you are) we did it on a Friday so at the end of the day we still had A LOT of cakes, flapjacks, brownies etc. left over. Instead of leaving them over the weekend and having to probably get rid of a lot of them due to the going stale, we took all of the leftovers down to the local [Salvation Army](https://www.salvationarmy.org.uk/).

We also took round a bunch of presents to the same Salvation Army place earlier in the week (for people who didn't want to do secret santa), so they weren't expecting to see us again that week! Needless to say they were very thankful.

<sub>I primarily contribute to good ol' Stackoverflow.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Starting from last year, I have a new tradition with my family.

In Mexico, we have this tradition called "Wizard Kings Day" (Día de Reyes / Día de los Reyes Magos). It's always on January 5th to January 6th. In Mexico, we don't believe in Santa Claus but we do believe in the Wizard Kings. They are the ones that give presents to kids while they're sleeping... but, what's with homeless kids? They can't feel that "magic", and so, my family and I have started this new tradition to go outside on January 5th and do the following:

- Give the kids a brand new toy that doesn't require batteries
- Give a bag with food to their parents
- Give them all a sandwich and a bottle of water (2L)

Why did we start last year? Because it's when I got a better salary and so, my end-year bonus was higher, and it allowed me to use it to buy those things above mentioned.

This year we made happier to 30 kids and their families allowing them to eat something fresh, nutritive and a warm hug at least for one day.

I will teach this to my kids when I have them

<sub>I primarily contribute to Stack Overflow but I do read a lot of questions in Japanese Language, Game Development and Apple StackExchange</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Hospital patients are often accompanied by family members who stay with them for many hours. While the hospitals provide their patients with food, they obviously can't provide food for those accompanying them.

Therefore, there is an organization in which **volunteers prepare nice warm meals and freeze them**, and those meals are distributed to the various hospitals, warmed up, and offered **to the family members or friends or caregivers accompanying the patients**.

Our family donates 4 meals a month to that cause. Each meal we make has chicken and 2 side dishes. Yesterday was pickup day, so that's the donation relevant to this question.

---

My favorite sites are StackOverflow, WPSE and Mi Yodea. I'd appreciate any combination of the following: flashlight(s), apron, mouse pad, stickers :)

Answer (score 1):

My place of work do a bake off this time of year where 20+ people bake different sweet an savoury snacks which are then available to purchase for the rest of the 130+ workforce. This year I made coffee, chocolate and caramel cupcakes, which went down a treat, and in total, we raised over £500 for a local children's charity.

We also regularly do other fundraisers, with the office donating large amounts of food/toiletries/cosmetics/office supplies to local charities and schools.

I am part of the web development team, and as such, spend a lot of my time on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

I regularly donate old clothes.