# More than 15k bottles of Viagra from Kenya, asking 110+ people for money, seriously?

Tags: support, spam, email, privacy

I received a strange mail from a well-known SE *user* with the following body two days ago:

> HALLO EVERYONE. I am writing to you from Kenya. I have recently come into contact with a great bunches of Viagras -- roughly 15,395.5 bottles worths! That's FIFTEEN THREE NINE FIVE and a half bottles. They're stuck in the customs. These Viagras have a NET VALUE of 15,395,500. I need to wire you the money, so you can wire the money to Customs. Then Customs will the money back to me and release the bottles. My agent PRINCE DAGAFOGU will then pick up the bottles and sell them. For your help you will be granted $752,495.41. Can you help me? We have only until 6 hours!
>
> Sincerely thank you.
>
> *(a blank image)*
>
> King Tutencut Dagafogu

The key point is that the email had **110+** CC recipients. Among them, I can recognize quite a few high-profile users, including ♦ moderators and many more.

I received this mail from an address that was not intended to be public, so I am wondering how this mail came to my inbox, and why there are so many CC recipients. Also, is it spam or something legitimate (it looks quite spammy)?

Comment: Also we all know *real* scammers put '$' at the end of numbers. *These Viagras have a NET VALUE of 15,395,500$*

Comment: **Related:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379804/560648 (another recent data breach)

Comment: [User who did it admitted it publicly](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1702?m=9548030#9548030).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Your link doesn't seem to point to the right place, or I'm missing some crucial context.

Comment: @tripleee It most definitely is the right link. The same user also posted a deleted answer here. Also, pair the text *A few minutes later, he apologized for this mistake, promising to send everyone a dollar if this would lead to spam.* in Glorfindel's answer here with the text in the comment *There was an explicit settlement offer made to send out money if anyone was spammed at that I* [sic] *address. [...] I was glad to do the dirty work and oblige.*

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**That's on me, and I'm really sorry about this!** As Glorfindel explained, I accidentally CC'd everyone entitled to a watch [from this contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910/208518), instead of BCC'ing... :\  One of the recipients then sent the message you quoted to everybody.

Right before that email you mention, you *should* have one from me, apologizing for this mistake and making everyone aware of it — I properly BCC'd everyone on that one!

We're looking at what systems we can use for similar situations in the future, so as to avoid emails like these having to be sent manually from our personal inboxes, which is much more prone to errors like these happening.

Also, the most ironic bit is that I was *about* to send everyone the email directly from Google Forms' builtin function to do so, but decided against it last minute because I wasn't sure the addresses would be BCC'd, and from GMail I could make sure that was the case... :|

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1311/discussion-on-answer-by-jnat-more-than-15k-bottles-of-viagra-from-kenya-asking).

Comment: If any of those users are EU citizens (which you should know from their postal address), GDPR requires you to have notified the relevant authorities of this breach within 72 hours. Did you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, @OrangeDog: our legal team reviewed what occurred and determined that the circumstances do not require reporting because no sensitive information was disclosed. Only a very small group of user email addresses were seen by other users and we notified those users. We have processes to ensure this does not occur again, such as using a delay on email sends to ensure BCC is used in the future.

Comment: The transparency and acceptance of accountability here is in welcome and marked contrast to most of the recent interactions SE (the company) has had with the community. I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: This is so funny, xD I love the juxtaposition of serious annoyance and King Tutencut Dagafogu's "HALLO EVERYONE"! (It's the accent, I think) xD

Answer (score 58):

It turns out a Stack Exchange employee accidentally sent an e-mail, related to [this contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910/295232), without putting the 110+ recipients in the BCC as required by data protection regulations. Therefore, all recipients could see each other's email addresses. A few minutes later, he apologized for this mistake, promising to send everyone a dollar if this would lead to spam.

One of the recipients thought it was funny to write up a spam message and send it to all other recipients (including me, that's how I know of it). This isn't really my type of humour, but I get where it's coming from. Please just ignore and move on.

Comment: I also replied (singularly, not in bulk) to the people replying in jokes on the thread for them to stop contacting me. Which they respected.

Comment: Did everyone get a dollar?

Comment: @user474678 A year and a half later and no dollar received for me. :(