# Stack Exchange Security vs. Online Forums

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users, security, hacked

How secure is Stack Exchange compared to online forums such as Reddit or Quora? Better? Worse? How difficult is it to hack and how secure is user information?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out why this information would be useful.  Could you expand on it?

Comment: It would be relevant to know how seucre stackexchange is to other forums because, as users, it would be useful to know how safe our information is and such, and just for fun how other forums compare. Sorry if the question was to broad; I'm new here.

Comment: Honestly - no one is ever going to tell you how to hack their own sites. SE does keep very *little* of your information, literally as little as possible though.

Comment: I'm not wondering how to hack it; basically I'm just wanting to know how the security of this site compares to other forums. I guess to put it simply, what is the "best" forum in terms of security.

Comment: Obligatory "Stack Exchange is not a forum" comment. And how would one answer that anyway, how is SE supposed to know how secure Quora and Reddit are?

Comment: I guess I'm just assuming people would just answer based of of experience and reports.

Comment: @NeonKraken that's very broad, reports on what ? publicly acknowledged security incidents ? (if the last one is yes, then we would expect you to dig those numbers to back up the question and maybe ask if you missed things or if your interpretation is correct), asking if the network is more or less secure than another one has good chances to be opinion based more than factually based with the actual form of this question.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect people to even answer this.  There's really no comparison that can be made.

Answer (score 6):

There is *something* we can mention about the security of Stack Exchange; over the years, 19 users (so far) have discovered one or more security incidents. They are awarded a place in the Hall of Fame, which you can find [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/security).

Sometimes, the company itself discovers a hack and either [blogs about it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/16/security-update/) or [apologizes on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322154/295232).

Whether those lists are complete, and how it compares to e.g. [Quora](https://help.quora.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020212652-Quora-Security-Update-FAQ), is impossible to tell unless you're deeply involved in *both* platforms, which hardly anyone is.