# I did not receive any email asking for my address for the "Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way" swag - what to do?

Tags: support, email, winter-bash-2018, swag

I've participated in the [Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321399/181233), [here's my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/321492#321492).

The question/contest has been closed at the end of January, and the participants have apparently been emailed with a question about their home address - I've never received any email from [JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat).

When noticing that, I've left [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way?page=1&tab=votes#comment1059652_321399) under the question and have sent an email with the same question to JNat, but did not receive a response for either of these.

Did I for some reason not qualify for the swag, or was my name missed in some way?

(I double-checked that the email address on my profile is correct and works fine. I know that it's working since I get all of the SO/SE network newsletters delivered to that address.)

I'm asking since a) I felt pretty good about the charitable aspect of this, b) I love Stack Overflow swag (still wearing the SO T-Shirts I got a couple of years back), and c) am pretty disappointed about the lack of communication on SE's part in this. I've tried to follow up on this a couple of times, but no response. Should I have followed up in a different way?

Part of the problem seems to be that there was no notification about the closure of the question - I was not aware that I was supposed to look for an email "in the next two weeks" after end of January. I stumbled onto this question last week again, checked emails, spam/junk folders, but nothing.

Like I said, I'm rather disappointed with this, and it feels like the "email the participants" part of these contests is rather unreliable, which is a real shame...

Sorry for the rant.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the correct email on your profile [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)? I believe that's what JNat used when sending the email to the winners. Maybe at some point you edited/removed it by mistake, or didn't update it when changing emails. Note that the email you log in with is **not the email in that page**.

Comment: I also didn't get an email for the stuff-a-way but did get an email for the watch @ShadowWizard

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yes that was the first thing I checked (even before entering the contest), but I checked it again before I wrote this question. The email address in my profile is correct - I've used this same address for almost 20 years now, and it's the one in my profile, never changed it since starting to use SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You email and comment were not missed!** The former was still marked as unread in my inbox (thought I'd seen it) and the latter was on a opened tab! I took a few days off late last week, so a few things piled up on me :\

**As for the email:** I just rechecked the list of addresses I sent it to, and yours was in there (so was @Magisch's, who mentioned in the comments they didn't get it either). Not sure why you can't find it, but... **it *was* sent.** Maybe it landed in spam, and then got auto-deleted before you could find it...?

**Finally, with regards to the actual swag:** the contest ended up getting a lot more answers than we'd expected, so we're running low on stock on a lot of the stuff we were planning on sending users. And 220+ users having filled the form, fulfilling this order is a *lot* of work for our vendor — as such, adding "stragglers" to the list for our vendor only complicates their job, since they'll have to rearrange quantities among the users already getting stuff.

However, since one of the things that led us to have this giveaway was the fact that we're changing swag vendors and still had a lot of inventory left in the warehouse, that means not all is lost! As soon as we're set up with our new vendor, **we'll still send you a box with swag :)** Unfortunately, I don't have an ETA on that, though — but I'll hold on to the email you sent me, and reach out to you as soon as we're set up! :)

Oh, yeah: if anyone else in the same situation is reading this, please email me so I put you on that "wait list" too :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you please give me a hint about the subject of the email that was sent? I searched for things I could think of, but it would be easier if I knew what to search for.

Comment: "Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way!" was the subject of the email, @nwinkler

Comment: Having said that, if you only have limited stock of stuff that you can send out, maybe limit the question to the first 100 participants, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - I checked my email account again, including the spam folder, nothing there with this subject. My spam folder hasn't been emptied in a while, I have lots of older stuff in there - not sure what happened to that email...

Comment: Yeah, as I said, the contest got way more responses than we'd anticipated. To add to that, we hadn't specified a cut-off _beforehand_, and doing so after the fact is kinda... not cool. Note that everyone's still getting a box full of great stuff, though, @nwinkler :)

Comment: And thanks for the kind offer about sending me some swag later, really appreciate it!

Comment: @JNat do I still need to email you too for this, or am I on the wait list?

Comment: Email me, please, @Magisch, 'cause it makes it easier for me to keep track and make sure I don't forget about it — I _really_ don't mean to let this fall through the cracks! :)

Comment: I really do not have the address collection message, could you please help me or resend it?

If this is not feasible at all, given the dates, don't worry, I'll be continuing to be an active SE user after all ;)

Comment: Please see this very answer, @Dark_eye, for how to proceed if you didn't get to the address collection email on time :)

Comment: @JNat, I missed the email :(, can I fill and send it now ?

Comment: Is there a timeframe for when this is going ahead?

Comment: Nope! As soon as I know, y'all will know ;)

Comment: @JNat I assume with the new policy on swag distribution this is no longer accurate, e.g we won't receive the items at all? If this is the case, can you either update this answer or delete the answer/question alltogether as obsolete?

Comment: No one's told me that folks in this situation aren't gonna get any swag, @Magisch. I'll try to get a definitive answer on which way this is gonna go once and for all, and update accordingly — this has been on halt for way too long... :\

Comment: @JNat I just heard that SE was discontinuing swag alltogether, for everyone, so I assumed there isn't gonna be any for people who still haven't gotten theirs. In any case, it's probably best to get some closure.

Comment: @JNat any updates on this?

Comment: None, unfortunately, @Magisch — our swag situation as a whole is still in flux (even more so since March, with COVID-19 and all that), which means this particular initiative has even more uncertainty around it... this is aggravated by the fact that, if indeed sending something your way, I'd like that to be something meaningful, instead of just whatever we can pull together to wrap this once and for all... :\ Anyway, as before: as soon as I know, you'll know.