# Thanks SE, love the swag!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2018, swag

## In [the Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/), SE sent me the following:

[image: A variety of SE swag]

## I just wanted to say thank you.

I already put the stickers on my travel trunks and had to wash the mug three times by now. Unfortunately, the Chemistry beaker/mug broke under light use :( but I'm still quite grateful for the gift.

Comment: I love mine too, I wear my SE shirt all the time!

Comment: Oh wow, there's Chemistry swag? Nice! This looks like awesome stuff.

Comment: @Cody _"carefully made to be broken"_ ;-) (from the current magnum ice cream ads)

Comment: We only sent *one* fan patch to each user? But we had soooooooo manyyyyyyy.

Comment: @animuson So if there are some left over, what should we do to gain it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, they're gone now. Everything that was leftover at our own vendor was donated away, hence why we did that competition. The fan patch is not an item we're planning on remaking at the new vendor. But I have like 100 of them sitting in a baggy in my office somewhere...

Comment: @animuson Well, I can give you my postal address to get rid of at least one set ;-) Make it another sell out: _first come, first served_

Comment: Honestly? The fan patch was the favourite bit of swag I've ever got - and I got it through the 100k route. I wouldn't have minded site patches too ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'll be sure to save them all as collectibles and sell them for $100 a piece in the future. ;P

Answer (score 6):

It's always nice to see which swag can be obtained from SE documented in pictures.

Congrats for yours.

This motivates me to still work further at the 100K rep for getting mine from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, SE!  I too got a wonderful bundle:

[image: swag photo]

The rubber duck now sits on my desk at work and has already helped me debug.  We're getting some interns this summer, so the duck will probably participate in their education.

(There might have also been a notebook, like the one in the question, in this bundle.  I got a pile of those to use as [contest prizes](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1917/1993) and don't now remember if one was in this box too.  They're nice notebooks!)

Comment: Oh, that rubber duck is just *too cute*. I'm envious. And very glad to see you're putting it to excellent use.

Answer (score 2):

A big thank you to StackExchange community for [Stuff-A-way!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/322072#322072). The package has arrived last month end. The stuff in it is soo cool especially sipper and bottle which my colleagues envy most ;)

[image]
[image]
I can't really express how much this means to me!... The SO tees are so cool to wear I didn't want to upload my pic PS- a bit shy :P