# Is it on topic to ask about how Stack Exchange implements a certain feature?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it on-topic over here (or any other SE site) to ask how Stack Exchange implements a certain feature?

For example, how do SE show 'linked questions' - do they make a 'note' in a database every time a post references another one? Or something else?

Comment: It's on topic, but scope is an issue.

Comment: @Servy I was thinking more of the 'idea'; not the code... (I wouldn't possibly understand SE's code! :). That on-topic? Are there any 'official' views that have been said before?

Comment: Again, it's on topic, so long as the question is sufficiently narrow about what you're asking as to allow for it to be answered in just a few paragraphs.  And of course there are plenty of things that they choose not to explain how they're implemented, not that you can't ask.

Comment: That is *very* on-topic! Meta is used to ask about these, among other things. But there is a possibility your question will get closed due to one of those *canonical* posts.

Comment: @MARamezani what do you mean?

Comment: Just ask it. You'll either get a full answer, part answer, or told no info can be divulged at all,

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I meant that if you're asking *what is the formula for hot questions?* your question will get closed of another one previously asked and explained. (You get the idea, and I'm too lazy to put a link in there :) Better search ***every*** corner before asking one. Just a suggestion. I know you know better.

Comment: @MARamezani Ahhh.. true - but it's hard to find stuff and you often miss things - as rene has proved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Meta Stack Exchange you can ask questions about software that drive the SE network.

But as it is closed source and only an SE Dev or Sysop could answer it might depend on how much they want to share or if the feature owner find the time to write a good answer.

Examples of good questions are:

[How does Stack Exchange work around the lack of Redis clustering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230366/how-does-stack-exchange-work-around-the-lack-of-redis-clustering/230378#230378)

[Does StackExchange have 1 multi-tenant environment, or many single-tenant environments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199141/does-stackexchange-have-1-multi-tenant-environment-or-many-single-tenant-enviro/199161#199161)

[Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172)

[Who made the 2013 Winter Bash snowflake script?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213043/who-made-the-2013-winter-bash-snowflake-script/213045#213045)

[Markdown formatting bug with code blocks in lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19624/markdown-formatting-bug-with-code-blocks-in-lists/74115#74115)

[How much bandwidth does SE eat up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172310/how-much-bandwidth-does-se-eat-up/172340#172340)

(and this selection doesn't mean I don't like contributions by other Devs)

For your example question I think their implementation is close to what is in [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) which means there is a row added to the PostLinks table for every link.

Comment: Nice! +1 - good example question :) And thanks for the 'answer' to my example question :)